# How do you get the index of the current iteration of a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, foreach

Is there some rare language construct I haven't encountered (like the few I've learned recently, some on Stack Overflow) in C# to get a value representing the current iteration of a foreach loop?

For instance, I currently do something like this depending on the circumstances:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (Object o in collection)
{
    // ...
    i++;
}
```

Comment: foreach casting retrieval is generally not going to me more optimized than just using index-based access on a collection, though in many cases it will be equal.  The purpose of foreach is to make your code readable, but it (usually) adds a layer of indirection, which isn't free.

Comment: I would say the primary purpose of `foreach` is to provide a common iteration mechanism for all collections regardless of whether they are indexable (`List`) or not (`Dictionary`).

Comment: Hi Brian Gideon - definitely agree (this was a few years ago and I was far less experienced at the time). However, while `Dictionary` isn't indexable, an iteration of `Dictionary` does traverse it in a particular order (i.e. an Enumerator is indexable by the fact it yields elements sequentially). In this sense, we could say that we are not looking for the index within the collection, but rather the index of the current enumerated element within the enumeration (i.e. whether we are at the first or fifth or last enumerated element).

Comment: foreach also allows the compiler to skip bounds checking each array access in the compiled code. Using for with an index will make the runtime check whether your index access is safe.

Comment: But it's false. If you don't change the iteration variable of a for loop within the loop, the compiler knows what its bounds are and doesn't need to check them again. This is such a common case that any decent compiler will implement it.

Comment: It's good. Does it lack readability? I don't think so. Too much writing? Typing cost is negligible when the phrase is not used very, very often. Low level optimization? Don't do that in C#. Just don't. Some sort of elegance? Well, in that case, there is `WithIndex` syntax that is nice, but what you have is good to. But do not use LINQ just for the sake of elegance. It's kind of a code smell to me. I use LINQ only when I can achieve a considerable improvement in readability and / or coding speed. Using LINQ for a simple loop is a no-no.

Comment: This [blog post](https://kodify.net/csharp/loop/foreach-index/#option-2-use-a-tuple-to-get-the-foreach-loops-value-and-index) has a clear description of some possible choices. I personally prefer using a `tuple` to access the value and index.

Comment: You're looking for a for() loop: `for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) { object o = collection[i]; /* do stuff */ }`.  If the collection doesn't have indexing, then your current approach is correct.

Answer (score 671, accepted):

The `foreach` is for iterating over collections that implement [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It does this by calling [`GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s793z9y2(v=vs.110).aspx) on the collection, which will return an [`Enumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx).

This Enumerator has a method and a property:

- `MoveNext()`
- `Current`

`Current` returns the object that Enumerator is currently on, `MoveNext` updates `Current` to the next object.

The concept of an index is foreign to the concept of enumeration, and cannot be done.

Because of that, most collections are able to be traversed using an indexer and the for loop construct.

I greatly prefer using a for loop in this situation compared to tracking the index with a local variable.

Comment: "Obviously, the concept of an index is foreign to the concept of enumeration, and cannot be done." -- This is nonsense, as the answers by David B and bcahill make clear. An index is an enumeration over a range, and there's no reason one cannot enumerate two things in parallel ... that's exactly what the indexing form of Enumerable.Select does.

Comment: Basic code example: `for(var i = 0; i < myList.Count; i ++){System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(i);}`

Comment: @JimBalter: A Linked List is an example of an IEnumerable that doesn't have an index. FlySwat's answer is correct, although maybe you were taking issue with his word "obviously", in which case, I agree; It's not so obvious to many.

Comment: @Pretzel The statement which I quoted is (obviously) not correct, and I explained why. The fact Linked List "doesn't have an index" is completely irrelevant and shows extraordinary confusion.

Comment: @JimBalter: Well, I'm not going to argue with you. Maybe Microsoft should have called it I-Iterable instead of IEnumerable (which, I'll conceded, does imply a number.) But the implementation is how it is. There's no index. (I'm guessing for thread-safety reasons...)

Comment: P.S. Just read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.100%29.aspx, which I've referred to several times now. Pay some attention to "you can call this method as an instance method on *any object of type IEnumerable<TSource>*"

Comment: The bottom line is that "A Linked List is an example of an IEnumerable that doesn't have an index" is a strawman that is completely irrelevant. No one ever claimed that all IEnumerables "have an index".

Comment: Being curious, is the simplified statement "the concept of an index is foreign to the concept of enumeration" correct, then?

Comment: @Pretzel Jim's point is that as long as you can map the elements to a sequence of integers, you can index it. That the class itself does not store an index is beside the point. Additionally, that the linked list *does* have an order only strengthens Jim's position. All you need to do is number each element in order. Specifically, you can achieve this by incrementing a count *while* you iterate, or you could generate a list of integers with the same length and then zip them (as in Python's [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function).

Comment: Enumerable literally means "can be numbered". That the API or underlying data structure doesn't provide a means for random access is another thing entirely different.

Comment: Just to be clear, the question asks for an index of "the current iteration of a foreach loop", which is not the same as the natural index of the enumerable (if there even is one). If your enumerable represents e.g. items 5, 6, 7 in some list, then you're right there's no way to get that. But the OP actually wanted 0, 1, 2 in that case, which of course is possible. Basically this is a correct answer to a different question.

Comment: @jpmc26 or even better just use Python's `enumerate` which does the zip of the index with the element in one go. `for i, x in enumerate(xs)`

Answer (score 983):

Ian Mercer posted a similar solution as this on [Phil Haack's blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/14/a-better-razor-foreach-loop.aspx):

```
foreach (var item in Model.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
{
    var value = item.value;
    var index = item.i;
}
```

This gets you the item (`item.value`) and its index (`item.i`) by using [this overload of LINQ's `Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx):

> the second parameter of the function [inside Select] represents the index of the source element.

The `new { i, value }` is creating a new [anonymous object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types).

Heap allocations can be avoided by using `ValueTuple` if you're using C# 7.0 or later:

```
foreach (var item in Model.Select((value, i) => ( value, i )))
{
    var value = item.value;
    var index = item.i;
}
```

You can also eliminate the `item.` by using automatic destructuring:

```
foreach (var (value, i) in Model.Select((value, i) => ( value, i )))
{
    // Access `value` and `i` directly here.
}
```

Comment: That solution is nice for the case of a Razor template where the neatness of the template is a non-trivial design concern and you are also wanting to use the index of every item that is enumerated.  However, do bear in mind that the object allocation from 'wrapping' adds expense (in space and time) on top of the (unavoidable) incrementing of an integer.

Comment: pure awesomeness, but where is that documented.... I mean two parameters in the Select delegate, I never saw that... and I can't find a documentation explanation..... experimenting with that expression I saw that value doesn't mean anything and only the position matters, first parameter the element, second parameter the index.

Comment: @mjsr The documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Sorry - that's clever, but is it really more readable than creating an index outside the foreach and incrementing it each loop?

Comment: With the later C# versions so you also use tuples, so you'll have something like this:
foreach (var (item, i) in Model.Select((v, i) => (v, i)))
Allows you to access the item and index (i) directly inside the for-loop with tuple deconstruction.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this is a good answer (over 450 upvotes at the time of writing)?  As far as I can see it's more difficult to understand than simply incrementing a counter, is hence less maintainable, it uses more memory, and it is probably slower.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @RichN The Linq `.Select( T item, Int32 index )` method is now well-known amongst most C# programmers today. It's only confusing if you're not yet familiar with Linq and its functional style of programming.

Comment: Has anyone done any performance and memory usage tests with the `tuple` version compared to the incrementing counter? I'm sure others would like to know if performance and memory was a factor in their coding requirements.

Comment: @RichN B/c `for` and `foreach` loops ain't "cool" nowadays (/s). Chaining is. The problem is that LINQ doesn't have `forEach` _on purpose_ (as [Eric Lippert explains beautifully](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/foreach-vs-foreach)). That's b/c foreach is solely used for side effects, breaking the chaining metaphor. LINQ calls that anti-pattern [I think Eric'd say it should be anti-pattern in other languages as well]. So you see `foreach` caught in the "stop using `for` loops; start chaining" coolness vs. "there's no foreach chaining in C# [LINQ] on purpose" crossfire

Comment: It is unefficient to delcare variables within a loop block. It will make abusing memory address reservation up to the end of the method using the loop.

Comment: SERIOUSLY? All that so you dont have to index++?  That's a bit of overkill...dont you think?

Answer (score 508):

Finally C# 7.0 has a decent syntax for getting an index inside of a `foreach` loop (i. e. tuples):

```
foreach (var (item, index) in collection.WithIndex())
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"{index}: {item}");
}
```

A little extension method would be needed:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class IEnumerableExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<(T item, int index)> WithIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self)       
       => self.Select((item, index) => (item, index));
}
```

Comment: This answer is underrated, having the tuples is much cleaner

Comment: Modified to handle null collections: `public static IEnumerable<(T item, int index)> WithIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self) => self?.Select((item, index) => (item, index)) ?? new List<(T, int)>();`

Comment: It might be useful to call the method `Enumerated` to be more recognizable for people used to [other languages](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687832-enumerated) (and perhaps swap the order of the tuple parameters too). Not that `WithIndex` isn't obvious anyway.

Comment: @2Toad For the null condition you could also use `Enumerable.Empty<(T, int)>()` as more efficient than creating an empty list, I think.

Comment: Good answer, just please don't name it "EnumExtensions" that's quite confusing. It has nothing to do with Enums. Just name it IEnumerableExtensions

Comment: Modified answer by @2Toad for nullable reference types annotation and included the change by @DanDiplo `public static IEnumerable<(T item, int index)> WithIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T>? self) => self?.Select((item, index) => (item, index)) ?? Enumerable.Empty<(T, int)>();`

Answer (score 128):

Could do something like this:

```
public static class ForEachExtensions
{
    public static void ForEachWithIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T, int> handler)
    {
        int idx = 0;
        foreach (T item in enumerable)
            handler(item, idx++);
    }
}

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] values = new[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" };

        values.ForEachWithIndex((item, idx) => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", idx, item));
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't "really" solve the problem. The idea is good but it doesn't avoid the additional counting variable

Comment: This does not work if we have a return statement within our for loop, if you change "ForEachWithIndex" for that, then it is not generic, better off writing a regular for loop

Comment: Your ForEachWithIndex call is equivalent to this one using the Linq Select that takes a string and an index: `values.Select((item, idx) => { Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", idx, item); return item; }).ToList();`

Answer (score 114):

I disagree with comments that a `for` loop is a better choice in most cases.

`foreach` is a useful construct, and not replaceble by a `for` loop in all circumstances.

For example, if you have a **DataReader** and loop through all records using a `foreach` it automatically calls the **Dispose** method and closes the reader (which can then close the connection automatically). This is therefore safer as it prevents connection leaks even if you forget to close the reader.

(Sure it is good practise to always close readers but the compiler is not going to catch it if you don't - you can't guarantee you have closed all readers but you can make it more likely you won't leak connections by getting in the habit of using foreach.)

There may be other examples of the implicit call of the `Dispose` method being useful.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  Rather subtle.  You can get more information at http://www.pvle.be/2010/05/foreach-statement-calls-dispose-on-ienumerator/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754(VS.71).aspx.

Comment: +1. I was writing more in detail about how `foreach` is different from `for` (and closer to `while`) on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/178225/6605).

Comment: While an interesting post about the differences of foreach vs for, this does not address the question asked at all, which was "*how do I get the index of the current iteration of a foreach loop*".

Answer (score 72):

Literal Answer -- warning, performance may not be as good as just using an `int` to track the index.  At least it is better than using `IndexOf`.

You just need to use the indexing overload of Select to wrap each item in the collection with an anonymous object that knows the index.  This can be done against anything that implements IEnumerable.

```
System.Collections.IEnumerable collection = Enumerable.Range(100, 10);

foreach (var o in collection.OfType<object>().Select((x, i) => new {x, i}))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", o.i, o.x);
}
```

Comment: The only reason to use OfType<T>() instead of Cast<T>() is if some items in the enumeration might fail an explicit cast. For object, this will never be the case.

Comment: Sure, except for the other reason to use OfType instead of Cast - which is that I never use Cast.

Comment: Why was the OfType() (or Cast, if preferred) needed at all? Select can be called right on collection, no?

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs No. Select requires a type parameter. non-generic IEnumerable has no type parameter to supply.

Comment: @AmyB thanks! I overlooked that collection was IEnumerable only.

Answer (score 60):

Using LINQ, C# 7, and the `System.ValueTuple` NuGet package, you can do this:

```cs
foreach (var (value, index) in collection.Select((v, i)=>(v, i))) {
    Console.WriteLine(value + " is at index " + index);
}
```

You can use the regular `foreach` construct and be able to access the value and index directly, not as a member of an object, and keeps both fields only in the scope of the loop. For these reasons, I believe this is the best solution if you are able to use C# 7 and `System.ValueTuple`.

Comment: This is different because .Select is built-in from LINQ. You don't have to write your own function? You will need to have VS install "System.ValueTuple" though.

Answer (score 47):

There's nothing wrong with using a counter variable. In fact, whether you use `for`, `foreach` `while` or `do`, a counter variable must somewhere be declared and incremented.

So use this idiom if you're not sure if you have a suitably-indexed collection:

```
var i = 0;
foreach (var e in collection) {
   // Do stuff with 'e' and 'i'
   i++;
}
```

Else use this one if you *know* that your *indexable* collection is O(1) for index access (which it will be for `Array` and probably for `List<T>` (the documentation doesn't say), but not necessarily for other types (such as `LinkedList`)):

```
// Hope the JIT compiler optimises read of the 'Count' property!
for (var i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++) {
   var e = collection[i];
   // Do stuff with 'e' and 'i'
}
```

It should never be necessary to 'manually' operate the `IEnumerator` by invoking `MoveNext()` and interrogating `Current` - `foreach` is saving you that particular bother ... if you need to skip items, just use a `continue` in the body of the loop.

And just for completeness, depending on what you were *doing* with your index (the above constructs offer plenty of flexibility), you might use Parallel LINQ:

```
// First, filter 'e' based on 'i',
// then apply an action to remaining 'e'
collection
    .AsParallel()
    .Where((e,i) => /* filter with e,i */)
    .ForAll(e => { /* use e, but don't modify it */ });

// Using 'e' and 'i', produce a new collection,
// where each element incorporates 'i'
collection
    .AsParallel()
    .Select((e, i) => new MyWrapper(e, i));
```

We use `AsParallel()` above, because it's 2014 already, and we want to make good use of those multiple cores to speed things up. Further, for 'sequential' LINQ, [you only get a `ForEach()` extension method on `List<T>` and `Array`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101265/why-is-there-not-a-foreach-extension-method-on-the-ienumerable-interface) ... and it's not clear that using it is any better than doing a simple `foreach`, since you are still running single-threaded for uglier syntax.

Comment: In my view, this is the best answer in terms of weighing readability and ensuring there is bounds safety

Answer (score 40):

Using @FlySwat's answer, I came up with this solution:

```
//var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }; // Your sample collection

var listEnumerator = list.GetEnumerator(); // Get enumerator

for (var i = 0; listEnumerator.MoveNext() == true; i++)
{
  int currentItem = listEnumerator.Current; // Get current item.
  //Console.WriteLine("At index {0}, item is {1}", i, currentItem); // Do as you wish with i and  currentItem
}
```

You get the enumerator using `GetEnumerator` and then you loop using a `for` loop. However, the trick is to make the loop's condition `listEnumerator.MoveNext() == true`.

Since the `MoveNext` method of an enumerator returns true if there is a next element and it can be accessed, making that the loop condition makes the loop stop when we run out of elements to iterate over.

Comment: There's no need to compare listEnumerator.MoveNext() == true. That's like asking the computer if true == true? :) Just say if listEnumerator.MoveNext() { }

Comment: @Zesty, you're absolutely correct. I felt that it's more readable to add it in this case especially for people who aren't used to entering anything other than i < blahSize as a condition.

Comment: @Gezim I don't mind predicates here, but I get your point in that this doesn't look like a predicate.

Comment: You should dispose the enumerator.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek The enumerator does not implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: @EdwardBrey you are right, it is a good point. But speaking about the `listEnumerator` here, it is a generic enumerator and as such it does implement `IDisposable` and should be disposed.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Good catch for `List<T>`'s enumerator. It implements `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>`, which inherits `IDisposable`. The enumerator for `List<T>` doesn't do anything in `Dispose` and doesn't have a finalizer, so calling `Dispose` in this case has no effect, but it could for other enumerables.

Answer (score 36):

Just add your own index. Keep it simple.

```
int i = -1;
foreach (var item in Collection)
{
    ++i;
    item.index = i;
}
```

Comment: It's better to start i with -1 and increment it just entering loop

Comment: why is it better?

Comment: int i = 0;
foreach (var item in Collection)
{
    if (item.value == 3) continue;
    ++i;
}

Comment: Good point, i'll update my answer

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a good idea because it's prone to +1 errors.

Comment: @DmitryKh can you elaborate?

Answer (score 25):

You could wrap the original enumerator with another that does contain the index information.

```
foreach (var item in ForEachHelper.WithIndex(collection))
{
    Console.Write("Index=" + item.Index);
    Console.Write(";Value= " + item.Value);
    Console.Write(";IsLast=" + item.IsLast);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Here is the code for the `ForEachHelper` class.

```
public static class ForEachHelper
{
    public sealed class Item<T>
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public T Value { get; set; }
        public bool IsLast { get; set; }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Item<T>> WithIndex<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        Item<T> item = null;
        foreach (T value in enumerable)
        {
            Item<T> next = new Item<T>();
            next.Index = 0;
            next.Value = value;
            next.IsLast = false;
            if (item != null)
            {
                next.Index = item.Index + 1;
                yield return item;
            }
            item = next;
        }
        if (item != null)
        {
            item.IsLast = true;
            yield return item;
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't actually return the index of the item.  Instead, it will return the index inside the enumerated list, which may only be a sublist of the list, thereby giving you accurate data only when the sublist and the list are of equal size.  Basically, any time the collection has objects in it not in the requested type your index will be incorrect.

Comment: @Lucas: No, but it will return the index of the current foreach iteration. That was the question.

Answer (score 23):

**Why foreach ?!**

The simplest way is using **for** instead of foreach **if you are using List**:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < myList.Count ; i++)
{
    // Do something...
}
```

Or if you want use foreach:

```
foreach (string m in myList)
{
     // Do something...
}
```

You can use this to know the index of each loop:

```
myList.indexOf(m)
```

Comment: indexOf solution is invalid for list with duplicates and is also very slow.

Comment: The issue to be avoided is where you traverse the IEnumerable multiple times, e.g. to get the count of items and then each item. This has implications when the IEnumerable is the result of a database query for example.

Comment: myList.IndexOf() is O(n), so your loop will be O(n^2).

Answer (score 21):

Here's a solution I just came up with for this problem

**Original code:**

```
int index=0;
foreach (var item in enumerable)
{
    blah(item, index); // some code that depends on the index
    index++;
}
```

**Updated code**

```
enumerable.ForEach((item, index) => blah(item, index));
```

**Extension Method:**

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T, int> action)
    {
        var unit = new Unit(); // unit is a new type from the reactive framework (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) to represent a void, since in C# you can't return a void
        enumerable.Select((item, i) => 
            {
                action(item, i);
                return unit;
            }).ToList();

        return pSource;
    }
```

Answer (score 21):

This answer: lobby the C# language team for direct language support.

The leading answer states:

> Obviously, the concept of an index is foreign to the concept of
>   enumeration, and cannot be done.

While this is true of the current C# language version (2020), this is not a conceptual CLR/Language limit, it can be done.

The Microsoft C# language development team could create a new C# language feature, by adding support for a new Interface IIndexedEnumerable

```
foreach (var item in collection with var index)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Iteration {0} has value {1}", index, item);
}

//or, building on @user1414213562's answer
foreach (var (item, index) in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Iteration {0} has value {1}", index, item);
}
```

If `foreach ()` is used and `with var index` is present, then the compiler expects the item collection to declare `IIndexedEnumerable` interface. If the interface is absent, the compiler can polyfill wrap the source with an IndexedEnumerable object, which adds in the code for tracking the index.

```
interface IIndexedEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    //Not index, because sometimes source IEnumerables are transient
    public long IterationNumber { get; }
}
```

Later, the CLR can be updated to have internal index tracking, that is only used if `with` keyword is specified and the source doesn't directly implement `IIndexedEnumerable`

Why:

- Foreach looks nicer, and in business applications, foreach loops are rarely a performance bottleneck
- Foreach can be more efficient on memory. Having a pipeline of functions instead of converting to new collections at each step. Who cares if it uses a few more CPU cycles when there are fewer CPU cache faults and fewer garbage collections?
- Requiring the coder to add index-tracking code, spoils the beauty
- It's quite easy to implement (please Microsoft) and is backward compatible

While most people here are not Microsoft employees, this is *a* correct answer, you can lobby Microsoft to add such a feature. You could already build your own iterator with an [extension function and use tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39997157/887092), but Microsoft could sprinkle the syntactic sugar to avoid the extension function

Comment: Wait, so does this language feature already exist, or is it proposed for the future?

Comment: @Pavel I updated the answer to be clear. This answer was provided to counter the leading answer which states "Obviously, the concept of an index is foreign to the concept of enumeration, and cannot be done."

Comment: Yeah, it seems like if JavaScript can do it, C# should be able to
    ["John","Ben","Mike","sPoNgeBoB"].forEach((name, i)=>{
    console.log(\`I uppercased name ${i} in your list so it looks like ${name.toUpperCase()}\`)
})

Answer (score 21):

C# 7 finally gives us an elegant way to do this:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<(int, T)> Enumerate<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> input,
        int start = 0
    )
    {
        int i = start;
        foreach (var t in input)
        {
            yield return (i++, t);
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = new string[]
        {
            "Alpha",
            "Bravo",
            "Charlie",
            "Delta"
        };

        foreach (var (i, t) in s.Enumerate())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i}: {t}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, and MS should extend the CLR/BCL to make this kind of thing native.

Answer (score 19):

It's only going to work for a List and not any IEnumerable, but in LINQ there's this:

```
IList<Object> collection = new List<Object> { 
    new Object(), 
    new Object(), 
    new Object(), 
    };

foreach (Object o in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(collection.IndexOf(o));
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

@Jonathan I didn't say it was a great answer, I just said it was just showing it was possible to do what he asked :)

@Graphain I wouldn't expect it to be fast - I'm not entirely sure how it works, it could reiterate through the entire list each time to find a matching object, which would be a helluvalot of compares.

That said, List might keep an index of each object along with the count.

Jonathan seems to have a better idea, if he would elaborate?

It would be better to just keep a count of where you're up to in the foreach though, simpler, and more adaptable.

Comment: Not sure on the heavy downvoting.  Sure performance makes this prohibitive but you did answer the question!

Comment: Another issue with this is that it only works if the items in the list are unique.

Answer (score 11):

This is how I do it, which is nice for its simplicity/brevity, but if you're doing a lot in the loop body `obj.Value`, it is going to get old pretty fast.

```
foreach(var obj in collection.Select((item, index) => new { Index = index, Value = item }) {
    string foo = string.Format("Something[{0}] = {1}", obj.Index, obj.Value);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
// using foreach loop how to get index number:
    
foreach (var result in results.Select((value, index) => new { index, value }))
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This is just a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11437562).

Answer (score 5):

```
int index;
foreach (Object o in collection)
{
    index = collection.indexOf(o);
}
```

This would work for collections supporting `IList`.

Comment: Two problems: 1) This is `O(n^2)` since in most implementations `IndexOf` is `O(n)`. 2) This fails if there are duplicate items in the list.

Comment: Note: O(n^2) means this could be disastrously slow for a big collection.

Comment: Great invention to use IndexOf method! This is what I was looking for to get the index (number) in foreach loop! Big Thx

Comment: God, I hope you did not use that! :( It DOES use that variable you did't want to create - in fact, it will create n+1 ints because that function has to create one in order to return, too, - and that indexof search is much, much slower than one integer increment operation in every step. Why won't people vote this answer down?

Comment: Don't use this answer, I found the hard truth mentioned in one of the comments. "This fails if there are duplicate items in the list."!!!

Comment: helpful while in debug session

Answer (score 5):

Better to use keyword `continue` safe construction like this

```
int i=-1;
foreach (Object o in collection)
{
    ++i;
    //...
    continue; //<--- safe to call, index will be increased
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can write your loop like this:

```
var s = "ABCDEFG";
foreach (var item in s.GetEnumeratorWithIndex())
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Character: {0}, Position: {1}", item.Value, item.Index);
}
```

After adding the following struct and extension method.

The struct and extension method encapsulate Enumerable.Select functionality.

```
public struct ValueWithIndex<T>
{
    public readonly T Value;
    public readonly int Index;

    public ValueWithIndex(T value, int index)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        this.Index = index;
    }

    public static ValueWithIndex<T> Create(T value, int index)
    {
        return new ValueWithIndex<T>(value, index);
    }
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<ValueWithIndex<T>> GetEnumeratorWithIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        return enumerable.Select(ValueWithIndex<T>.Create);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this should be quite efficient, but it works:

```
@foreach (var banner in Model.MainBanners) {
    @Model.MainBanners.IndexOf(banner)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If the collection is a list, you can use List.IndexOf, as in:

```
foreach (Object o in collection)
{
    // ...
    @collection.IndexOf(o)
}
```

Comment: And now the algorithm is O(n^2) (if not worse). I would think *very* carefully before using this. Its also a duplicate of @crucible 's answer

Comment: @BradleyDotNET is exactly right, don't use this version.

Comment: Be careful with this! If you've got a duplicated item in your list, it will get the position of the first one!

Answer (score 4):

This way you can use the index and value using LINQ:

```
ListValues.Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i }).ToList().ForEach(element =>
{
    // element.Index
    // element.Value
});
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution for this problem is an extension method `WithIndex()`,

http://code.google.com/p/ub-dotnet-utilities/source/browse/trunk/Src/Utilities/Extensions/EnumerableExtensions.cs

**Use it like**

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };    

var odd = list.WithIndex().Where(i => (i.Item & 1) == 1);
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 0, 2, 4 }, odd.Select(i => i.Index));
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 1, 3, 5 }, odd.Select(i => i.Item));
```

Comment: I'd use a `struct` for the (index,item) pair.

Answer (score 3):

For interest, Phil Haack just wrote an example of this in the context of a Razor Templated Delegate (http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/14/a-better-razor-foreach-loop.aspx)

Effectively he writes an extension method which wraps the iteration in an "IteratedItem" class (see below) allowing access to the index as well as the element during iteration.

```
public class IndexedItem<TModel> {
  public IndexedItem(int index, TModel item) {
    Index = index;
    Item = item;
  }

  public int Index { get; private set; }
  public TModel Item { get; private set; }
}
```

However, while this would be fine in a non-Razor environment if you are doing a single operation (i.e. one that could be provided as a lambda) it's not going to be a solid replacement of the for/foreach syntax in non-Razor contexts.

Answer (score 3):

I built this in [LINQPad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINQPad):

```
var listOfNames = new List<string>(){"John","Steve","Anna","Chris"};

var listCount = listOfNames.Count;

var NamesWithCommas = string.Empty;

foreach (var element in listOfNames)
{
    NamesWithCommas += element;
    if(listOfNames.IndexOf(element) != listCount -1)
    {
        NamesWithCommas += ", ";
    }
}

NamesWithCommas.Dump();  //LINQPad method to write to console.
```

You could also just use `string.join`:

```
var joinResult = string.Join(",", listOfNames);
```

Comment: Can someone explain to me what's this O(n*n) thing ?

Comment: @Axel it basically means that the operations required to calculate the result increase quadratically, i.e. if there are `n` items then the operations are `n * n`, or `n`-squared. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities

Answer (score 2):

Unless your collection can return the index of the object via some method, the only way is to use a counter like in your example.

However, when working with indexes, the only reasonable answer to the problem is to use a for loop. Anything else introduces code complexity, not to mention time and space complexity.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a way to get the value of the current iteration of a foreach loop.  Counting yourself, seems to be the best way.

May I ask, why you would want to know?

It seems that you would most likley be doing one of three things:

1)  Getting the object from the collection, but in this case you already have it.

2)  Counting the objects for later post processing...the collections have a Count property that you could make use of.

3)  Setting a property on the object based on its order in the loop...although you could easily be setting that when you added the object to the collection.

Comment: 4)  The case I've hit several times is something different that has to be done on the first or last pass--say a list of objects you are going to print and you need commas between items but not after the last item.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem, but thinking around the problem in my case gave the best solution, unrelated to the expected solution.

It could be quite a common case, basically, I'm reading from one source list and creating objects based on them in a destination list, however, I have to check whether the source items are valid first and want to return the row of any error.  At first-glance, I want to get the index into the enumerator of the object at the Current property, however, as I am copying these elements, I implicitly know the current index anyway from the current destination.  Obviously it depends on your destination object, but for me it was a List, and most likely it will implement ICollection.

i.e.

```
var destinationList = new List<someObject>();
foreach (var item in itemList)
{
  var stringArray = item.Split(new char[] { ';', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

  if (stringArray.Length != 2)
  {
    //use the destinationList Count property to give us the index into the stringArray list
    throw new Exception("Item at row " + (destinationList.Count + 1) + " has a problem.");
  }
  else
  {
    destinationList.Add(new someObject() { Prop1 = stringArray[0], Prop2 = stringArray[1]});
  }
}
```

Not always applicable, but often enough to be worth mentioning, I think.

Anyway, the point being that sometimes there is a non-obvious solution already in the logic you have...

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't sure what you were trying to do with the index information based on the question. However, in C#, you can usually adapt the IEnumerable.Select method to get the index out of whatever you want. For instance, I might use something like this for whether a value is odd or even.

```
string[] names = { "one", "two", "three" };
var oddOrEvenByName = names
    .Select((name, index) => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(name, index % 2))
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

This would give you a dictionary by name of whether the item was odd (1) or even (0) in the list.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?  Note that myDelimitedString may be null if myEnumerable is empty.

```
IEnumerator enumerator = myEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
string myDelimitedString;
string current = null;

if( enumerator.MoveNext() )
    current = (string)enumerator.Current;

while( null != current)
{
    current = (string)enumerator.Current; }

    myDelimitedString += current;

    if( enumerator.MoveNext() )
        myDelimitedString += DELIMITER;
    else
        break;
}
```

Comment: Multiple problems here. A) extra brace. B) string concat += per loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

As a newbie to C# coming from Python, I've come up with a solution that I like that doesn't involve creating helper methods, using libraries, or just using a for loop. I think it's quite elegant:

```
string[] fruits = new string[] {"apple", "banana", "orange", "kiwi"};
foreach (var (item, index) in fruits.Zip(Enumerable.Range(0, fruits.Length)))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{index}: {item}");
}
// Output:
// 0: apple
// 1: banana
// 2: orange
// 3: kiwi
```

Thanks to .Zip and Enumerate.Range being "lazy" (as Python calls it) or using "deferred execution", this approach shouldn't add any unneccessary memory usage, and very little extra time, at least to my understanding. There are probably applications where this approach doesn't work and others would be preferable, but I found this useful.

Comment: I hope this answer will get more attention as time goes on. I find it more readable than the ones that use `.Select`, as excellent as they are. And `.Zip` is useful for many more scenarios beyond the original question. I think every .NET programmer should have it in their toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution to this problem, with a focus on keeping the syntax as close to a standard `foreach` as possible.

This sort of construct is useful if you are wanting to make your views look nice and clean in MVC. For example instead of writing this the usual way (which is hard to format nicely):

```
 <%int i=0;
 foreach (var review in Model.ReviewsList) { %>
    <div id="review_<%=i%>">
        <h3><%:review.Title%></h3>                      
    </div>
    <%i++;
 } %>
```

You could instead write this:

```
 <%foreach (var review in Model.ReviewsList.WithIndex()) { %>
    <div id="review_<%=LoopHelper.Index()%>">
        <h3><%:review.Title%></h3>                      
    </div>
 <%} %>
```

I've written some helper methods to enable this:

```
public static class LoopHelper {
    public static int Index() {
        return (int)HttpContext.Current.Items["LoopHelper_Index"];
    }       
}

public static class LoopHelperExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<T> WithIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> that) {
        return new EnumerableWithIndex<T>(that);
    }

    public class EnumerableWithIndex<T> : IEnumerable<T> {
        public IEnumerable<T> Enumerable;

        public EnumerableWithIndex(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) {
            Enumerable = enumerable;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
            for (int i = 0; i < Enumerable.Count(); i++) {
                HttpContext.Current.Items["LoopHelper_Index"] = i;
                yield return Enumerable.ElementAt(i);
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

In a non-web environment you could use a `static` instead of `HttpContext.Current.Items`.

This is essentially a global variable, and so you cannot have more than one WithIndex loop nested, but that is not a major problem in this use case.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your specific question, but it DOES provide you with a solution to your problem: use a for loop to run through the object collection. then you will have the current index you are working on.

```
// Untested
for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("My index is " + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are foreach'ing. Do you have IndexOf available? If it is a list you can use collection.IndexOf(item) to get the index. If it is an array, you do not have IndexOf. You will need to introduce an external counter variable or use the classic "c language" for statement.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, this is working, inside a foreach loop.

```
@foreach (var item in _modalSubscriberList)                                                                                   
{                                                                           
 (_modalSubscriberList.IndexOf(item) + 1)
}
```

Comment: What language is that? ASP? This is a C# question... not sure if that will help anyone.

Comment: This language does not seem to be C#. Which Language is your answer written in? 
Maybe (Razor?)

Comment: In response to the comments: In the provided example: _modalSubscriberList is a list, so IndexOf is a valid statement.

Comment: Although the text is written in razor syntax, it is not pertinent to the issue at hand. Let's concentrate on providing a solution that addresses the original concern with confidence.