# Getting the array key in a 'foreach' loop

Tags: c#, arrays

How do I get the key of the current element in a `foreach` loop in C#?

For example:

### PHP

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    echo("$value is assigned to key: $key");
}
```

#### What I'm trying to do in C#:

```
int[] values = { 5, 14, 29, 49, 99, 150, 999 };

foreach (int val in values)
{
    if(search <= val && !stop)
    {
         // Set key to a variable
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Grauenwolf's way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60032/getting-the-array-key-in-a-foreach-loop#60035) is the most straightforward and performant way of doing this with an array:

> Either use a for loop or create a temp variable that you increment on each pass.

Which would of course look like this:

```
int[] values = { 5, 14, 29, 49, 99, 150, 999 };

for (int key = 0; key < values.Length; ++key)
  if (search <= values[key] && !stop)
  {
    // set key to a variable
  }
```

With .NET 3.5 you can take a more functional approach as well, but it is a little more verbose at the site, and would likely rely on a couple [support functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apply) for [visiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) the elements in an IEnumerable.  Overkill if this is all you need it for, but handy if you tend to do a lot of collection processing.

Comment: _"or create a temp variable that you increment on each pass"_ as far as I remember, there is no guarantee that foreach will loop over your collection in an ascending (or descending) order, only that it will stop at every element at _exactly once_, therefor if you are using an external value, your solution might- or might not be valid based on the implementation. Normally it will give you the desired result, but i.e. a common optimization is to parse an array in descending order (it takes one less machine instruction than ascending order per cycle).

Comment: I think that depends on the type of enumerable you're iterating over. If it's an array, I'd think order would be guaranteed.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to get at the key (read: index) then you'd have to use a for loop. If you actually want to have a collection that holds keys/values then I'd consider using a HashTable or a Dictionary (if you want to use Generics).

```
Dictionary<int, string> items = new  Dictionary<int, string>();

foreach (int key in items.Keys)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} has value: {1}", key, items[key]);
}
```

Hope that helps,
Tyler

Comment: It would be much more performant to do foreach(KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in items) and then reference pair.Key and pair.Value, rather than doing a lookup in each iteration.

Answer (score 11):

With DictionaryEntry and KeyValuePair:

Based on
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionaryentry.aspx)

```
IDictionary<string,string> openWith = new Dictionary<string,string>()
{
   { "txt", "notepad.exe" }
   { "bmp", "paint.exe" }
   { "rtf", "wordpad.exe" }
};

foreach (DictionaryEntry de in openWith)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", de.Key, de.Value);
}

// also

foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> de in openWith)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", de.Key, de.Value);
}
```

[Releated SO question: KeyValuePair VS DictionaryEntry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905424/keyvaluepair-vs-dictionaryentry)

Answer (score 4):

Alas there is no built-in way to do this. Either use a for loop or create a temp variable that you increment on each pass.

Answer (score 3):

I answered this in another version of this question:

> Foreach is for iterating over
>   collections that implement
>   IEnumerable. It does this by calling
>   GetEnumerator on the collection, which
>   will return an Enumerator.
>
> This Enumerator has a method and a
>   property:
>
> ```
> * MoveNext()
> * Current
> ```
>
> Current returns the object that
>   Enumerator is currently on, MoveNext
>   updates Current to the next object.
>
> Obviously, the concept of an index is
>   foreign to the concept of enumeration,
>   and cannot be done.
>
> Because of that, most collections are
>   able to be traversed using an indexer
>   and the for loop construct.
>
> I greatly prefer using a for loop in
>   this situation compared to tracking
>   the index with a local variable.

[How do you get the index of the current iteration of a foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021/c-get-index-of-current-foreach-iteration#43029)

Answer (score 2):

Actually you should use classic for (;;) loop if you want to loop through an array. But the similar functionality that you have achieved with your PHP code can be achieved in C# like this with a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, int> values = new Dictionary<int, int>();
values[0] = 5;
values[1] = 14;
values[2] = 29;
values[3] = 49;
// whatever...

foreach (int key in values.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is assigned to key: {1}", values[key], key);
}
```

Comment: It would be much more performant to do foreach(KeyValuePair<int, int> pair in values) and then reference pair.Key and pair.Value, rather than doing a lookup in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I just came up with for this problem

**Original code:**

```
int index=0;
foreach (var item in enumerable)
{
    blah(item, index); // some code that depends on the index
    index++;
}
```

**Updated code**

```
enumerable.ForEach((item, index) => blah(item, index));
```

**Extension Method:**

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T, int> action)
    {
        var unit = new Unit(); // unit is a new type from the reactive framework (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) to represent a void, since in C# you can't return a void
        enumerable.Select((item, i) => 
            {
                action(item, i);
                return unit;
            }).ToList();

        return pSource;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this functionality yourself using an extension method. For example, here is an implementation of an extension method KeyValuePairs which works on lists:

```
public struct IndexValue<T> {
    public int Index {get; private set;}
    public T Value {get; private set;}
    public IndexValue(int index, T value) : this() {
        this.Index = index;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

public static class EnumExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<IndexValue<T>> KeyValuePairs<T>(this IList<T> list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            yield return new IndexValue<T>(i, list[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -10):

`myKey = Array.IndexOf(values, val);`

Comment: That isn't a good idea. Array.IndexOf is basically a search with a worse case of O(n). Do that n times, can your total worse case becomes O(n^2).

In layman's terms, an array of 100 items could take up to 10000 comparisons.

Comment: Efficiency aside, if the array has duplicated items you'll get the index of the first one, not necessarily the one you're on. Consider an array of { 5, 14, 5, 29, ... }. When 'val' is 5 you'll always get zero even if you're on the third element.