# How can I Sort a List<int> using another List<int>?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, int

I need to Sort a List using another List.
I am trying to use :

```
var docsIds = new List<int>() { 1, 7, 4 };
var tileSizes = new List<int>();
tileSizes = tileSizes.OrderBy(x => docsIds.IndexOf());
```

Input : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Expected Output: 1,7,4,2,3,5,6

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Test input and expected output would be of help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945935/sort-one-list-by-another, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275269/sort-a-list-from-another-list-ids, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470098/list-sort-based-on-another-list, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227757/sort-one-list-based-on-another

Comment: @CodeCaster I cannot use this : docs = docs.OrderBy(d => docsIds.IndexOf(d.Id)).ToList(); as I don't have an Id inside the docs.

Comment: @JoseFrancis the input does not make it clear whether it's for the doccsIds or for tileSizes

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]. It's unclear what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto tileSizes will have 4,1,7 as a list of int and I need to sort it in order of docsIds.

Comment: @JoseFrancis why not just return docsIds then? It's not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: @CodeCaster edited the question.

Comment: If `tileSizes` will have `{ 4, 1, 7 }` then why don't you show that in your example? And show the actual output, not just the expected output. Or at least describe how it's not working. Below your code, you state that the Input is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`. What does `IndexOf` return if a value is not found in the lookup list? How does that affect your ordering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `tileSizes` only has values chosen from `docIds` (which seems to be the intent, though the question is a bit unclear), then the missing piece is a parameter to `IndexOf()`, specifically `IndexOf(x)`.

Then, `IndexOf()` returns an integer showing where in `docIds` the value would be, and `OrderBy()` can use that in sorting.

Oh, right.  And `OrderBy()` doesn't return a `List`, but rather an `Enumerable`, so you'll need a `ToList()` at the end.  Putting that all together, your last line should be something like...

```
tileSizes = tileSizes.OrderBy(x => docsIds.IndexOf(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually like to do things a bit more manually, so there is my solution:

```
List<int> randomItems = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
List<int> outputOrder = new List<int>(){0,6,3,1,2,4,5};
List<int> resultList = new List<int>();

foreach(int order in outputOrder)
{
    resultList.Add(randomItems[order]);
}
```

**Edited in order to replicate the OP values**

The resultList will contain: 1,7,4,2,3,5,6

Alternatively you can have the outputOrder like this:

```
List<int> outputOrder = new List<int>(){1,7,4,2,3,5,6};
```

and simply change the loop instruction to:

```
resultList.Add(randomItems[order--]);
```

And the result will be the same.

Comment: I know it's not the most efficient solution, but at least you can put a breakpoint and see what is happening and have control over it.

Comment: I think the OP wants the result list to be sorted based on the outputOrder list, which means it should be `{1, 2, 14, 95, 45}`

Comment: What if the lists don't have the same amount of values?

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto you can always and code (an "if") to prevent that situation and do whatever you want in that situation. IE some throw or error handling

Comment: This seems to be an answer to a different question that what the OP asked.

Comment: The `outputOrder` is not a list of indexes. It is a list of numbers that defines the hierarchy of those numbers. E.g. for an `outputOrder` of {1, 7, 4}, you must sort the list such that all 1's come before all 7's and all 7's come before all 4's and all 4's come before any number not in the list. This is not what you've answered here.

Answer (score 0):

If `tileSizes` are distinct and always contain all `docsIds`, [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731) can be used for an O(n) complexity:

```
tileSizes = docsIds.Union(tileSizes).ToList();        // { 1, 7, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6 }
```