# Pair-wise iteration in C#, or sliding window enumerator

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iterator, ienumerable

If I have an `IEnumerable` like:

```
string[] items = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
```

I would like to loop thru all the pairs of consecutive items (sliding window of size 2). Which would be

```
("a", "b"), ("b", "c"), ("c", "d")
```

My solution was is this

```
    public static IEnumerable<Pair<T, T>> Pairs(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) {
        IEnumerator<T> e = enumerable.GetEnumerator(); e.MoveNext();
        T current = e.Current;
        while ( e.MoveNext() ) {
            T next = e.Current;
            yield return new Pair<T, T>(current, next);
            current = next;
        }
    }
   
 // used like this :
 foreach (Pair<String,String> pair in IterTools<String>.Pairs(items)) {
    System.Out.PrintLine("{0}, {1}", pair.First, pair.Second)
 }
```

When I wrote this code, I wondered if there are already functions in the .NET framework that do the same thing and do it not just for pairs but for any size tuples.
IMHO there should be a nice way to do this kind of sliding window operations.

<sub>I use C# 2.0 and I can imagine that with C# 3.0 (using LINQ) there are more and nicer ways to do this, but I'm primarily interested in C# 2.0 solutions. Though, I will also appreciate C# 3.0 solutions.</sub>

Comment: This seems like it could share a lot of implementation with Jon Skeet's `SmartEnumerator` which tells you whether an item is the last in the list.  http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2007/07/27/smart-enumerations.aspx

Comment: For reference, this function is called 'Windowed' in F#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874901/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-f-seq-windowed-in-c

Comment: Somewhat related: [Get previous and next item in a IEnumerable using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759849/get-previous-and-next-item-in-a-ienumerable-using-linq).

Answer (score 62):

In .NET 4 this becomes even easier:-

```
var input = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
var result = input.Zip(input.Skip(1), (a, b) => Tuple.Create(a, b));
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this evaluates `input` twice - not a problem for an array, but if it's lazily-evaluated that could be expensive.

Comment: Also, the second argument to `Zip` can be passed as a method group: `…input.Zip(input.Skip(1), Tuple.Create);`

Comment: I just did this in a unit test, just to see the difference. With `Enumerable.Range(0, count)` as the iterator, I had to increase the count to ~1 million before the delay was noticeable, and ~10 million before it was slow enough to bother me. Still, @dahlbyk's solution elegantly avoids this, so I'd use that any day. (The whole *point* of extension methods is to be able to hide the not-extremely-readable code away from sight, so priorities here should be straightforward...).

Comment: @Jay, and since .NET Core 3.0 (from 2019) there is an overload that skips that argument entirely, so `var result = input.Zip(input.Skip(1));`.

Answer (score 47):

Rather than require a tuple (pair) type, why not just accept a selector:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Pairwise<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    TSource previous = default(TSource);

    using (var it = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (it.MoveNext())
            previous = it.Current;

        while (it.MoveNext())
            yield return resultSelector(previous, previous = it.Current);
    }
}
```

Which allows you to skip the intermediate object if you want:

```
string[] items = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
var pairs = items.Pairwise((x, y) => string.Format("{0},{1}", x, y));

foreach(var pair in pairs)
    Console.WriteLine(pair);
```

Or you can use an anonymous type:

```
var pairs = items.Pairwise((x, y) => new { First = x, Second = y });
```

**Update:** I just implemented this on a real project and used [C# 7.0 `ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) instead:

```
public static IEnumerable<(T, T)> Pairwise<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var previous = default(T);
    using (var it = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (it.MoveNext())
            previous = it.Current;

        while (it.MoveNext())
            yield return (previous, previous = it.Current);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder about the execution order in `yield return …(previous, previous = …)`. Does the C# language guarantee that the first argument will be prepared before the second argument is evaluated?

Comment: I'm reasonably certain it does, but I have to check the spec to be sure.

Comment: Yes it does, see [section 7.4.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691335%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of the C# spec. *"During the run-time processing of a function member invocation, the expressions or variable references of an argument list are evaluated in order, from left to right, as follows:..."*

Comment: Just wanted to chime in that I've done some performance analysis of this version and using a Queue with Dequeue/Peek and the Zip method. The Queue method is actually twice as fast as the GetEnumerator method and 6 times faster than Zip, and I consider it more readable than both. e.g.
    var queue = new Queue<T>(enumerable);
    while(queue.Count() > 1){
        yield return func(queue.Dequeue,queue.Peek);
    }

Comment: Very interesting... can you post your benchmark to a Gist or something?

Comment: @Novaterata Then your benchmarks are flawed. `GetEnumerator()` is always superior if used correctly. For a concrete `List<T>` you do not want to use its general enumerator, as explained in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet/62663221#62663221).

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way is to use ReactiveExtensions

```
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
```

and make yourself an extension method to kit bash this together

```
public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> Buffer<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, int bufferSize, int stepSize)
{
    return seq.ToObservable().Buffer(bufferSize, stepSize).ToEnumerable();
}
```

Comment: Rather than coerce to/from observable, the Interactive Extensions companion to Rx (https://www.nuget.org/packages/ix-main) ships with an `IEnumerable<T>` version of `Buffer()`: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/2252cb4edbb25aca12005b9a912311edd2f095f3/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive/EnumerableEx.Single.cs#L211-L229

Answer (score 6):

Just for convenience, here is a selector-less version of @dahlbyk's answer.

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> Pairwise<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    var previous = default(T);

    using (var e = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (e.MoveNext())
            previous = e.Current;

        while (e.MoveNext())
            yield return Tuple.Create(previous, previous = e.Current);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is even cleaner than the original. In modern C# this can be used as:

foreach (var (previous, next) in Enumerable.Range(0, 10).PairWise()) Console.WriteLine(previous + "-" + next);

Answer (score 5):

A little late to the party, but as an alternative to all these extension methods, one might use an actual "sliding" `Collection` to hold (and discard) the data.

Here is one I ended up making today:

```
public class SlidingWindowCollection<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    private int _windowSize;
    private Queue<T> _source;

    public SlidingWindowCollection(int windowSize)
    {
        _windowSize = windowSize;
        _source = new Queue<T>(windowSize);
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (_source.Count == _windowSize)
        {
            _source.Dequeue();
        }
        _source.Enqueue(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _source.Clear();
    }

    ...and just keep forwarding all other ICollection<T> methods to _source.
}
```

Usage:

```
int pairSize = 2;
var slider = new SlidingWindowCollection<string>(pairSize);
foreach(var item in items)
{
    slider.Add(item);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", slider));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution using a Stack. It is short and concise.

```
string[] items = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

Stack<string> stack = new Stack<string>(items.Reverse());

while(stack.Count > 1)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", stack.Pop(), stack.Peek());
}
```

You can take the same concept and use a queue which avoids the need for reversing the items and is even simpler:

```
var queue = new Queue<string>(items);

while (queue.Count > 1)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", queue.Dequeue(), queue.Peek());
}
```

A short word about performance:

I believe it's important to realize that unless you know that a task is causing a bottleneck in your real application, it's probably not worth working out what the truly fastest way of doing is. Instead, write the code which does the job for you. Also, use code you can remember, so it easily flows out of your hand the next time you need it.

Nevertheless, in case you care for some performance data for 10.000.000 random strings:

```
Run #1
  InputZip             00:00:00.7355567
  PairwiseExtension    00:00:00.5290042
  Stack                00:00:00.6451204
  Queue                00:00:00.3245580
  ForLoop              00:00:00.7808004
  TupleExtension       00:00:03.9661995

Run #2
  InputZip             00:00:00.7386347
  PairwiseExtension    00:00:00.5369850
  Stack                00:00:00.6910079
  Queue                00:00:00.3246276
  ForLoop              00:00:00.8272945
  TupleExtension       00:00:03.9415258
```

Tested using Jon Skeet's micro benchmarking tool.

If you want to take a look at the source for the test go here: [gist here](https://gist.github.com/Postlagerkarte/65fde9ea48b55e8dc6639d9b236bab97)

Comment: this is very inefficient, especially if the collection has lots of elements. Your space complexity is O(n) instead of O(1). Your time complexity is also O(n) as other solutions here, but still slower by a constant factor.

Comment: This isn't about premature optimization. You are doing more work than necessary with more code. This is just bad design.

Comment: Well, some of the better solutions on this page are generics methods that are ready to use and can be copy - pasted into a project with some minor parameter checking. Yours is just a 3 lines idea. And not a good one. You're increasing space complexity from very palatable O(1) to mediocre O(n) and doubling execution time at zero gain in anything.

Comment: @ZarShardan: I updated my answer with some benchmark results.

Comment: you're not testing the same thing. in PairwiseExtension you call String.Format which is far more taxing than Tuple<string,string>.Create. Try replacing it with James Holwell's solution and use ValueTuple instead of Tuple while you at it.
Furthermore, often iteration ends early. So maybe add .Take(N/2) before the ToList(). call, and in your solutions Count > N/2 where N is 10000000 in your test.

Comment: Indeed the string.format was influencing the results - i copy / pasted the original solutions - fixed that and changed all types to ValueTuple (good suggestion) also switched the test to use James Holwell's solution. Looking at the results, I don't think it is fair to call any of the given solutions "inefficient"

Comment: upvoted for the effort to test this. Still don't like your O(n) space solution :D

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577590/pair-wise-iteration-in-c-or-sliding-window-enumerator/577612#577612) to avoid of O(n<sup>2</sup>) approach by explicitly using the passed iterator:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Tuples<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, int groupCount) {
  if (null == input) throw new ArgumentException("input");
  if (groupCount < 1) throw new ArgumentException("groupCount");

  var e = input.GetEnumerator();

  bool done = false;
  while (!done) {
    var l = new List<T>();
    for (var n = 0; n < groupCount; ++n) {
      if (!e.MoveNext()) {
        if (n != 0) {
          yield return l;
        }
        yield break;
      }
      l.Add(e.Current);
    }
    yield return l;
  }
}
```

For C# 2, before extension methods, drop the "this" from the input parameter and call as a static method.

Comment: This doesn't return the result the question asks for. `Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Tuples(2)` returns `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5}}` instead of the desired `{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}` that is a sliding window.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Pairwise<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, T, TResult> selector)
{
    var previous = enumerable.First();
    foreach (var item in enumerable.Skip(1))
    {
        yield return selector(previous, item);
        previous = item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Forgive me if I'm overlooking something, but why not something simple, like a for loop?:

```
public static List <int []> ListOfPairs (int [] items)
{
    List <int> output = new List <int>();
    for (int i=0; i < items.Length-1; i++)
    {
        Int [] pair = new int [2];
        pair [0]=items [i];
        pair [1]=items [i+1];
        output.Add (pair);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# 3.0 solution (sorry:)

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Tuples<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int nTuple)
{
    if(nTuple <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("nTuple");

    for(int i = 0; i <= sequence.Count() - nTuple; i++)
        yield return sequence.Skip(i).Take(nTuple);
}
```

This isn't the most performant in the world, but it's sure pleasant to look at.

Really, the only thing making this a C# 3.0 solution is the .Skip.Take construct, so if you just change that to adding the elements in that range to a list instead, it should be golden for 2.0.  That said, it's still not performant.

Comment: Not the most performant? This is an O(n*n) implementation! For a small 10 item list, the entire list was traversed 20 times

Comment: That's true, but it's also two lines of (real) code and is an obviously simple implementation. It's up to the OP to decide whether he needs a fast solution -- maybe he only needs this operation on lists of a couple dozen items.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate `Pairs` implementation, using last pair to store previous value:

```
static IEnumerable<Pair<T, T>> Pairs( IEnumerable<T> collection ) {
  Pair<T, T> pair = null;
  foreach( T item in collection ) {
    if( pair == null )
      pair = Pair.Create( default( T ), item );
    else
      yield return pair = Pair.Create( pair.Second, item );
  }
}
```

Simple `Window` implementation (only safe for private use, if caller does not save returned arrays; see note):

```
static IEnumerable<T[]> Window( IEnumerable<T> collection, int windowSize ) {
  if( windowSize < 1 )
    yield break;

  int index = 0;
  T[] window = new T[windowSize];
  foreach( var item in collection ) {
    bool initializing = index < windowSize;

    // Shift initialized window to accomodate new item.
    if( !initializing )
      Array.Copy( window, 1, window, 0, windowSize - 1 );

    // Add current item to window.
    int itemIndex = initializing ? index : windowSize - 1;
    window[itemIndex] = item;

    index++;
    bool initialized = index >= windowSize;
    if( initialized )
      //NOTE: For public API, should return array copy to prevent 
      // modifcation by user, or use a different type for the window.
      yield return window;
  }
}
```

Example use:

```
for( int i = 0; i <= items.Length; ++i ) {
  Console.WriteLine( "Window size {0}:", i );
  foreach( string[] window in IterTools<string>.Window( items, i ) )
    Console.WriteLine( string.Join( ", ", window ) );
  Console.WriteLine( );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The F# `Seq` module defines the pairwise function over `IEnumerable<T>`, but this function is not in the .NET framework.

If it were already in the .NET framework, instead of returning pairs it would probably accept a selector function due to the lack of support for tuples in languages like C# and VB.

```
var pairs = ns.Pairwise( (a, b) => new { First = a, Second = b };
```

I don't think any of the answers here really improve on your simple iterator implementation, which seemed the most [natural](http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/the-ienumerable-pairwise-function-in-c/) to me (and the poster [dahlbyk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577590/pair-wise-iteration-in-c-or-sliding-window-enumerator#answer-1581482) by the looks of things!) too.

Comment: _lack of support for tuples in languages like C# and VB_ - back then in 2010 ? Seems available already.

Answer (score 0):

I created a slightly modified version of the late-2020-updated code in @dahlbyk's answer. It is better suited for projects with nullable reference types enabled (`<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`). I also added basic docs.

```
/// <summary>
/// Enumerates over tuples of pairs of the elements from the original sequence. I.e. { 1, 2, 3 } becomes { (1, 2), (2, 3) }. Note that { 1 } becomes { }.
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<(T, T)> Pairwise<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    using var it = source.GetEnumerator();
        
    if (!it.MoveNext())
        yield break;

    var previous = it.Current;

    while (it.MoveNext())
        yield return (previous, previous = it.Current);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make a single pass through the IEnumerable.

```
items.Aggregate(new List<string[]>(), (list, next) => { if (list.Count > 0) list[^1][1] = next; list.Add(new[] { next, next }); return list; }, (list) => { list.RemoveAt(list.Count -1); return list; });
```

Comment: The last chuck might have a single element, in which case your code will fail with an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias you are correct. Depending on how much control you have over the contents of your `items` you might have to take unintended number of items into account by using the `ElementAtOrDefault` method. When you increase the `Chunk` you will have to use `ElementAtOrDefault` method for all subsequent index after the `0`.

Comment: I think that this expression is preferable: `pairs.Length > 1 ? pairs[1] : default`. The `ElementAtOrDefault` will allocate an enumerator for each chuck, and the `Chuck` operator allocates an array per chunk already.

Comment: Amended the post in cases where one has no control over the contents of the list and performance is somewhat important.

Comment: Now it's better, but to be honest I am not a fan of casually introducing extension methods for common types, unless these methods can be useful in a wide range of scenarios. Admittedly though your answer is better than some heavily upvoted answers, like the one that double-enumerates the input with `input.Zip(input.Skip(1)`.

Comment: I guess it all depends what place this has in the code base. Is it a heavily used returning pattern but within the same library, one could at least consider to make it internal.

Comment: After reading the question more carefully, your answer does not produce the required output. The OP wants `("a", "b"), ("b", "c"), ("c", "d")`, not `("a", "b"), ("c", "d")`.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Changed the answer. This was even easier.

Comment: My understanding is that the OP has defined their problem in terms of a source `IEnumerable`, not an array or `IList`. The fact that they used an array as source in the example is accidental.

Comment: Haha, well we will get there ;-)

Comment: Now ([revision 5](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75347040/5)) you are enumerating the source multiple times, like in the flawed Ian Mercer's answer. An enumerable sequence might be deferred, and return different results each time (and different number of results). You can't assume that it is backed by a materialized collection.

Comment: Last one for today.

Comment: Upvoted for the effort. :-)

Answer (score -1):

New C# language allows to do something like this:

```
        var pairlist = new (string, string)[] { ("a", "b"), ("b", "c"), ("c", "d") };

        foreach (var pair in pairlist)
        {
            //do something with pair.Item1 & pair.Item2
```