# LINQ method to group collection into subgroups with specified number of elements

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, group-by

Does there exist a LINQ method to group a given collection into subgroups with specified number of elements I mean, something like Scala's `grouped` method. 

e.g. in Scala, `List(89, 67, 34, 11, 34).grouped(2)` gives `List(List(89, 67), List(34, 11), List(34))`.

In case such a method doesn't exist, what would be the LINQ way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split List into Sublists with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. But you can argue if it's very pretty...

```
  Int64[] aValues = new Int64[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
  var result = aValues
          .Select( ( x, y ) => new KeyValuePair<Int64, Int32>( x, y ) )
          .GroupBy( x => x.Value / 2 )
          .Select( x => x.Select( y => y.Key ).ToList() ).ToList();
```

How it works:

Select **x** and **y** from the original collection, where **x** is the actual value and **y** is the **index** of it in the given collection. Then **group by integer devision** of the index and the desired grouping length ( in this example **2** ).

Grouping by integer devision will round up to the lower - so **0 / 2 = 0**, **1 / 2 = 0**, etc. which will give us the needed grouping category value. This is what we are grouping against here.

For result select only the values grouped in lists and return them as a collection of lists.

Comment: Beautiful! Now could you please explain in brief how it works? I am not very well versed with LINQ you see.

Comment: Of course. Let me know if this explanation helps and if not, I'll try to come up with a better one.

Comment: No, this is enough. I like the trick. Thank you very much for the excellent answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try the approach shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577590/pair-wise-iteration-in-c-or-sliding-window-enumerator/577696#577696) to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577590/pair-wise-iteration-in-c-or-sliding-window-enumerator).

```
public static class GroupingExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Grouped<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> input,
        int groupCount)
    {
        if (input == null) throw new ArgumentException("input");
        if (groupCount < 1) throw new ArgumentException("groupCount");

        IEnumerator<T> e = input.GetEnumerator();

        while (true)
        {
            List<T> l = new List<T>();
            for (int n = 0; n < groupCount; ++n)
            {
                if (!e.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (n != 0)
                    {
                        yield return l;
                    }
                    yield break;
                }
                l.Add(e.Current);
            }
            yield return l;
        }
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
List<int> l = new List<int>{89, 67, 34, 11, 34};
foreach (IEnumerable<int> group in l.Grouped(2)) {
    string s = string.Join(", ", group.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Result:

```
89, 67
34, 11
34
```

Comment: By the way please use some different name for the method. The word tuple already has a meaning in context of C# / LINQ/ FP.

Comment: Do you have a good suggestion? `Grouped`? Something else? I didn't write the code, but I imagine that you can just change the name of the method without affecting how it works. It doesn't seem to call itself recursively or anything like that.

Comment: No. That's not the issue. Naming a method `Tupled` that doesn't do anything related to tuples would just confuse other people. `Grouped` or `GroupInto` would be fine IMO.

Comment: Upvoted your answer. Too bad I can't mark multiple answers as correct. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a website that seems to have some sample code to do what you want:
http://www.chinhdo.com/20080515/chunking/

So what you could do is take this method and create an extension method.

Extension method sample:

```
static class ListExtension
{
    public static List<List<T>> BreakIntoChunks<T>(this List<T> list, int chunkSize)
    {
        if (chunkSize <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("chunkSize must be greater than 0.");
        }

        List<List<T>> retVal = new List<List<T>>();

        while (list.Count > 0)
        {
            int count = list.Count > chunkSize ? chunkSize : list.Count;
            retVal.Add(list.GetRange(0, count));
            list.RemoveRange(0, count);
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd be happy if you post the code inline with a link to the original source.

Comment: With the code in the answer above you can not just call BreakIntoChunks(size) off of any List<T> you have. You just need to include the namespace from where you place the extension method.

Comment: Err... Comments is not exactly the right place to post the code. I suggest adding it to your answer instead.

Comment: Upvoted your answer. Too bad I can't mark multiple answers as correct. Thank you. :)