# Get previous and next item in a IEnumerable using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have an IEnumerable of a custom type. (That I've gotten from a SelectMany)

I also have an item (myItem) in that IEnumerable that I desire the previous and next item from the IEnumerable.

Currently, I'm doing the desired like this:

```
var previousItem = myIEnumerable.Reverse().SkipWhile( 
    i => i.UniqueObjectID != myItem.UniqueObjectID).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

I can get the next item by simply ommitting the `.Reverse`.

*or*, I could:

```
int index = myIEnumerable.ToList().FindIndex( 
    i => i.UniqueObjectID == myItem.UniqueObjectID)
```

and then use `.ElementAt(index +/- 1)` to get the previous or next item.

1. Which is better between the two options?
2. Is there an even better option available?

"Better" includes a combination of performance (memory and speed) and readability; with readability being my primary concern.

Comment: Considering readability, Your first option is awesome! Much better then in the answers. Will use it! Thanks!

Comment: I agree with @Aleksei, using that one too

Comment: My answer was really late but I added extension methods for NextOrLast, PreviousOrNext if you need book-ends, and fuction lookups so you can use LINQ.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First off

> "Better" includes a combination of performance (memory and speed)

In general you can't have both, the rule of thumb is, if you optimise for speed, it'll cost memory, if you optimise for memory, it'll cost you speed.

There is a better option, that performs well on both memory and speed fronts, and can be used in a readable manner (I'm not delighted with the function name, however, `FindItemReturningPreviousItemFoundItemAndNextItem` is a bit of a mouthful).

So, it looks like it's time for a custom find extension method, something like . . .

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindSandwichedItem<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> matchFilling)
{
    if (items == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
    if (matchFilling == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("matchFilling");

    return FindSandwichedItemImpl(items, matchFilling);
}

private static IEnumerable<T> FindSandwichedItemImpl<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> matchFilling)
{
    using(var iter = items.GetEnumerator())
    {
        T previous = default(T);
        while(iter.MoveNext())
        {
            if(matchFilling(iter.Current))
            {
                yield return previous;
                yield return iter.Current;
                if (iter.MoveNext())
                    yield return iter.Current;
                else
                    yield return default(T);
                yield break;
            }
            previous = iter.Current;
        }
    }
    // If we get here nothing has been found so return three default values
    yield return default(T); // Previous
    yield return default(T); // Current
    yield return default(T); // Next
}
```

You can cache the result of this to a list if you need to refer to the items more than once, but it returns the found item, preceded by the previous item, followed by the following item.  e.g.

```
var sandwichedItems = myIEnumerable.FindSandwichedItem(item => item.objectId == "MyObjectId").ToList();
var previousItem = sandwichedItems[0];
var myItem = sandwichedItems[1];
var nextItem = sandwichedItems[2];
```

The defaults to return if it's the first or last item may need to change depending on your requirements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Feels slightly overkill, but still a great answer.

Comment: I hate converting things to `List<>` just to make searching easier (sometimes it's not practical), and even if you're only ever going to do this once you'll need to code something similar. IMHO putting it in it's own function is a no brainer, making it generic is as easy as not. The only real issue I have with the code is the function name.

Comment: After fixing some minor build errors, and testing it appropriately, I have to say that I am impressed. This performs exactly as required and I like the readability of it. The main drawback (to me) is the I must call `.ToList()` to get the items; oh well. I also renamed the function to `FindSurroundingItems<T>` which is accurate enough for my purposes.

Comment: Sorry for build errors and lack of tests, it was just to give an idea of what the method should do _I also limit the time I spend "working" on SO answers :)_ You could always have it return a tuple with the three items, instead of yielding out the items.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: Good code, but there is an issue: What happens if none of the items match? Then nothing is returned. This requires analysis of the result by the caller. The correct action in case there is no matching item is to produce three `default(T)` items. I would be glad to upvote this answer once the proposed correction is implemented (hint: you will need to replace the `break;`  with `yield break;`).

Comment: @Dimitre: You are of course correct sir, the answer has been updated, I hope it meets with your approval :)

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: Yes it does now. :) +1 for a good and complete solution. BTW, I have given this method the name `FindTripple()`.

Comment: @Dimitre: Now that you've said that I want to call it `FindExcentraGallumbits()`

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: sounds funny and somewhat difficult to remember -- is this from Latin and/or abbreviations/acronyms?

Comment: Ah, forgive me, I misspelt it. It should be [Eccentrica Gallumbits](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Eccentrica_Gallumbits)

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: A better name: FindTriad.

Answer (score 22):

For readability, I'd load the `IEnumerable` into a linked list:

```
var e = Enumerable.Range(0,100);
var itemIKnow = 50;
var linkedList = new LinkedList<int>(e);
var listNode = linkedList.Find(itemIKnow);
var next = listNode.Next.Value; //probably a good idea to check for null
var prev = listNode.Previous.Value; //ditto
```

Comment: I really like this answer for readability; but it seems like it'd be a bit of a memory hog.

Comment: This is literally the whole point of a doubly-linked list, I don't understand why everyone is allergic to queues and linked lists on here. I would love to know if creating a Queue<T> or LinkedList<T> from another IEnumerable<T> even results in a copy. Seems like it could just use the original enumerable as pointers.

Comment: @novaterata: Creating (for example) a `Queue` from an `IEnumerable` will **copy** the references in the `IEnumerable`. So won't copy the objects pointed to by the `IEnumerable`, but it will copy references to those objects. It's as expensive as there are items in the sequence. If it was something I needed to do regularly in a loop I'd find another way. _that said I have nothing against Linked Lists and Queues, but I do dislike performing unnecessary copies_

Answer (score 14):

By creating an extension method for establishing context to the current element you can use a Linq query like this:

```
var result = myIEnumerable.WithContext()
    .Single(i => i.Current.UniqueObjectID == myItem.UniqueObjectID);
var previous = result.Previous;
var next = result.Next;
```

The extension would be something like this:

```
public class ElementWithContext<T>
{
    public T Previous { get; private set; }
    public T Next { get; private set; }
    public T Current { get; private set; }

    public ElementWithContext(T current, T previous, T next)
    {
        Current = current;
        Previous = previous;
        Next = next;
    }
}

public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<ElementWithContext<T>> 
        WithContext<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        T previous = default(T);
        T current = source.FirstOrDefault();

        foreach (T next in source.Union(new[] { default(T) }).Skip(1))
        {
            yield return new ElementWithContext<T>(current, previous, next);
            previous = current;
            current = next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you intended using `Concat` instead `Union`.

Comment: This solution is dangerous. Enumerating multiple times an `IEnumerable` of unknown origin should be avoided. It could cause multiple hits to a database, or to the filesystem, or to a web resource. If you have to do it, as a first step create a buffer with [`ToList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist).

Answer (score 4):

You could cache the enumerable in a list

```
var myList = myIEnumerable.ToList()
```

iterate over it by index

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
```

then the current element is `myList[i]`, the previous element is `myList[i-1]`, and the next element is `myList[i+1]`

(Don't forget about the special cases of the first and last elements in the list.)

Comment: The best way to do this is just to use Modulus `%` on the `[i-1]` `[i+1]` entries

Comment: Only if you want the element after the last element to be the first element, and vice versa

Comment: I think `.ToArray()` is slightly faster then `.ToList()`, and immediately demonstrate impossibility to modify, which is suitable here - for readablility.

Answer (score 3):

You are really over complicating things:

Sometimes just a `for` loop is going to be better to do something, and I think provide a clearer implementation of what you are trying to do/

```
var myList = myIEnumerable.ToList();

for(i = 0; i < myList.Length; i++)
{
   if(myList[i].UniqueObjectID == myItem.UniqueObjectID) 
   {
      previousItem = myList[(i - 1) % (myList.Length - 1)];
      nextItem = myList[(i + 1) % (myList.Length - 1)];
   }
}
```

Comment: Does IEnumerable support operator [] or property Length? Not as far as I know. This code is broken.

Comment: @spender ah meant to convert to a list first.

Comment: Isn't that going to be much the same as the OP's second method then except he uses FindIndex instead of a for loop?

Comment: @Chris, yep, was just pointing out that linq is most likely not required.

Comment: Yeah, you're right on that. I always assume that something like the FindIndex will be optimised enough that it is like your above one except potentially faster. Though I suppose actually the big difference is that you are doing it in one loop whereas potentially the ElementAt will need to run through again at least once more and probably twice... I guess that sort of thing is the trap of always going for Linq...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a LINQ extension method that returns the current item, along with the previous and the next. It yields [`ValueTuple<T, T, T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-3) values to avoid allocations. The source is enumerated once.

```
/// <summary>
/// Projects each element of a sequence into a tuple that includes the previous
/// and the next element.
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<(T Previous, T Current, T Next)> WithPreviousAndNext<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, T firstPrevious = default, T lastNext = default)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    (T Previous, T Current, bool HasPrevious) queue = (default, firstPrevious, false);
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (queue.HasPrevious)
            yield return (queue.Previous, queue.Current, item);
        queue = (queue.Current, item, true);
    }
    if (queue.HasPrevious)
        yield return (queue.Previous, queue.Current, lastNext);
}
```

Usage example:

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(1, 5);
Console.WriteLine($"Source: {String.Join(", ", source)}");
var result = source.WithPreviousAndNext(firstPrevious: -1, lastNext: -1);
Console.WriteLine($"Result: {String.Join(", ", result)}");
```

Output:

```
Source: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5  
Result: (-1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, -1)
```

To get the previous and the next of a specific item, you could use [tuple deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct):

```
var (previous, current, next) = myIEnumerable
    .WithPreviousAndNext()
    .First(e => e.Current.UniqueObjectID == myItem.UniqueObjectID);
```

Comment: Nice one Theodor, that's neat

Answer (score 2):

**CPU**

Depends entirely on where the object is in the sequence. If it is located at the end I would expect the second to be faster with more than a factor 2 (but only a constant factor). If it is located in the beginning the first will be faster because you don't traverse the whole list.

**Memory**

The first is iterating the sequence without saving the sequence so the memory hit will be very small. The second solution will take as much memory as the length of the list * references + objects + overhead.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would try to answer this using [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) from Linq.

```
string[] items = {"nought","one","two","three","four"};

var item = items[2];

var sandwiched =
    items
        .Zip( items.Skip(1), (previous,current) => new { previous, current } )
        .Zip( items.Skip(2), (pair,next) => new { pair.previous, pair.current, next } )     
        .FirstOrDefault( triplet => triplet.current == item );
```

This will return a anonymous type {previous,current,next}.
Unfortunately this will only work for indexes 1,2 and 3.

```
string[] items = {"nought","one","two","three","four"};

var item = items[4]; 

var pad1 = Enumerable.Repeat( "", 1 );
var pad2 = Enumerable.Repeat( "", 2 );

var padded = pad1.Concat( items );
var next1 = items.Concat( pad1 );
var next2 = items.Skip(1).Concat( pad2 );

var sandwiched =
    padded
        .Zip( next1, (previous,current) => new { previous, current } )
        .Zip( next2, (pair,next) => new { pair.previous, pair.current, next } )
        .FirstOrDefault( triplet => triplet.current == item );
```

This version will work for all indexes.
Both version use lazy evaluation courtesy of Linq.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some extension methods as promised. The names are generic and reusable with any type simple and there are lookup overloads to get at the item needed to get the next or previous items. I would benchmark the solutions and then see where you could squeeze cycles out.

```
 public static class ExtensionMethods  
{
    public static T Previous<T>(this List<T> list, T item) { 
        var index = list.IndexOf(item) - 1;
        return index > -1 ? list[index] : default(T);
    }
    public static T Next<T>(this List<T> list, T item) {
        var index = list.IndexOf(item) + 1;
        return index < list.Count() ? list[index] : default(T);
    }
    public static T Previous<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T, Boolean> lookup) { 
        var item = list.SingleOrDefault(lookup);
        var index = list.IndexOf(item) - 1;
        return index > -1 ? list[index] : default(T);
    }
    public static T Next<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T,Boolean> lookup) {
        var item = list.SingleOrDefault(lookup);
        var index = list.IndexOf(item) + 1;
        return index < list.Count() ? list[index] : default(T);
    }
    public static T PreviousOrFirst<T>(this List<T> list, T item) { 
        if(list.Count() < 1) 
            throw new Exception("No array items!");

        var previous = list.Previous(item);
        return previous == null ? list.First() : previous;
    }
    public static T NextOrLast<T>(this List<T> list, T item) { 
        if(list.Count() < 1) 
            throw new Exception("No array items!");
        var next = list.Next(item);
        return next == null ? list.Last() : next;
    }
    public static T PreviousOrFirst<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T,Boolean> lookup) { 
        if(list.Count() < 1) 
            throw new Exception("No array items!");
        var previous = list.Previous(lookup);
        return previous == null ? list.First() : previous;
    }
    public static T NextOrLast<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T,Boolean> lookup) { 
        if(list.Count() < 1) 
            throw new Exception("No array items!");
        var next = list.Next(lookup);
        return next == null ? list.Last() : next;
    }
}
```

And you can use them like this.

```
var previous = list.Previous(obj);
var next = list.Next(obj);
var previousWithLookup = list.Previous((o) => o.LookupProperty == otherObj.LookupProperty);
var nextWithLookup = list.Next((o) => o.LookupProperty == otherObj.LookupProperty);
var previousOrFirst = list.PreviousOrFirst(obj);
var nextOrLast = list.NextOrLast(ob);
var previousOrFirstWithLookup = list.PreviousOrFirst((o) => o.LookupProperty == otherObj.LookupProperty);
var nextOrLastWithLookup = list.NextOrLast((o) => o.LookupProperty == otherObj.LookupProperty);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following technique:

```
var items = new[] { "Bob", "Jon", "Zac" };

var sandwiches = items
                    .Sandwich()
                    .ToList();
```

Which produces this result:

[image]

Notice that there are nulls for the first `Previous` value, and the last `Next` value.

It uses the following extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<(T Previous, T Current, T Next)> Sandwich<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T beforeFirst = default, T afterLast = default)
{
    var sourceList = source.ToList();

    T previous = beforeFirst;
    T current = sourceList.FirstOrDefault();

    foreach (var next in sourceList.Skip(1))
    {
        yield return (previous, current, next);

        previous = current;
        current = next;
    }

    yield return (previous, current, afterLast);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Theodor, appreciate the help

Comment: `IEnumerable`s of unknown origin should not be enumerated multiple times!

Comment: Thats I would name as magnificient! Thanks, amigasssso!

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for every element in myIEnumerable I’d just iterate through it keeping references to the 2 previous elements. In the body of the loop I'd do the processing for the second previous element and the current would be its descendant and first previous its ancestor.

If you need it for only one element I'd choose your first approach.