# Get previous/next item of a given item in a List<>

Tags: c#, list

Says I have this List : 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13

For example, given value is : 9, the previous item is 7 and the next item is 13

How can I achieve this using C#?

Comment: Get the index of the given item. Add 1 to move next, subtract one to move prev. Make sure to check bounds.

Comment: index of +/- 1.... what have you tried?

Comment: What kind of list? It's very easy with a (doubly) linked list, like the `LinkedList<T>` class.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to find 7 and 13 because they are next to 9 in the list (position-wise), or because they are closest to 9 (math-wise)?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque how to do it through linked List?

Comment: Related: [Get previous and next item in a IEnumerable using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759849/get-previous-and-next-item-in-a-ienumerable-using-linq).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use *indexer* to get element at desired index.  Adding one to index will get you *next* and subtracting one from index will give you *previous* element.

```
int index = 4; 
int prev = list[index-1];
int next = list[index+1];
```

You will have to check if next and previous index exists other wise you will get [IndexOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx) exception. As List is **zero based index** so first element will have index `0` and second will have `1` and so on.

```
if(index - 1 > -1)
   prev = list[index-1];
if(index + 1 < list.Length)
   next = list[index+1];
```

Answer (score 38):

Using LINQ in one line and with circular search:

**Next of**

```
YourList.SkipWhile(x => x != NextOfThisValue).Skip(1).DefaultIfEmpty( YourList[0] ).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Previous of**

```
YourList.TakeWhile(x => x != PrevOfThisValue).DefaultIfEmpty( YourList[YourList.Count-1]).LastOrDefault();
```

**This is a working example [(link to the fiddle)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/McFPNu)**

```
    List<string> fruits = new List<string> {"apple", "banana", "orange", "raspberry", "kiwi"};
    string NextOf = "orange";
    string NextOfIs;

    NextOfIs = fruits.SkipWhile(x => x!=NextOf).Skip(1).DefaultIfEmpty(fruits[0]).FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine("The next of " + NextOf + " is " + NextOfIs);

    NextOf = "kiwi";
    NextOfIs = fruits.SkipWhile(x => x!=NextOf).Skip(1).DefaultIfEmpty(fruits[0]).FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine("The next of " + NextOf + " is " + NextOfIs);

    string PrevOf = "orange";
    string PrevOfIs;

    PrevOfIs = fruits.TakeWhile(x => x!=PrevOf).DefaultIfEmpty(fruits[fruits.Count-1]).LastOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine("The prev of " + PrevOf + " is " + PrevOfIs);

    PrevOf = "apple";
    PrevOfIs = fruits.TakeWhile(x => x!=PrevOf).DefaultIfEmpty(fruits[fruits.Count-1]).LastOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine("The prev of " + PrevOf + " is " + PrevOfIs);
```

Comment: I had to get an element two places before the known element and ended up reversing the list with `.Reverse()` and then using the first approach with `.Skip(2)`

Answer (score 13):

I have implemented this by Inheriting the .Net List

```
public class NavigationList<T> : List<T>
    {
        private int _currentIndex = 0;
        public int CurrentIndex
        {
            get
            {
                if (_currentIndex > Count - 1) { _currentIndex = Count - 1; }
                if (_currentIndex < 0) { _currentIndex = 0; }
                return _currentIndex;
            }
            set { _currentIndex = value; }
        }

        public T MoveNext
        {
            get { _currentIndex++; return this[CurrentIndex]; }
        }

        public T MovePrevious
        {
            get { _currentIndex--; return this[CurrentIndex]; }
        }

        public T Current
        {
            get { return this[CurrentIndex]; }
        }
    }
```

Using this becomes quite easy

```
 NavigationList<string> n = new NavigationList<string>();
            n.Add("A");
            n.Add("B");
            n.Add("C");
            n.Add("D");
            Assert.AreEqual(n.Current, "A");
            Assert.AreEqual(n.MoveNext, "B");
            Assert.AreEqual(n.MovePrevious, "A");
```

Comment: Having a getter of a property which modifies the internal state of the object seems pretty bad practice (``MoveNext`` and `MovePrevious`). Better make them functions. Also having `_currentIndex` which can point to an invalid index seems odd. Better use the setter to correct the index (rather than having the getter doing the same work). But I still like the approach!

Comment: I will concur with @JackMiller's points above, but I did give the answer a +1.  A wrapper class for solving your need is an elegant approach and makes your code that uses the wrapper easier to read.  LINQ is bitchen for a lot of things.. but it can be difficult to read/follow when things get complicated.

Comment: combining this answer with [@Melad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42714127/6157415) answer you can obtain a complete **circular list** in **both direction**, it's awesome!

Answer (score 8):

```
        List<int> listInts = new List<int>();
        listInts.AddRange(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13 });
        int index = listInts.IndexOf(3); //The index here would be "1"
        index++; //Check first if the index is in the length
        int element = listInts[index]; //element = 5
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 8):

Also if you want compact solution with circular logic without creating new list you can use following code:

```
int nextNumber = list[(list.IndexOf(currentNumber) + 1) % list.Count];
int previousNumber = list[(list.IndexOf(currentNumber) - 1 + list.Count) % list.Count];
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/PkP2Jy

Answer (score 6):

Following may be helpful

```
 int NextValue = 0;
 int PreviousValue =0;
 int index = lstOfNo.FindIndex(nd =>nd.Id == 9);

 var Next = lstOfNo.ElementAtOrDefault(index + 1);
 var Previous = lstOfNo.ElementAtOrDefault(index - 1);

 if (Next != null)
     NextValue = Next;


if (Previous != null)
   PreviousValue = Previous;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int index = list.IndexOf(9); // find the index of the given number

// find the index of next and the previous number
// by taking into account that 
// the given number might be the first or the last number in the list
int prev = index > 0 ? index - 1 : -1;

int next = index < list.Count - 1 ? index + 1 : -1;

int nextItem, prevItem;

// if indexes are valid then get the items using indexer 
// otherwise set them to a temporary value, 
// you can also use Nullable<int> instead
nextItem = prev != -1 ? list[prev] : 0;
prevItem = next != -1 ? list[next] : 0;
```

Comment: It could be confusing. What if element of list is `0`? Then we couldn't determine wheter there is no next / prev element on list or just it's just element on list.

Comment: @pwas yes I guess using Nullable<int> would be a better idea

Answer (score 3):

```
var index = list.IndexOf(9);
if (index == -1) 
{
   return; // or exception - whater, no element found.
}

int? nextItem = null; //null means that there is no next element.
if (index < list.Count - 1) 
{
   nextItem = list[index + 1];
}

int? prevItem = null;
if (index > 0) 
{
   prevItem = list[index - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make it a kind of Circular list, try this:

```
public class NavigationList<T> : List<T>
{
    private int _currentIndex = -1;
    public int CurrentIndex
    {
        get
        {
            if (_currentIndex == Count)
                _currentIndex = 0;
            else if (_currentIndex > Count - 1)
                _currentIndex = Count - 1;
            else if (_currentIndex < 0)
                _currentIndex = 0;


            return _currentIndex;
        }

        set { _currentIndex = value; }
    }

    public T MoveNext
    {
        get { _currentIndex++; return this[CurrentIndex]; }
    }

    public T Current
    {
        get { return this[CurrentIndex]; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `LinkedList<T>`

```
List<int> intList = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13 };

LinkedList<int> intLinkedList = new LinkedList<int>(intList);

Console.WriteLine("Next Value to 9 "+intLinkedList.Find(9).Next.Value);

Console.WriteLine("Next Value to 9 " +intLinkedList.Find(9).Previous.Value);

//Consider using dictionary for frequent use
var intDictionary = intLinkedList.ToDictionary(i => i, i => intLinkedList.Find(i));    

Console.WriteLine("Next Value to 9 " + intDictionary[9].Next.Value);

Console.WriteLine("Next Value to 9 " + intDictionary[9].Previous.Value);

Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 2):

Approach with `ElementOrDefault()`

https://dotnetfiddle.net/fxVo6T

```
int?[] items = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13  };
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    int? previous = items.ElementAtOrDefault(i - 1);
    int? current = items.ElementAtOrDefault(i);
    int? next = items.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1);
}
```

Comment: Hey! It looks clear and simple as God's love. Thank you bro!

Answer (score 2):

this is a fully circle list obtained combining [@Thunder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37878827/6157415) and [@Melad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42714127/6157415) answers:

```
private class CircularList<T> : List<T>
    {
        private int _currentIndex = 0;
        public int CurrentIndex
        {
            get
            {
                if (_currentIndex > Count - 1) { _currentIndex = 0; }
                if (_currentIndex < 0) { _currentIndex = Count - 1; }
                return _currentIndex;
            }
            set => _currentIndex = value;
        }
        
        public int NextIndex
        {
            get
            {
                if (_currentIndex == Count - 1) return 0;
                return _currentIndex + 1;
            }
        }
        
        public int PreviousIndex
        {
            get
            {
                if (_currentIndex == 0) return Count - 1;
                return _currentIndex - 1;
            }
        }
        
        public T Next => this[NextIndex];

        public T Previous => this[PreviousIndex];

        public T MoveNext
        {
            get { _currentIndex++; return this[CurrentIndex]; }
        }

        public T MovePrevious
        {
            get { _currentIndex--; return this[CurrentIndex]; }
        }

        public T Current => this[CurrentIndex];
        
        
    }
}
```

[check git-repo with example here](https://github.com/d3w201/CircleList/blob/master/Main/Program.cs)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe extend the class List :

```
public static class ListExtension
{
    public static T Next<T>(this List<T> list, T elt)
    {
        int index = list.IndexOf(elt);
        index = (index == list.Count - 1) ? 0 : index + 1;
        return list[index];
    }
    public static T Prev<T>(this List<T> list, T elt)
    {
        int index = list.IndexOf(elt);
        index = (index == 0) ? list.Count - 1 : index - 1;
        return list[index];
    }
}
```

to use the extend functions :
List<anything> list;

list.Next(elt) give the element which follows elt and list.Prev(elt) the element which precedes elt

Answer (score 0):

Return null if the item is not found or if it is the last element in the list

```
 List<string> fruits = new List<string> { "apple", "banana",  "kiwi" };
    var index = fruits.IndexOf("banana");
    var nextFruit = index==-1 ?null : fruits.Skip(index+1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.