# How to access the next and previous items within a foreach iteration over an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable

I want to access the next and previous items (if within range) while processing the current item and iterating over `IEnumerable<object>`, which lacks an indexer (as far as I know).

I wouldn't want to require a `List<object>` collection instead or an array in order to accomplish this, although it's the only option that I know of right now.

I'd also prefer to avoid Linq expressions if possible.

That's how my method is defined at the moment:

```
public static void PrintTokens(IEnumerable<object> tokens)
{
    foreach (var token in tokens)
    {
        // var next = ?
        // var prev = ?
    }
}
```

Comment: What are `next` and `prev` at the boundaries? Do you want to start looping at the second item and finish at the second-to-last, or should `prev` be `null` when you're looping over the first item, or...?

Comment: With an enumerable you can only deal with the current item, but you can keep track of previous ones.  So instead of thinking about previous, current, and next instead think about keeping track of the previous two values and the current would be the "next" value.

Comment: What is the point of limiting yourself by removing Linq and List?

Comment: `Lag` or `Lead` (or likely both at the same time) may be useful. https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#lag

Comment: [IEnumerable is an Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=netframework-4.7.2) which does not contain prev and next and you have to implement those yourself

Comment: @canton7, yes, `prev` and `next` would equal to `null` at the boundaries.

Comment: Do you have problem using `for` loop and track the items yourself, which is lot more extensible as per your need and a bit faster as well sometimes?

Comment: @mjwills, actually the real code in my project is very similar to what I've posted, except that I removed the `switch` body from the `foreach` iteration because it  (how each type of `token` is being treated) has hardly anything to do with the question itself. To be even more specific - it's a method that prints each token according to its type, but it also has to decide where to print spaces between tokens according to the previous the upcoming next token.

Comment: @mjwills, if the next token is a `char` and its value is either `'('`, `')'`, `','` or `null` (meaning it's the last token in the input), then no space character (`' '`) should be printed at the end of the current iteration.

Comment: Related: [Get previous and next item in a IEnumerable using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759849/get-previous-and-next-item-in-a-ienumerable-using-linq)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do your loop as normal, but the item you're currently on becomes `next`, the previous item is `current`, and the item before that is `prev`.

```
object prev = null;
object current = null;
bool first = true;
foreach (var next in tokens)
{
    if (!first)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing {0}. Prev = {1}. Next = {2}", current, prev, next);
    }

    prev = current;
    current = next;
    first = false;
}

// Process the final item (if there is one)
if (!first)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Processing {0}. Prev = {1}. Next = {2}", current, prev, null);
}
```

If you're using C# 7.0+, you can write

```
(prev, current, first) = (current, next, false);
```

instead of the three separate statements at the end of the loop.

Comment: You'd actually want to go past the second one to make sure you have a previous, current and next

Comment: He said in the comments on his question he wanted to start with `prev = null`, and end with `next = null`. The output matches what he said he wanted: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gAMADO

Comment: You actually need that last statement inside of a `if(!first)` in case `tokens` is empty.

Comment: I'm testing this right now, just a few moments and I'll mark this as an answer if it works for me, I really appreciate all the quick help!

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an extension method which returns a tuple with 3 objects: previous, current and next:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T, T>> GetItems<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        where T : class
    {
        if (source != null)
        {
            // skip the first iteration to be able to include next item
            bool skip = true;
            T previous = default(T), current = default(T), next = default(T);
            foreach (T item in source)
            {
                next = item;
                if (!skip)
                {
                    yield return new Tuple<T, T, T>(previous, current, next);
                }
                previous = current;
                current = item;
                skip = false;
            }
            if (!skip)
            {
                next = default(T);
                yield return new Tuple<T, T, T>(previous, current, next);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. Maybe extend with custom class instead of tuple.

Comment: Use ValueTuple - save on a few allocations!

Comment: Bear in mind this will not work if `source` contains items which are `null` - it gets confused. It also won't work correctly if `source` is empty.

Comment: By `Use ValueTuple`, I meant `IEnumerable<(T previous, T current, T next)>`, etc, using the C# 7 tuple syntax.

Comment: @canton7 Ah ok. Was already somewhat confused... Makes sense, will update.

Comment: Scratch that, I want to leave it as is to support earlier versions of the C# spec and compiler.

Comment: Fair! The comments about `source` containing `null` or being empty still apply.

Comment: @canton7 Yes you are absolutely right. Will update, thanks.

Comment: Almost there! Just need a `if (!skip)` test around that final `yield return`, to handle the case where `source` is empty.

Comment: @canton7 :) should have read your answer and the comments to it better...

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, wouldn't a for loop be the simplest and most efficient method?

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Count(); i++)
{
    token previous = i > 0 ? tokens[i - 1] : null;
    token current = tokens[i];
    token next = i < tokens.Count() ? tokens[i + 1] : null;
}
```

Then your current loop index is for the actual loop item, and previous and next are easy to get, no need for "your current loop object is the previous object", and no need for a separate 'if' outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

U can try this extention method. It is get "size" previous item and "size" next items and current item:

```
    public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source, int size, System.Func<Queue<TSource>, TSource, Queue<TSource>, TResult> selector)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("source");
        }

        if (selector == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("selector");
        }
        Queue<TSource> prevQueue = new Queue<TSource>(size);
        Queue<TSource> nextQueue = new Queue<TSource>(size);

        int i = 0;
        foreach (TSource item in source)
        {
            nextQueue.Enqueue(item);
            if (i++ >= size)
            {
                TSource it = nextQueue.Dequeue();
                yield return selector(prevQueue, it, nextQueue);
                prevQueue.Enqueue(it);
                if (prevQueue.Count > size)
                {
                    prevQueue.Dequeue();
                }
            }
        }

        while (nextQueue.Any())
        {
            TSource it = nextQueue.Dequeue();
            yield return selector(prevQueue, it, nextQueue);
            prevQueue.Enqueue(it);
            if (prevQueue.Count > size)
            {
                prevQueue.Dequeue();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an extension method that Microsoft provides in its documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementatordefault?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-elementatordefault-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-index)), and then use `ElementAtOrDefault<T>()` inside of your foreach loop like:

```
foreach (var el in elements) {
...
  var prev = elements.ElementAtOrDefault(el - 1);
  var current = el; //This is redundant, but shown for clarity
  var next = el.ElementAtOrDefault(el + 1);
...
}
```

It looks like this:

```
public static TSource? ElementAtOrDefault<TSource> (
this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source, Index index);
```

And here is an example:

```
string[] names =
{ "Hartono, Tommy", "Adams, Terry", "Andersen, Henriette Thaulow",
    "Hedlund, Magnus", "Ito, Shu" };

 int index = 20;

 string name = names.ElementAtOrDefault(index);

 Console.WriteLine( 
"The name chosen at index {0} is '{1}'.",
 index,
 String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? "<no name at this index>" : name);
```

Answer (score -1):

From documentation:

> IEnumerable exposes an enumerator, which **supports a simple iteration**.

So to achieve what you want, you can follow one of four ways:

- Invoking `ToList()` on tokens variable - this way you can access items by index
- Use `ElementAt()` method on IEnumerable, but it would lack performance, as tokens would be enumerated everytime you call this method
- As you proposed, change `IEnumerable<object> tokens` to `IList<object> tokens`
- Write custom loop which saves previous, current and next items (next would actually be the current item in your loop)

Answer (score -2):

I think a raw `IEnumerable` doesn't provide this, but [LinkedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) offers it.

Comment: Because it doesn't answer the question, I assume?