# Update object in collections based on previous object value in collection using lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

This I have used regular code but can I use lambda or linq for this do it in one go. 
Update object in collections based in it previous object value using lambda

```
foreach (var city in frontcities)
{
    if (first== false)
    {
        // previous = city.CitySchduletime.Where(item => item.Schduletimestart == hour).FirstOrDefault().Schduletimestart;
        previous = city.CitySchduletime.Where(item => item.Schduletimestart == hour).FirstOrDefault().Schduletimestop;
        first = true;
    }
    else
    {
        DateTimeOffset ts = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(previous).AddHours(defaultgap);

        int eta = 600;
        long start = ts.AddSeconds(eta).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
        previous = ts.AddSeconds(eta).AddHours(1).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
        SchduleTime schduleTime = city.CitySchduletime.Where(item => item.Schduletimestart == hour).FirstOrDefault();
        schduleTime.Schduletimestop = previous;
        schduleTime.Schduletimestart = start;
      //  city.CitySchduletime.Where(item => item.Schduletimestart == hour).FirstOrDefault().Schduletimestart = start;
        //city.CitySchduletime.Where(item => item.Schduletimestart == hour).FirstOrDefault().Schduletimestop = previous;
        //Caculate Eta betwen next city and this city
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to update anything using lambda. It goes against functional programming and against `Q` in LINQ.

Comment: Please note when you're finding `previous` or `schduleTime` in your code, you can get in trouble and get an exception.

Comment: This might help: [Get previous and next item in a IEnumerable using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759849/get-previous-and-next-item-in-a-ienumerable-using-linq/58778597#58778597)

Comment: @CodingYoshi Where exactly

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` may return null and you will get an exception. If you know for sure it can never be null, use `First()`.

Comment: Yes, i handle this thanks

Answer (score 1):

I often define an extension method that looks something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<(T Previous, T Current)> CurrentAndPrevious<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self)
    {
        using(var iter = self.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (iter.MoveNext())
            {
                var previous = iter.Current;
                while (iter.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return (previous, iter.Current);
                    previous = iter.Current;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Used like

```
foreach(var (previous, current) in myList.CurrentAndPrevious())
 {
            ...
 }
```