# Returning list that satisfy conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists filled with `(x, y)` data points; one of the lists being the main list and the other being a list I want to compare against.

So for example, in the **main** list I try to find "gaps" in the data; say I'm looking at two `x` data points `x1 = 21` and `x2 = 24`. The difference between those two points is greater than `deltaX = 1`. So what I'd like to do, is look through the **second** list, and find all data points between `x1 = 21` and `x2 = 24` to "fill in the gap".

I have something like this:

```
double diffX = Math.Abs(datapoints1[i + 1].X - datapoints1[i].X);

if (diffX > deltaX)
{
    datapoints1.AddRange(LookBetween(datapoints1[i + 1].X, datapoints1[i].X);
}
.
.
.
private IEnumerable<PointXY> LookBetween(double upperLimit, double lowerLimit)
{
    return datapoints2.Where(x => x.X < upperLimit && x.X > lowerLimit);
}
```

`LookBetween` seems to return a boolean because nothing gets added to the main list. How can I get it to return a list of the `x, y` values that match the criteria based on the gap of `x`?

Comment: *"Obviously, LookBetween returns a boolean."*, no, it returns a `IEnumerable<PointXY>`, can you clarify what you meant?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? It seems to me that the code you've given already does what you describe. And your last sentence didn't make much sense...

Comment: @ScottChamerlain I said that it returns a boolean, because thats what it seems like. When I step through the code, nothing gets added to the main list.

Comment: It seems to me that you can just union `datapoints1` with the values of `datapoints2` that are between the min and max of `datapoints1`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to do a [pairwise iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1581482/54249) through neighbors in `datapoints1`.

Using the function linked above, you might have something like:

```
var pairs = datapoints1.Pairwise((d1, d2) => new
{
    x1 = d1.X,
    x2 = d2.X, 
    diffX = Math.Abs(d1.X - d2.X),
});
var gaps = from pair in pairs
           where pair.diffX > deltaX
           from dp2 in datapoints2
           where pair.x1 < dp2.X && dp2.X < pair.x2
           select dp2;
```

Or using your `LookBetween` function...

```
var gaps = from pair in pairs
           where pair.diffX > deltaX
           from dp2 in LookBetween(pair.x2, pair.x1)
           select dp2;
```

Comment: Doesn't work :/ When I step through the code, I get: `"Enumeration yielded no results"`. And I checked, and there are several gaps where it should have identified and filled them in from the other list...

Comment: @John I think that at that point, you should provide a test case. An example of datapoints1, datapoints2 and the expected result.

Comment: Yeah, we're really flying blind here. Your description suggests `datapoints1` is sorted...is that the case?