# Is there a built-in extension methods on collections like Apply?

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for a built-in extension method like Apply:

```
collection.Apply (predicate)
```

which will apply a method on all items contained in the collection.

I am asking first so that I don't write something that already exists.

EDIT: The reason I didn't use foreach was because I want to express the method using LINQ.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ equivalent of foreach for IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there's `List<T>.ForEach`, but nothing on `IEnumerable<T>`. It's the kind of thing that's in plenty of 3rd party "extra extension methods" toolkits though :)

I'd agree with the other answers that `foreach` is usually a better way to go - although it could occasionally make the difference between:

```
DoSomething(x => x.Where(...).Select(...).ForEach(...));
```

and

```
DoSomething(x => {
    foreach (var y in x.Where(...).Select(...)) {
        (...)
    }
});
```

which is more significant than just a single line.

I think I'd *usually* only use such a method if I already had a delegate to hand, or potentially a method group. For example, it's quite nice to be able to have a one-liner to dump a filtered collection:

```
people.Where(p => p.Age >= 18).ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

It's possible that after more exposure to functional programming I'd use it more often though.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Do you know any such toolkits for EMs? I checked the net but it shows more documentation than any toolkits/classes.

Comment: Well, there's my own MoreLINQ project to start with: http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/

Comment: Thanks Jon, I am gonna yours :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there isn't one for `IEnumerable<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, or `IList<T>`.

The `List<T>` class, however, has a generic [`ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) method (built-in, not extension), which you can use as such:

```
list.ForEach(delegate);
```

Personally, I don't any real value to such methods. A simple foreach loop uses a single line more and offers the same usability, but there's nothing stopping you from writing one yourself of course.

Answer (score 1):

Well I for one can't live without the basic `ForEach(...)` extension method, maybe because I've swallowed the functional pill or something.

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Action<T> action)
{
    if (sequence == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

    foreach (T t in sequence)
        action(t);
}
```

Some might say this just saves a couple of lines of code. 
But I think there is more to it than that: It saves a variable declaration and my personal favorite is that it plays really well with intellisense.

i.e.

```
people.Where(p => p.Age < 38)
      .Select(p => p.Firstname + " " + p.Surname)
      .ForEach(fullname => Console.WriteLine(fullname));
```

Is both much easier and quicker to write than the foreach loop because of the power of intellisense.

Never underestimate the importance of intellisense in API design.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if there is something like that but why don't you use foreach, since you are applying that method on all the items.