# Linq style "For Each"

Tags: c#, .net, linq, foreach

Is there any Linq style syntax for "For each" operations?

For instance, add values based on one collection to another, already existing one:

```
IEnumerable<int> someValues = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };

IList<int> list = new List<int>();

someValues.ForEach(x => list.Add(x + 1));
```

Instead of

```
foreach(int value in someValues)
{
  list.Add(value + 1);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerable

Comment: See also this blog post from Eric Lippert, regarding the rationale for not including `ForEach` in the BCL: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: Original link to Eric Lippert's blog post is dead. [Wayback machine link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100220102439/http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Answer (score 354, accepted):

Using the ToList() extension method is your best option:

```
someValues.ToList().ForEach(x => list.Add(x + 1));
```

There is no extension method in the BCL that implements ForEach directly.

---

Although there's no extension method in the *BCL* that does this, there *is* still an option in the `System` namespace... if you add [Reactive Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Main) to your project:

```
using System.Reactive.Linq;

someValues.ToObservable().Subscribe(x => list.Add(x + 1));
```

This has the same end result as the above use of `ToList`, but is (in theory) more efficient, because it streams the values directly to the delegate.

Comment: Bear in mind that this isn't ideal for a very long list, as it makes a copy of the entire list before looping through it.

Comment: Calling `ToList` followed by `ForEach` involves iterating through the original collection twice. I'd prefer a standard `foreach` loop any day: less typing, more readable and better performance: `foreach (var x in someValues) list.Add(x + 1);`

Comment: For anyone who sees this and thinks its a good answer, its not. It is crazy inefficient. See Noldorin's answer for the correct way to do things.

Comment: @Steve: Thanks for pointing that out. Indeed, this is not the best solution because it means the collection is iterated over twice, and memory is temporarily allocated for the `List<T>`, adding more overhead!

Comment: @Stefan: Not sure how mine was not "correct". You really don't want to be using this less performant method just because it saves you writing a 3 line extension method.

Comment: Fair points all, but I'd like to add this: It may be inefficient in theory, but most in-memory lists I work with tend to have less than a dozen items. Perf. problems are usually somewhere else, so I think it is a premature optimization to categorically state that this answer is bad. The question was whether this *syntax* is available, and this is as close as you get on plain vanilla .NET 3.5 SP1 without writing the extension method yourself. I would love to have a ForEach extension method in the BCL, but it's not available in the current framework.

Comment: @Mark: Your code's ineffiency might be forgivable if it was more readable/understandable/intuitive than the alternatives, but it's not. What's the benefit of using your code rather than a standard `foreach` loop?

Comment: @Luke: There's no particular benefit, but that wasn't the question either. In any case I think this is a storm in a teacup: in most cases I bet you can't feel the perf diff at all.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't be complaining about the performance either, if the more efficient solution weren't so very simple. (Using the foreach loop or a short extension method.) Meh, I haven't down-voted anyway.

Comment: @MarkSeemann in my testing the new answer of `someValues.ToObservable().Subscribe(...)` seems to be around 50 times slower than `ToList().ForEach(...)` and `Select(...).ToList()`

Comment: @qujck but *in theory*, it's much more efficient! ;)

Comment: Honestly – and I'm trying to be constructive here – I think the addendum that converts to an Observable and attaches a Subscriber just for a `foreach` brought an already questionable answer into "wrong" answer territory

Answer (score 127):

The [`Array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2.aspx) and [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) classes already have `ForEach` methods, though only this specific implementation. (Note that the former is `static`, by the way).

Not sure it really offers a great advantage over a `foreach` statement, but you could write an extension method to do the job for all `IEnumerable<T>` objects.

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
        action(item);
}
```

This would allow the exact code you posted in your question to work just as you want.

Comment: Thanks, It's clear that I could write the extension myself. I just want to use built in stuff as far as possible before doing this.

Comment: Yeah, that's fair enough. I also make sure I'm not reinventing BCL functionality too. In this case, there's none however.

Comment: Array class doesn't have a ForEach method :) but there is a "EnumerableExtensions" statşc class in Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2 namespace. it has foreach method for IEnumerable :)

Answer (score 37):

There isn't anything built-in, but you can easily create your own extension method to do it:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why isn't there anything built in?  Am I missing something?  This seems like much needed basic functionality.

Comment: @DanCsharpster because linq methods aren't supposed to have side effects

Answer (score 21):

The official MS line is "because it's not a functional operation" (ie it's a stateful operation).

Couldn't you do something like:

```
list.Select( x => x+1 )
```

or if you really need it in a List:

```
var someValues = new List<int>( list.Select( x => x+1 ) );
```

Comment: You have a point about functional vs. stateful operations. However, F# was designed as a functional length, and has an equivalent `ForEach` method.

Comment: Can you give a reference for "The official MS line"? I'm interested in reading the rest of their take.

Comment: I probably shouldn't have used the word "official", but this is the blog I was thinking of: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Answer (score 6):

There is no Linq ForEach extension. However, the `List` class has a ForEach method on it, if you're willing to use the `List` directly.

For what it's worth, the standard `foreach` syntax will give you the results you want and it's probably easier to read:

```
foreach (var x in someValues)
{
    list.Add(x + 1);
}
```

If you're adamant you want an Linq style extension. it's trivial to implement this yourself.

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> @this, Action<T> action)
{
   foreach (var x in @this)
      action(x);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There isn't anything like that in standard Linq, but there is a ForEach operator in [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).