# Unexpected result with Where()

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code, which is supposed to return a value type, applying at each step the transformations specified in `steps`.

```
private static T Transformed<T>(T x, params Func<T, T>[] steps) where T : struct
{
     if ((steps?.Length ?? 0) == 0)
     {
        return x;
     }

     var reallyEmpty = steps.Where(f => (x = f(x)).Equals(int.MinValue));
     return x;
}
```

I only need the `Where` extension to get through each step without using a loop, thus I use a condition which could probably never be true (`Equals(int.MinValue)`).
But if I have this calling code, I get `5` and not `15`, how I'd expect.

```
int res1 = Transformed(5, x => x * 2, x => x + 5);
Console.WriteLine(res1);
```

My question is why? Doesn't `Where` go through each element and check it?

Comment: You aren't iterating over `reallyEmpty` so the side-effect `x = f(x)` is never executed.

Comment: If you are a big fan of linq, you can create [ForEach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1509458/1997232) extension and never ever again confuse yourself or others.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Where` is lazily evaluated - you're never using the result of it, so the predicates are never being evaluated.

You *could* force iteration by counting the results or similar:

```
var ignored  steps.Where(f => (x = f(x)).Equals(int.MinValue)).Count();
```

... but it would be significantly clearer to just loop yourself:

```
foreach (var step in steps) 
{
    x = step(x);
}
```

After all, you're not *really* avoiding a loop by using `Where` - you're just hiding it, and in doing so you're overcomplicating your code to the extent that you don't understand it any more.

Answer (score 2):

If you're really set on using LINQ, it's possible to do what you want using `Aggregate`:

```
private static T Transformed<T>( T x, params Func<T, T>[] steps ) where T : struct
{
    return steps?.Aggregate( x, ( accum, f ) => f( accum ) ) ?? x;
}
```

I don't typically find aggregate particularly readable, but I figured it was worth mentioning.