# C#: Is There A ForAny Statement?

Tags: c#, foreach, radio-button

Quick question, I know there is a `foreach` statement that checks each specified control in a form, but is there a `forany` statement that can check for a specific control amongst a group of the same types of controls, or is there a certain specification I can use in a `foreach` state that limits it. For example: Say I check if ANY RadioButton on a form is checked. If one is checked, it a message box will display "Hi". My approach would go something like:

```
foreach (Control rb in this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
{
    if(((RadioButton(rb)).Checked == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hi");
        return;
    }
}
```

The problem with this is it checks ALL RadioButtons and sees if they are checked. I don't want that. I want it to check if anyone of the are checked. Is there a way I can manipulate this?

Comment: No, your current approach checks only until it has found a checked radiobutton

Comment: @TimSchmelter Does it check every specified control?

Comment: You could just write your own enumerable extension that executed a method on the first true

Comment: Your example would return, and therefore break the loop, the first time it finds a checked button. My guess is that your code isn't actually checking any of the buttons you are looping through but is instead checking the sender control (wrapped as `rbs`) on each iteration.

Comment: @CallumLinington The `Any` method already basically does that.

Comment: `ForAny` = `Where` + [`ForEach`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1509442/1997232).

Comment: @Abion47 as Tim already pointed out to the guy who answered with Any, no it doesnt do what OP wants...

Comment: @Sinatr so would `foreach (Control rb in this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Where(x => x.Checked == true){}` work?

Comment: @CallumLinington It does exactly what you are describing. The first time a check would return true, `Any` will return true, allowing code to be run when used in conjunction with an if block. If that isn't what OP actually wants, then he needs to clarify what it is he needs.

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko It depends. Do you need references to all the buttons that are checked or do you just need to know that one of them is checked?

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko, that would enumerate all checked radiobuttons of `this` (but not radiobuttons nested in another containers).

Comment: @Abion47 I need to know if one of them is checked.

Comment: Your approach doesn't check if **any** of your radio buttons are checked, *except* for the one which is equal to `sender`.... The loop does nothing with the collection it is iterating over (no access to `rb` inside the loop) or am I missing something?

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko Then your current `foreach` approach is fine (minus the typo that pinkfloydx33 and I have pointed out). If you must have a LINQ version, use the `Any` method as described by Ehsan Sajjad's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linq is your friend here, Use [`Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) method which will return `bool`, but behind the scenes of-course it will also loop through the check-boxes it's just syntactic sugar.

Your all this code :

```
foreach (Control rb in this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
{
    RadioButton rbs = sender as RadioButton();
    if(rbs.Checked == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hi");
        return;
    }
}
```

can be replaced with:

```
var anyRadioChecked = this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Any(x=>x.Checked);
if(anyRadioButton)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Hi");
   return;
}
```

and if you are inside a RadioButton event, and you want to check for the `RadioButton` is checked only if there is any `RadioButton` on the `Form` then you would need to do it following way:

```
RadioButton rbs = sender as RadioButton;
var anyRadioButton = this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Any();
if(anyRadioButton && rbs.Checked)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Hi");
   return;
}
```

The above will return `true` if atleast one checkbox is checked.

Comment: OP asked for a method like ForAny instead of doing foreach

Comment: but OP does also not enumerate the whole collection. He stops on the first checked button. If he'd initialize  `bool` variable `anyChecked` to `true` and `break` the loop he would have the same code as you without LINQ. Also, `ForAny` sounds more like `Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Where(rb =>rb.Checked)`

Comment: agreed but OP asked for a method built-in like ForAny, so we have `Any()` right :)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Does this also work in a `foreach` statement? And, could this be `bool anyChecked` instead of `var anyChecked`?

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko `var anyChecked` and `bool anyChecked` are identical in this context.

Comment: Your code contains the same typo that OP's code does. It's not checking if `rb` is checked. It's checking if `rbs` is checked. As such, your LINQ will produce different results than the foreach method.

Comment: oh alright, i misunderstood the question, i have updated answer.

Comment: This only checks if there are any radio buttons on the form and if the one referenced to by sender is checked. Why is nobody using the values being iterated over (`rb` in op)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the typo is OP's, and that rather than deviating from his intent you merely recopied his error.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad is there a way to get a radio button inside of a group box?

Answer (score 2):

Well, your current code does that already. You only enumerate the collection until the first checked `RadioButton`. You could use LINQ to shorten the code as [Ehsan has already shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42417358/284240).

> But is there a `forany` statement

This sounds like you want to use seomething like this:

```
var checkedRadioButtons = this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Where(cb => cb.Checked);
```

Now you can enumerate all checked radio-buttons:

```
foreach(RadioButton btn in checkedRadioButtons)
{
    // ..
}
```

or if you only want to know if there is at least one:

```
bool isAnyCheckedRadioButton = checkedRadioButtons.Any();
```

or you want to know how many are checked:

```
int countCheckedRadioButtons = checkedRadioButtons.Count();
```

or you want to store them in a collection:

```
List<RadioButton> checkedRadioButtonList = checkedRadioButtons.ToList();
```

Maybe that LINQ query using `Enumerable.Where` is what you understand as `ForAny`:

Comment: Except the original code doesn't do anything with the collection outside of using it to loop x times. Other than that I think the solution is correct.

Comment: I can't get the `bool` to work. I think it's because my radio buttons are stored in a panel. How do I fix that?

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko: even better, then you need to use: `panel.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>() ...` instead of `this.Controls.OfType...`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I figured it out, but I don't understand why the form won't detect it? It still is in the form.

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko: because `OfType` is an extension method that filters the given sequence by the type. It does not know that a control could contain child controls. The panel is such a container control which contains child controls, your RadioButtons. So you will never find controls that are nested in others(recursively). If you use [`Controls.Find(name, true)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) you will find controls by name even if they are sitting in another child controls if you pass `true` as second argument.

Comment: But you can't use this method because it is not a type filter. I'd prefer using the correct container control, so `panel.OfType...`. That's also safer since there could be `RadioButtons` in other container-controls which you don't want to process. If you really needed a recursive approach you could use [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2209896/284240). Then this would also find your RB's: `var q = Controls.FlattenChildren().OfType<RadioButton>()...`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Alright. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score -1):

You could create your own extension method to do it - that's all ForEach, Select etc. are.

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void ForFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> arr, Func<T, bool> predicate, Action<T> action)
    {
        using (var enumerator = arr.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                if (predicate(enumerator.Current))
                {
                    action(enumerator.Current);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
    .ForFirst(
        rb => rb.Checked, 
        rb => MessageBox.Show("Hi from " + rb.ToString()));
```

You **can** use `First()`, `Where()`, `Any()` I have just offered a different but **valid** solution. This is solution is flexible, and a *one liner...*

Comment: Might I suggest using `First` instead (or alternatively `FirstOrDefault`)?

Comment: No need for `rb as RadioButton` the `OfType` should already do that for you. And I agree with abion47 might as well call First

Comment: This looks very complex. I don't know if I can use or understand this.

Comment: It is straightforward, all you're doing is getting the enumerator from the enumerable (the thing that actually iterates the list), then you're checking if you can move to the next element (which if it succeeds will change current) then it calls the predicate (the function that checks a condition) if that succeeds it will call the action (the function where you've defined what to do), and then returns.

Comment: @CallumLinington I'm not going to doubt you on whether or not this works, but I'm not at all experienced with `static class` and `static void`. I don't know how to evaluate this code (given you didn't do it for me) and understand what is going on or how to fix it (if there was an error).

Comment: Fair points, I created this in Linqpad first, so checked it against ints (the nice thing about this is that it is generic). The static stuff is just making it an extension method - static only means can't be instantiated, so not an instance method

Comment: The static stuff is *not* what makes it an extension method. That would be the `this` before the first parameter. Without it, this would just be a regular static method.

Comment: I meant that the static and this is required to make it an extension method