# java - compare two groups of objects efficiently

Tags: algorithm, comparison

I have two groups of objects where each group consists of 4 objects. The goal is to compute the degree of similarity between thes two groups. The comparison between two objects results to an int number. The lowest this number is the more similar the objects are. The order of these objects withing the group doesn't matter to the group equality.

So what i must do is compare each object of group 1 with each object of group 2 and this will give me 16 different comparison result between objects. I store these in a 4x4 int table called costs.

```
int[][] costs= new int[4][4];
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
     for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
         costs[i][j]=compare(objectGroup1[i],objectGroup2[j]);
      }
 }
```

Now i have 4 sets of 4 comparison results and I must choose one result from each set, in order to add them and compute the total distance metric between the groups. This is the point where i got stuck.
I must try all combinations of four and get the minimum sum but there is the restrition of using an object only once.

Example: if the first of four values to add is the comparison result between objectGroup1[1] - objectGroup2[1] then I can't use in this foursome any other comparison results that came using objectGroup1[1] and same goes for objectGroup2[1].

valid example: group1[1]-group2[2], group1[2]-group2[1], group1[3]-group2[3],group1[4]-group2[4]---->each object from each group appears only once

What kind of algorithm can I use here?

Comment: Is four a guaranteed size, or do you need an algorithm that will scale up to larger sizes well?

Comment: it is preffered to be a generic solution as i might need to compare larger groups in the future. thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to find the [permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of group 1's items that make it most similar to group 2's items when pairing the items off.

Eric Lippert has a good series of blog posts on [producing permutations](http://ericlippert.com/2013/04/15/producing-permutations-part-one/). So basically all you have to do is iterate over them, computing the score by pairing items, and return the best score. Basically just Zip-ing and MinBy-ing:

```
groupSimilarity =
    item1.Groups

    // (you have to implement Permutations)
    .Permutations()

    // we want to compute the best score, but we don't know which permutation will win
    // so we MinBy a function computing the permutation's score
    .MinBy(permutation =>
        // pair up the items and combine them, using the Similarity function
        permutation.Zip(item2.Groups, SimilarityFunction)
        // add up the similarity scores
        .Sum()
     )
```

The above code is C#, written in a "Linqy" functional style (sorry if you're not familiar with that). [MinBy](http://morelinq.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs) is a useful function from [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), [Zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122737/what-is-the-use-of-zip-extension-method-in-linq) is a standard Linq operator.

Comment: if i'm not mistaking permutation refers to the  distinct rearrangement of the objects of 1 group. What i'm looking for is the distinct combinations between two different sets of objects. correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: You only need to permute one of them to get all of the matchings-that-don't-repeat-an-object. If you permute both, you just end up repeating matchings. For example, {1,2} vs {3,4} has two possible matchings: {1:3, 2:4} and {2:3, 1:4}. Including {1:4, 2:3} and {2:4, 1:3} as well just repeats two matchings that are already there.