# to add two one dimensional array and display as two dimensional array

Tags: c#

Suppose there are two arrays. One array is used to store names and the other array to store marks. How can I display a name with its corresponding mark? Both arrays are of different types.

Comment: Solution: make a single array of `CustomObject`.  Or key-value pairs like a dictionary.  Or `Tuple<name,mark>`

Comment: you can use Zip from linq. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122737/what-is-the-use-of-enumerable-zip-extension-method-in-linq

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something like:

```
int[] marks = { 1, 2 };
string[] names = { "one", "two"};

var dictionary = names.Zip(marks, (s, i) => new { s, i })
                          .ToDictionary(item => item.s, item => item.i);
```

or

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

for (int index = 0; index < marks.Length; index++)
{
    dictionary.Add(names[index], marks[index]);
}
```

and then

```
foreach (var item in dictionary )
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}",
    item.Key,
    item.Value);
}
```