# LINQ C# Calculating a List value using 2 lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists:

1. `List<int> listOne` say [1,2,3,4]
2. `List<int> listTwo` say [111,222,333,444]

Now I want to make a resultant `List<int>` using the above 2 lists, making some calculation like `[1*100/111, 2*100/222 ,...` `listOne[i]*100/listTwo[i].,...]`

What I have tried:

```
resultantList = listOne.Select((s, i) => new { s * 100 / listTwo[i] }).ToList();

resultantList = listOne.Select((s, i) => s * 100 / listTwo[i]).ToList();
```

But this doesn't compile. How should I frame the LINQ for this?

Comment: Your second one should compile fine. Zip (as in DavidG's answer) is better but your second option should have worked perfectly fine. What compile error did you have with it?

Comment: here is a  `zip` sample for your question.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5122785/2332844)

Comment: Yes, its compiling, just checked again patiently now. Thanks lot

I remember It was showing error like 
'Anonymous member declarator ...'
Actually  this deals with realtime data to be displayed on the Dashboard. 
Which is best way to go about? I see many answers here. Is LINQ & mine calculates\performs faster.
This list is one of the value (inside an object) that needs to keep changing on page as per the data received back-end. Please advice.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Linq [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx), for example:

```
var results = listOne.Zip(listTwo, 
    (one, two) => one*100 / (decimal)two);
```

Note: the cast to decimal is important otherwise the division will produce integer output (which is always zero in your test data)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Zip`

```
List<int> result = listOne.Zip(listTwo, (i1, i2) => i1 * 100 / i2).ToList();
```

But because of integer division i expect all values to be 0 because even multiplied with 100 the division result is less than 1. So maybe you want to use `decimal`:

```
List<decimal> result = listOne.Zip(listTwo, (i1, i2) => decimal.Divide(i1 * 100, i2)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var resultList = new List<int>();
for(var i = 0; i < listOne.Count; i++)
{
  resultList.Add((listOne[i] * 100) / (decimal)listTwo[i]);
}
```

Comment: this is not `LINQ`.

Answer (score 0):

The operation mathematical operation is done using select statement and stored in resultant list.The result will be a decimal number hence the output list is a decimal list.The inputs are typecasted to decimal to perform the operation

`List<decimal> result = listOne.Select((x,i) => (decimal)x*100 / (decimal)listTwo[i]).ToList();`

Comment: Please explain the answer as well. Without that it is a low quality post and may be deleted.

Comment: The answer was self explanatory.