# Way to refer back to an old random instance when a new one is already made?

Tags: c#, random

So my general question is: **is there a way to refer to an old random instance after declaring a new one?**

First, the following is the code that I'm currently using.

This is the list I created:

```
        Random p1rnd = new Random();
        List<string> p1list = new List<string>();
        p1list.Add("A");
        p1list.Add("B");
        p1list.Add("C");
        p1list.Add("D");
        p1list.Add("E");
        p1list.Add("F");
        p1list.Add("G");
        p1list.Add("H");
        p1list.Add("I");
        p1list.Add("J");
        int p1r = p1rnd.Next(p1list.Count);
```

This is the block of code where I used the list, and is what I'm currently having an issue with:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nWhat would you like to say?");
                    Console.Write("A. ");
                    p1r = p1rnd.Next(p1list.Count); //CHOICE A
                    Console.Write(p1list[p1r]);
                    Console.Write("B. ");
                    p1r = p1rnd.Next(p1list.Count); //CHOICE B
                    Console.Write(p1list[p1r]);
                    Console.Write("C. ");
                    p1r = p1rnd.Next(p1list.Count); //CHOICE C
                    Console.Write(p1list[p1r]);
                    p1choiceA = Console.ReadLine();
```

Basically, I'm planning to use if-else statements to remove the choices. However, I don't know how to phrase my condition.

```
        if ( ) // SHOULD BE CHOICE A
        {
        p1list.Remove( )
        }
        else if ( ) // SHOULD BE CHOICE B
        {
        p1list.Remove( )
        }
        else if ( ) // SHOULD BE CHOICE C
        {
        p1list.Remove( )
        }
```

Typically, I would use `p1list[p1r]`. But, given that I created new random instances for each, I don't know what to put anymore. How would I refer to the instance used in CHOICE A and B? Thanks.

Comment: Explain what you are ultimately trying to do please.

Comment: @Sweeper Oops, sorry it's not clear. I'm going to use if-else statements to remove the choices. For example, if they choose CHOICE A, I want to remove that choice from the list. But if I use the code 'p1list[p1r]', it refers to the choice that came up in CHOICE C instead. Because of that, I'm wondering if there's a way to refer back to CHOICE A. (I'll put this up on the post too)

Comment: Which list are you talking about? Update the code part as well

Comment: @SirRufo Updated that as well. Please tell me if anything else is confusing.

Comment: On the next edit we need some navigation instruction for your question **or** you reorganize it for better readability.

Comment: I'll reorganize it, then. Sorry that it wasn't to your liking.

Comment: if you want to refer to your previous instances of the Random class at a later point, you'd have to keep them in memory, in separate variables, organised in such a way that you can relate them to the integers they generated. I think that's what you're trying to do, right?

Comment: You can use another list to keep the items for the three choices.

Comment: @ADyson Yes. If you could expound on how to do that further, it'd really be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @SirRufo Noted, will try.

Comment: @Sarah you've got a `List` of `string`s, you would just need a corresponding `List` of `Random`s as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you wish to show three random choices. The user gets to pick one, which gets removed from the list. Then he gets to see three more choices: the two remaining from the original list, plus an additional random one. Is that correct?

My suggestion:

First, sort your list into a random order. This makes everything else way easier.

```
//using System.Linq;
var sortedList = p1list.OrderBy( s => p1rnd.NextDouble() ).ToList();
```

Now that the list is sorted, it is very simple to select three questions. Just pick the first three!! And if you ever need to know which ones you picked... they were the first three. This satisfies the requirements of both randomness and recall.

To compose a list for display to the user, [`Zip()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122737/what-is-the-use-of-enumerable-zip-extension-method-in-linq) the list with an array containing the choice identifiers (the letters A, B, and C).

```
    var choiceLetters = new [] { "A", "B", "C" };

    var choiceStrings = choiceLetters.Zip
    (
        sortedList, 
        (a,b) => string.Format("{0}. {1}", a, b)
    );
    Console.WriteLine("What would you like to say?");
    foreach (var s in choiceStrings) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

To remove one, just remove it from the `sortedList`.

```
    var choiceLetter = Console.ReadLine();
    var choiceIndex = Array.IndexOf(choiceLetters, choiceLetter.ToUpper());
    if (choiceIndex == -1) break;  //User didn't pick A, B, or C

    sortedList.RemoveAt(choiceIndex);
```

Complete solution:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Random p1rnd = new Random();
    List<string> p1list = new List<string>
    {
        "These sentences make up the random list of choices.",
        "In your example you used single letters.",
        "That was kind of confusing.",
        "The user always sees A, B, and C.",
        "But not sentences 0, 1, and 2.",
        "I'll have a beer please."
    };

    var sortedList = p1list.OrderBy( s => p1rnd.NextDouble() ).ToList();

    var choiceLetters = new [] { "A", "B", "C" };

    while (true)
    {
        var choiceStrings = choiceLetters.Zip
        (
            sortedList, 
            (a,b) => string.Format("{0}. {1}", a, b)
        );

        Console.WriteLine("What would you like to say?");
        foreach (var s in choiceStrings) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        var choiceLetter = Console.ReadLine();
        var choiceIndex = Array.IndexOf(choiceLetters, choiceLetter.ToUpper());
        if (choiceIndex == -1) break;  //User didn't pick A, B, or C

        sortedList.RemoveAt(choiceIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful! But I'd like to ask, is it possible to add different Console.ReadLine(); for what you choose? Like, I want to add, "Your response was [response different with each choice]." Is that possible?

Comment: @Sarah Please note this is a Q&A-Site (Question&Answer). Anyone can ask a question and anyone can answer **that** question. If you have another question, ask that as a **new** question. BTW Asking for „Is .. possible?“ will just produce answers like „Yes, of course.“ or „No“. Do you really want to know if it is possible or how to do? If how, then ask what you really want

Comment: Noted, was just asking for clarifications. Will be sure to follow the rules next time around.

Comment: The user's choice is contained in `sortedList[choiceIndex]` so you can always display it with `Console.Writeline(sortedList[choiceIndex])`'.