# making unique strings after getting value from hashset?

Tags: c#

Okay So I have this Hashset that contains 3 items and I want to apply some logic on it such that I am able to append some predefined 3 values for the each item present inside the hashset

for example,

```
HashSet<string> hs = new HashSet<string>(); //it could be string or some other class object
hs.add("Red");
hs.add("Yellow");
hs.add("Blue");

//Some predefined values for those strings that I want to append to them
string[] str = {Alpha, Beta, Gamma}
```

The output I desire is:

```
unique strings associating "RedAlpha", "YellowBeta", "bluegamma"
```

for example s1 = "RedAlpha", s2 = "YellowBeta", s3 = "bluegamma";

I then want to apply some different logic to each of them later but then I guess that is a different thing

My Tried code

```
int count = 1;
int index = 0;
string s = "";
foreach(string strr in hs)
{

 string s + count = strr + str[index]; // I don't know how to make new unique string
 count++;
 index++;
}
```

My other Tried Code,

```
   foreach(string strr in hs)
{

 string s = strr + str[index]; 
 s = s + ","
 index++;
}

s.split(",");
```

Comment: Stop.  Asking questions and dumping the answers into your program will not make you a good programmer.  Take a step back and make sure you understand the things in the code you are already using.  Then when you ask a question and are introduced to something new, study what you've been shown.  Don't just throw together bits of code like they are magical incantations in some language no one understands.

Comment: @BenVoigt I am sorry sir.

Comment: No reason to apologize to me.  I just want to help you improve faster, by pointing out that you already had the piece you needed (arrays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to merge 2 collection together and perform some operation on them, use the Zip method. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42749868) for an explanation of Zip method.

Here is how to achieve what you need:

```
HashSet<string> hs = new HashSet<string>();
hs.Add("Red");
hs.Add("Yellow");
hs.Add("Blue");

string[] str = { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma" };
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> kvps = 
    hs.Zip(str, (left, right) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(left, right))
    .ToList();
```

If you want a dictionary, it is straight forward as well:

```
Dictionary<string, string> kvps = 
    hs.Zip(str, (left, right) => new { left, right })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.left, x.right);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a list:

```
int index = 0;
var list = new List<string>();
foreach(string strr in hs)
{
    list.Add(strr + str[index]);
    index++;
}

Console.WriteLine(list[0]); //RedAlpha
```

Comment: Actually it would be better if I am able to use them as a key value player perhaps using dictionary?

Comment: @Shad you may use dictionary, yes