# Join elements in two List<string> using comma in C#

Tags: c#

i have 2 lists:

List 1 = {"1", "2", "", "", "4", ""}

List 2 = {"3", "4", "5", "", "6", ""}

I want a new List:

List 3 = {"1, 3", "2, 4", "5", "", "4, 6", ""};

How can i get this result?

Comment: See [What is the use of Enumerable.Zip extension method in Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5122737/402022).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Zip__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___1___2__) with [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__) for this:

```
var result = list1
  .Zip(list2, (a, b) => string.Join(", ", new[] { a, b }.Where(x => x != "")))
  .ToList();
```

[Try online](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxAgrgOwD4AEBMAjALABQuADAAS6EAsA3GZTYQHQAyAlpgI5OkyANwgIqAGy6xCVALxVMcAO5VusADy0KAPgAUASioBvAESETSKifwWrtk/br2TAXwEixk2PjkLlqqRhNQh0DYxMAZkd7AFZnSxMANmc3YVEqBDgodHEYXy8YdgAtLgAHXQL8S10IS2BDWW1WCjYAKQB7Hl17S0UlAG0AXWMqWqpgKhc2AHUAC0Q4XQAPOSaVgEJ5B30dtgAVdrUYAwEyADN2zIgAY1mqXQ8qKCoeDKycmH0yKh/WAE5dAByEyAqgAaie4KowMB+gYQA===)

Comment: I adjusted to `novaLinha.Zip(listaEstadosConcatenar, (a, b) => string.Join(", ", new[] { a, b })).Where(x => x != "").ToList()` but it produces results like "," or "2 ," or ", 3".

Comment: @GustavoB. You placed the parentheses differently