# Why do I want to use zip() in Python?

Tags: python, zip

I understand how `zip` in python works in general. But I couldn't get my head around why it is beneficial. Most online sources give examples that look like:

```
name = [ "Manjeet", "Nikhil", "Shambhavi", "Astha" ] 
roll_no = [ 4, 1, 3, 2 ] 
marks = [ 40, 50, 60, 70 ] 

mapped = list(zip(name, roll_no, marks))
```

(source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zip-in-python/)

But I can easily replace it with:

```
mapped = []
for i in range(len(name)):
    mapped.append([name[i], roll_no[i], marks[i]])
```

The advantages of using zip I can think of is:

1. I'd imagine it's faster because of python's magic
2. Less code to type
3. It won't return error if input lists have different length

But is that it? Are there scenarios where zip provides more significant advantage? Note that I'm not shouting zip is not useful. On the contrary, I'm trying to understand when it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of a zip function (as in Python or C# 4.0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429692/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-zip-function-as-in-python-or-c-sharp-4-0)

Comment: Because people keep shoting their feet with routines like that. Have actually read the dosc https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?

Comment: `zip()` is more readable then `range(len())` and all of `[i]`

Comment: The code you provided assumes `name` as the shortest array which could throw an error at runtime if `marks` or `roll_no` was smaller.  If you had used `zip` you would never have this kind of problem, because it abstracts away this corner case. IMO `zip()` is much easier to read. Moreover, in Haskell (I don't know for python), there's a function called `zipWith` which is a zip on steroid and is very useful.

Comment: Also, it's different from your code in that it's a generator meaning you can do it on very large iterables. To get the equivalent performance requires many more lines of code.

Comment: Suppose you don't actually *want* to assign a name to the list. With the `for` loop, *all* you can do is build up a named list. With `zip`, you can create an "anonymous" list that can be passed, for example, as the argument to another function.

Comment: @LVB Python *does* have an equivalent of `zipWith`; it's just called `map`: `map(operator.add, [1,2,3], [4,5,6])` produces the sequence 5, 7, 9. (This works because unlike Haskell `map`, you can provide multiple lists, one for each argument the mapped function expects.)