# Foreach/For loop alternative lambda function?

Tags: c#

We use for or foreach to loop through collections and process each entries.

**Is there any alternative in all those new lambda functions for collections in C#?**

Traditional way of doing

```
foreach(var v in vs)
{
  Console.write(v);
}
```

Is there anything like?

```
vs.foreach(v => console.write(v))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ equivalent of foreach for IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

List has the ForEach method, however, IEnumerable does not.

There are a number of questions / answers regarding this. I think the main reason it was not implemented in IEnumerable though is that Linq on Enumerables is "meant" to be side effect free as it's a querying language.

Eric Lippert explains his thoughts on his blog.

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: +1 for linking to Eric Lippert's blog, where he explains why doing it this way is a bad idea (and traditional `foreach` is actually better).

Answer (score 11):

Yes.

<strike>Of of `IList`, there is a ForEach extension method:</strike>

There is a ForEach method for List:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4" };

list.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Just to be clear: It is a method within `List<T>`, it is *not* an extension method.  It does not make sense to add ForEach to LINQ, but it *does* make sense to move it up to `IList<T>`:  Go [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552410/move-lots-of-helpful-methods-from-list-to-ilist-using-extension-methods) to support this! :)

Comment: Hmm, I stand corrected. I always thought it was an extension off of IList<T> rather than a method off of the concrete implementation.

Comment: heheh regarding **off of**, I edited your answer, but sorry I cannot edit your comment, help yourself :-)

Comment: Dunno what the big deal with Off Of is.. Someone care to explain?

Comment: @Ian P: English-wise, I don't know exactly, I'm not a native speaker. But somehow if you're a programmer, you will start to have a language feel of English language(off wasn't use there ☺). In the sentence I edited, it's hard to deduce what "method off" conveys. And the sentence where "off of" is warranted is when the words that precedes the "off of" is a verb, and the word *method* is definitely not a verb. Perhaps this could illuminate: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1447359&page=1 and this: http://www.answerbag.com/q_view/707088. On a somewhat related note: http://xkcd.com/541/

Comment: Haha, interesting.. I've, along with various other colleagues of mine, have always used "SomeMethod() is a method that hangs off of TypeY.."

Comment: :-) That is ok, "hangs" is a verb. Other examples: "back off of my man", "Making money off of local services", "Put off", they are all preceded by verb, by action. I feel "off of" is warranted there. One particular phrase I often see in http://slashdot.org "Get off my lawn", I  never(afaict) seen it there phrased as "Get off of my lawn", I think the geek crowd in slashdot.org is the most grammar nazis of all geeks. Another grammar tips: http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/ending-prepositions.aspx

Comment: On other news, I googled: `"Get off my lawn" site:slashdot.org`. And googled: `"Get off my lawn" site:slashdot.org`.  There are other geeks who uses "Get off of my lawn", though they are miniscule (55 results) compared to those that uses "Get off my lawn" (1,250 results)

Comment: A person have to back off if Client Eastwood is enforcing something :-D http://www.joeszilagyi.com/images/blog/2009/08/EastwoodMyLawn.jpg

Comment: I hate broken links, so [here's the archived version](http://web.archive.org/web/20120904060042/http://www.joeszilagyi.com/images/blog/2009/08/EastwoodMyLawn.jpg) of the image @MichaelBuen posted.

Answer (score 3):

[`List(T).ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) does exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

Eric makes a compelling argument except for the fact that there is a ForEach for List<T> but only for List<T>. I've fouund numerous occassions to use that very useful extension method and been equally frustrated by the lack of a general extension method for IEnumerable<T>, so I finally decided to write my own.

In doing so, I ended up going one step further and writing a Once<T> and ForEvery<T> fluent extension methods that allow chaing of actions on each item and the execution of an action just once in that chain, if for no other reason than they seemed like a good idea at the time.

Here's the code:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{   
   public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Action<T> action)
   {
      foreach (var item in collection)
      {
         action(item);
      }
   }

   public static IEnumerable<T> Once<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, 
      Func<IEnumerable<T>, bool> predicate, Action<IEnumerable<T>> action)
   {
      if (predicate(collection)) 
         action(collection);
      return collection;
   }

   public static IEnumerable<T> ForEvery<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection,
      Func<T, bool> predicate, Action<T> action)
   {
      foreach (var item in collection)
      {
         if (predicate(item)) 
            action(item);
      }
      return collection;
   }
}
```

You can find example usage code on my blog post [Extend IEnumerable with ForEach and Once Methods](http://www.tsjensen.com/blog/2011/04/29/Extend+IEnumerable+With+ForEach+And+Once+Methods.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

By default, there isn't one.
You could define your own:

> ```
> public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action) {  
>    foreach(T val in source)  
>       action(val);  
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

What you've written is perfectly legal (apart from the case) - assuming that the type of `vs` has `ForEach` defined as an extension method or if it's a `List`.

[`ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) is defined for `List<T>`:

> Performs the specified action on each element of the `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)  
{
    int[] i = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 78, 8, 9};
    var data = i.ToList();

    data.ForEach(m => { Console.WriteLine(m); });

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vs.ToList().ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item));
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET 3.5's Linq doesn't have Foreach, though [LinqBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) provided one.  I got accustomed to using Linqbridge that I naturally [assumed](http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/03/power-of-lambda.html) it is part of .NET 3.5 Framework

Just add it to your extension methods collections if you think it could bring clarity to your program

```
static class Helper
{
    public static IEnumerable<t> ForEeach<t>
        (this IEnumerable<t> source, Action<t> act)
    {
        foreach (T element in source) act(element);
        return source;
    }
}
```