# List.ForEach method and collection interfaces

Tags: .net, collections, interface, ienumerable, ilist

In .NET 3.5 List<> gains a ForEach method. I notice this does not exist on IList<> or IEnumerable<> what was the thinking here? Is there another way to do this? Nice and simple short way to do this?

I ask because I was at a talk where the speaker said always use the more general interfaces.
But why would I use IList<> as a return type if I want to be able to turn around and use ForEach? Then I would just end up casting it back to a List<>.

Comment: As for "what was the thinking here?": http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: This method is not new in 3.5, it's been there since 2.0. BTW, this is probably a dupe...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what was the thinking here?

You can read [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)'s [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/foreach-vs-foreach) for the reasons why this feature wasn't added.

> Is there another way to do this? Nice and simple short way to do this?

Why not just use the foreach keyword? I find it more readable.

```
foreach (var foo in ilist)
{
    // etc...
}
```

Though you can add a `ForEach` extension method to `IEnumerable<T>` if you want to:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (T item in enumeration)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet).

Answer (score 1):

It's not in the framework (yet) but [Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) adds the .Run(this IEnumerable enumerable) extension method that does the same as List's custom ForEach. Until this is part of the standard framework you'll have to write your own or use the extra dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Why is `ForEach` not in `IEnumerable<T>`?  Eric Lippert explains this nicely [in his blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/foreach-vs-foreach).  Basically, LINQ is meant to be functional (no side effects), and `ForEach` is decidedly non-functional.

But, why is it not in `IList<T>`?  Well... [it should be](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552410/move-lots-of-helpful-methods-from-list-to-ilist-using-extension-methods)!