# WPF LINQ and the ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, linq, observablecollection

In my WPF application I'd like to use LINQ as much as possible (especially to avoid `foreach`). But WPF works a lot with the ObservableCollection, and I can't use LINQ with these kind of collection. What can I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What makes you think you can't use LINQ with `ObservableCollection<T>`? It implements `Collection<T>` so it should be fine.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var collection = new ObservableCollection<int>()
        {
            1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 2, 4, 5, 3
        };

        var query = collection.Where(x => x % 2 == 0);
        foreach (int x in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry. I remember there were problems with some queries, but now I have tried and everything works.

Comment: The resulting query is an IEnumerable. Is there a clean way of going back into an ObservableCollection<int> ?

Comment: @tofutim: No, not as far as I'm aware I'm afraid.

Comment: Clean way back? What about `new ObservableCollection<int>(collection)`. Almost all (if not all) collection types have constructors accepting an IEnumerable<T> as argument.

Comment: @ToaoG: That takes a copy of the data - it won't change when the original observable collection changes, which is what I'd expected tofutim to require. I could have misunderstood though.

Comment: Maybe this is not the right place for my method, but I do that all the time, e.g., in a method with signature `public ObservableCollection<T>  DoSomething(ObservableCollection<T> _input)` where in the method I use Linq, e.g., `var subset = _input.where(n = > n.condition)` and then `return new ObservableCollection<int>(subset)`

Comment: @ToaoG: It depends on what you're trying to observe. Normally I'd expect an observable collection to want to be fairly closely linked to the original source collection. But YMMV.

Comment: Yeah I typed my answer a bit hastily, the proper signature should be `public ObservableCollection<T> DoSomething(IEnumerable<T> _input)`. But what I said happens very naturally if your view displays an ObservableCollection which should be filtered according to some user input - then I use above code in the getter of the bound ObservableCollection. Is there a better way?

Comment: @ToaoG: If you're going to filter it so that you don't *actually* observe any changes in the original data, what good is it doing you to use ObservableCollection at all? What changes will you observe?

Comment: Say you have a property called data of type `List<T>` with all the data, and bind a property of type `ObservableCollection<T>` to your view. As getter `get { return new ObservableCollection<T>(data.Where(n => n.name == 'What User entered in a textbox')); }`. Then the view will only see the part of the data that the user requests.

Comment: @ToaoG: You didn't answer my question: why bother using an ObservableCollection at all, if you're not going to be able to observe any changes? (Because it's a copy of the data.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Is a possible solution to wrap every LINQ operator that describes ObservableCollection<T> instead of IEnumerable<T> and forwards a event notification on CollectionChanged. It will trigger everytime the underlying collection changes as opposed to when the query result changes, but that's not unheard of. Are ObservableCollection objects expensive? It's a bit weird that there is no IObservableCollection<T> interface.

Comment: @Tormod: It sounds like you should possibly look at Reactive Extensions, which is more designed around the idea of reacting to changes as a fundamental operation.

Answer (score 18):

Just for anybody else who may come across this issue with trying to filter an ObservableCollection but find that they can't.

Jon is absolutely correct in that there is no reason why you can't do this but the key thing for a newbie or for someone who has been developing with WPF for a while, is that you need to include the "**using System.Linq;"** namespace. As you soon as you do this, you can do a ".where" query on your object.

Comment: Thanks for the additional answer! *That* was my issue :)

Comment: The resulting ObservableCollection will not update if the query result update as a consequence of the underlying source being updated.

Answer (score 1):

The OP asked especially for the LINQ ".ForEach()" Method, which cannot be used on ObservableCollection< T >, since it's implemented for List< T > only.

There is another SO-Topic, where I found my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/200584/2408978

Answer (score 0):

You need my [ObservableComputations](https://github.com/IgorBuchelnikov/ObservableComputations) library maybe. That is .NET API designed especially to work with LINQ like queries to ObservableCollection in WPF and other .NET UI frameworks that support binding  to [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=netframework-4.8) and [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) objects (Xamarin, Blazor).