# Are there std::for_each algorithm analog in C# (Linq to Objects)

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

Are there std::for_each algoritm analog in C# (Linq to Objects), to be able to pass `Func<>` into it? Like

```
sequence.Each(p => p.Some());
```

instead of

```
foreach(var elem in sequence)
{
  elem.Some();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ equivalent of foreach for IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet)

Comment: o yes, thanks.. thats preatty much answers my question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `foreach` statement in C# language itself.

As Jon [hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet/200614#200614) (and Eric [explicitly states](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)), LINQ designers wanted to keep methods side-effect-free, whereas `ForEach` would break this contract.

There actually **is** a `ForEach` method that does applies given predicate in `List<T>` and `Array` classes but it was introduced in .NET Framework 2.0 and LINQ only came with 3.5. They are not related.

After all, you can always [come up with your own extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet/200584#200584):

```
public static void ForEach<T> (this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (T item in enumeration)
        action (item);
}
```

I agree this is useful in case you already have a single parameter method and you want to run it for each element.

```
var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
list.Where (n => n > 3)
    .ForEach (Console.WriteLine);
```

However in other cases I believe good ol' `foreach` is much cleaner and concise.

By the way, a single-paramether void method is not a `Func<T>` but an `Action<T>`.
`Func<T>` denotes a function that returns `T` and `Action<T>` denotes a `void` method that accepts `T`.

Comment: It's not so much that it is possible that they wanted it side-effect-free, [it is a fact](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).  ;)

Comment: Oh thank you! I thought I came across this somewhere on Eric's blog but wasn't sure. After all, he must've written about pretty much every aspect of the language by now.

Comment: does it mean, for generic case on Linq to Objects, there are no ForEach and foreach statement should be used, instead.. right ?

Comment: I think I just answered this question. In short, a) there is only `ForEach` on `List<T>` and `Array` but it was introduced way before LINQ; b) designers of LINQ wanted it to be side-effect-free whereas `ForEach` extension method would break this convention; c) you can always write your own extension method that does the thing if you have reasons to do so.

Answer (score 3):

`System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` has a method `void ForEach(Action<T> action)` which executes the supplied delegate per each list item. The `Array` class also exposes such a method.