# C#: is there a way to set a property of objects in a collection using lambda expression?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I am developing a small project and I thought I could try something I don't know so I can learn something new.
I have a collection of Messages, called msgs. I would like to filter only the unread ones and then set it to "read".
To do that, I called the Where method with this lambda expression, I imagine I would get a list of all messages which are unread. Now I would like to set the value to "Read" (assigning 'T' to the MessageRead property). Is there a way to do that using lambda expressions?

I got to this code, but the "All" method is not what I am loking for, I just found out that it checks if all the elements in the list match this condition.

```
msgs.Where(message => message.MessageRead == 'F').All(message => message.MessageRead = 'T');
```

Thanks a lot,
Oscar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are after is a ForEach extension method, see discussions here: [LINQ equivalent of foreach for IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet)

Comment: That is just great! Thanks for your help!
You were so fast that I have to wait 10 minutes to accept your answer, as soon as it is possible, I will mark it!

Answer (score 5):

In fact if there was such a method, it wouldn't had any benefits over regular foreach statement.

Eric Lippert (senior software design engineer at Microsoft) has a good overview of this topic: [“foreach” vs “ForEach”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I know. In this case, am not doing because it is better, but because I want to learn it. :)

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the `foreach` statement? It does exactly what you need:

```
foreach (var msg in msgs.Where(m => m.MessageRead == 'F'))
{
    msg.MessageRead = 'T';
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does. But the problem is that I already know this one. I want to learn new stuff in order to be able to use them if I need ;)

Comment: @Oscar: Fair enough, although part of the learning process is discovering what the appropriate techniques are in different scenarios. The correct answer to "How do I open a beer bottle using my cellphone?" is almost always "Don't use your cellphone; use a bottle opener".

Comment: Hi! That is true, but I think we can learn something when they are not necessarily needed but we have time/opportunity to do so, so in the future, case we need it, we already know. Nodoby know, maybe at some point in time all that is left is a cellphone and a bottle :)