# Query and updating a property in a collection using LINQ

Tags: linq

What is the most succint/simple way of updating a single property of a specific item within a collection using LINQ?

For example if I have a List of the following:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

How can I use LINQ to update the "Selected" property of a Ticket item wheres its "Name" property has the value of "Beach". In SQL it would be:

```
UPDATE Tickets SET Selected = true WHERE Name = 'Beach'
```

I thought I was on the right track with this...

```
tickets.Select(x => { x.Selected = true; return x; }).ToList().Where(x => x.Name == "Beach");
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can change the order, then use the ForEach operator:

```
tickets
   .Where(x => x.Name == "Beach")
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(x => { x.Selected = true; });
```

Note:

- that the `ToList()` is needed because IEnumerable doesn't support ForEach in Linq - see [LINQ equivalent of foreach for IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet)
- that for readability it might be better to separate this out into a linq query and then a more conventional `foreach(x in list)` C# loop
- if this is linq-to-sql, then you'll need to call `SubmitChanges()` in order to persist your changes.

Comment: Why ToList()? Sure it was in the OP, but it is probably unnecessary overhead.

Comment: The reason is - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet

Comment: `IEnumerable` doesn't support `.ForEach()`, so it's needed.

Comment: I prefer to your solution than the other one,because the code is more readable. Is there any performance advanatage for FloatLeft's suggestion ?

Answer (score 8):

Bit late for an answer but i think we don't have to convert to `ToList()` as Mentioned by stuart what actually we can do is just tweak Stuart code(which is great piece of code) as following

```
tickets
   .Where(x => x.Name == "Beach")
   .All(x => x.Selected = true);
```

Another option

```
tickets
   .Where(x => x.Name == "Beach")
   .All(x => { x.Selected = true; return true; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me start off by saying this, don't use LINQ to set properties like that, that's not how LINQ's meant to be used.

You *should* write the query to select the rows to be changed, change them in a loop, and submit the changes to the database (if LINQ to SQL).

```
var query = tickets.Where(ticket => ticket.Name == "Beach");
foreach (var item in query)
    item.Selected = true;

// if LINQ to SQL
context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Jeff, please can you supply a reason why you think LINQ should not be used in this way? The ForEach() is doing exactly the same thing as your foreach loop.

Comment: @IsolatedStorage ForEach is not part of LINQ anyway... The reason is noone actually expects Where/Select/Any/All to update existing objects - as result doing so will cause confusion... Delayed execution does make it even more entertaining.