# ForEach Extension Method for ListItemCollection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods, listitem

I implemented an ExtensionMethod which basically works as ForEach-Loop, my Implementation looks like this:

```
public static void ForEach(this ListItemCollection collection, Action<ListItem> act )
{
    foreach (ListItem item in collection)
        act(item);
}
```

However, I'd like the method to stop looping after the first time a specific condition is met.

Here's how I currently use it:

```
ddlProcesses.Items.ForEach(item => item.Selected = item.Value == Request["Process"]?true:false);
```

The Problem with this is that there can only be one item inside the DropDownList which matches this requirement, but the loop is being finished anyway, what would be the least ugly way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are not experimenting **ddlProcesses.Items.FindByValue(Request["Process"]).Selected = true;** would be the simplest thing to do

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Use tilde to highlight `syntax in comments`

Comment: @abatishchev deselect all items ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Sorry, no such task in OP's question. But in fact, he will need this later, i guess. But everything up to him :)

Comment: @abatishchev Maybe he does or not still there is **ClearSelection()** which does the trick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a `Func<ListItem, bool>` instead of an `Action<ListItem>` and break the loop if it returns `true`:

```
public static void ForEach(this ListItemCollection collection,
    Func<ListItem, bool> func)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in collection) {
        if (func(item)) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
ddlProcesses.Items.ForEach(
    item => item.Selected = (item.Value == Request["Process"]));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void ForEach(this ListItemCollection collection, Action<ListItem> act )
{
    foreach (ListItem item in collection)
    {
        act(item);
        if(condition) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does condition come from?

Comment: @abatischev this is from OP " I'd like the method to stop looping after the first time a specific condition is met."

Comment: @Peter the OP could place his condition there ... I've just wanted to let him know that you can stop a foreach loop with a break;

Answer (score 1):

First do this:

```
IEnumerable<ListItem> e = ddlProcesses.Items.OfType<ListItem>(); // or Cast<ListItem>()
```

to get generic collection.

Then [use can roll your own, generic extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet):

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (T item in collection) action(item);
}

public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T> func)
{
    foreach (T item in collection) if (func(item)) return;
}
```

---

Anyway, cache lookup result:

```
var process = Request["Process"];

e.ForEach(i => i.Selected = i.Value == process);
```

Comment: e.ToList() results in copying the whole list into a new List instance before iterating. This may not be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are not 100% clear. Do you need to process all items to set them to false except the only one which matches the condition or do you just want to find the with the right condition or do you want to apply a function until a condition is met?

1. Only do something to an item the first time the condition matches

   ```
   public static void ApplyFirst(this ListItemCollection collection,
                         Action<ListItem> action, Func<ListItem, bool> predicate)
   {
       foreach (ListItem item in collection) 
       {
          if (predicate(item))
          {
              action(item);
              return;
          }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Do something to an item everytime a condition matches

   ```
   public static void ApplyIf(this ListItemCollection collection,
                         Action<ListItem> action, Func<ListItem, bool> predicate)
   {
       foreach (ListItem item in collection) 
       {
          if (predicate(item))
          {
              action(item);
          }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Do something to all items until a condition matches

   ```
   public static void ApplyUntil(this ListItemCollection collection,
                         Action<ListItem> action, Func<ListItem, bool> predicate)
   {
       foreach (ListItem item in collection) 
       {
          action(item);
          if (predicate(item))
          {
              return;
          }
       }
   }
   ```