# How can I loop through a ListBox's selected items in Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, listbox, compact-framework, listboxitem, listboxitems

I adapted the following code from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/96df2c84-3507-4322-a441-4c3ba2a6522b/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-and-items-from-listbox-?forum=winforms)

```
foreach (String table in tablesToTouch)
{
    foreach (Object selecteditem in listBoxSitesWithFetchedData.SelectedItems)
    {
        site = selecteditem as String;
        hhsdbutils.DeleteSiteRecordsFromTable(site, table);
    }
}
```

...but, alas, the SelectedItems member appears unavailable to me: "*'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedItems' and no extension method 'SelectedItems' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*"

Another suggestion was:

```
foreach(ListItem listItem in listBox1.Items)
{
   if (listItem.Selected == True)
   {
     . . .
```

...but I also don't have ListItem available.

What is a workaround to accomplish the same thing?

### UPDATE

There are at least two (somewhat kludgy) things I could do:

```
0) Manually keep track of items selected in listBoxSitesWithFetchedData (as they are clicked) and loop through *that* list
1) Dynamically create checkboxes instead of adding items to the ListBox (getting rid of the ListBox altogether), and use the text value of checked checkboxes to pass to the "Delete" method
```

But I'm still thinking there's got to be a more straightforward way than those.

### UPDATE 2

I can do this (it compiles):

```
foreach (var item in listBoxSitesWithFetchedData.Items)
{
    hhsdbutils.DeleteSiteRecordsFromTable(item.ToString(), table);
}
```

...but I'm still left with the problem of only acting on the items that have been selected.

### UPDATE 3

Since the CF-Whisperer said that listbox multiselection isn't possible in the murky and misty labyrinthine world of CF (cuneiform forms), I simplified the code to:

```
foreach (String table in tablesToTouch)
{
    // Comment from the steamed coder:
    // The esteemed user will have to perform this operation multiple times if they want 
to delete from multiple sites              
    hhsdbutils.DeleteSiteRecordsFromTable(listBoxSitesWithFetchedData.SelectedItem.ToString(), 
        table);
}
```

Comment: if you can understand this code on this page try some of the working coded answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831004/foreach-extension-method-for-listitemcollection

Comment: They all require ListItem, which I don't have.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.item.aspx this doesn't work for you..?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because I don't have access to ListItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Compact Framework `Listbox` simply contains a list of `object` Items.  It calls `ToString()` on each for display, but the items are there.

So let's say we have an object:

```
class Thing
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }

    public Thing(string a, int b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}: {1}", B, A);
    }
}
```

And we throw some into a `ListBox`:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(new Thing("One", 1));
listBox1.Items.Add(new Thing("Two", 2));
listBox1.Items.Add(new Thing("Three", 3));
```

They will show up as the `ToString()` equivalent in the list (e.g. "One: 1").

You can still iterate across them as the source objects via a cast or `as` operation like this:

```
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine("A: " + (item as Thing).A);
    Console.WriteLine("B: " + (item as Thing).A);
}
```

Comment: Now you've got me thinking about Dr. Seuss.

Comment: It has a `SelectedItem` property.  You can't multi-select in the CF, as far as I recall.

Comment: "Dang it!" <= in a Kip Dynamite-esque voice.
Thanks.