# LINQ: Assinging Property-values in IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq

What is the LINQ-version of the following code-snippet:

```
List<Car> myCarList = ...;
foreach(Car c in myCarList)
{
if(c.Name.Equals("VW Passat"))
{
c.Color = Colors.Silver;
}
}
```

i tried Select like this and it works:

```
myCarList = myCarList.Where(c=>c.Name.Equals("VW Passat")).Select(c=> new Car(){Color=Colors.Silver, Name=c.Name}).ToList();
```

But it´s annoying recreating the object, especially if you have many properties to pass. how to do it simpler?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I might write it like this:

```
foreach (Car c in myCarList.Where(c => c.Name == "VW Passat"))
{
    c.Color = Colors.Silver;
}
```

Here the LINQ query is used perform the filtering, but on ordinary loop performs the update. You *could* write an `Enumerable.ForEach` or convert to a list and use `List<T>.ForEach`. But consider that `Enumerable.ForEach` was omitted deliberately because that's not how LINQ was intended to be used. See here for more details:

- [LINQ equivalent of foreach for `IEnumerable<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet)

Comment: just a polite inquiry ..is this more efficient than the non-linq version ? Why /Why not ?

Comment: @ashutoshraina: I doubt it makes a huge difference. It it's important, measure the performance of both. I'd expect the non-LINQ version to be slightly faster, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Mark Why you changed back the `==` I had put after `c.Name`? Is there something I don't know?

Comment: @xanatos: Sorry it was an accident - I originally typoed when writing my first answer and when I later edited it to improved the wording it accidentally reverted your correction. Thanks for trying to fix it. I've corrected it now.