# LINQ: Transforming items in a collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there a LINQ method to modify items in a collection, such as simply setting a property of each item in a collection?  Something like this:

```
var items = new []{ new Item { IsActive = true } }
var items = items.Transform(i => i.IsActive = false)
```

where Touch enumerates each item and applies the transformation.  BTW, I am aware of the SELECT extension method, but this would require I expose a method on the type that does this transformation and return the same reference.

```
var items = items.Select(i => i.Transform())
```

where Item.Transform returns does the transformation and return the same instance.

TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ equivalent of foreach for IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet)

Comment: The difference between the first and the second is that the first actually changes the collection while the other returns a new one.

Comment: `var items = items.Select( i => { i.IsActive = false; return i; })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `ForEach()` on `List`, so you can do `items.ToList().ForEach(i => i.IsActive = false)`. You might want to read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) though.

Comment: It makes me cringe when I see people take perfectly good collections of items and convert it to a new list so they can use that method...

Comment: Not LINQ but this is sort of what i am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @JeffMercado, my method returns an IEnumerable<T>.  I can return List or array if I want.    No, I am not creating a new collection just to use ForEach.

Comment: @e28Makaveli: I'm not saying that using the `List<T>.ForEach()` method is bad, I'm saying that given a collection that is not declared as a list, creating a new list just to use it is.  If you have a list of items from the start, then I would welcome its use (but personally would prefer not to).

Comment: @JeffMercado yes, that would make me cringe too .... creating a new List just to use one of its APIs.  Many things wrong with that.  This is not what i am doing though.

Answer (score 14):

No, there are no methods in standard LINQ that allows you to modify items in a collection.  LINQ is for querying collections and not for causing side-effects (e.g., mutating the items).  Eric Lippert goes into the idea in more detail in his blog post: [“foreach” vs “ForEach”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Just use a loop.

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    item.IsActive = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response.  This is what i will end up doing anyway but I though there was such a method as this is a common thing to do.

Comment: @e28Makaveli Note that if your collection is a `List<T>`, then you can use the `ForEach()` method: `list.ForEach(x => x.Property = value);`

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is for querying. Use a simple loop if you want to modify. Just use the right tool for the right job. LINQ is not a messiah for everything.

Comment: True, true but the Select extension is some sort of transformation is it not?  I would say LINQ is for querying and enumerating over collections.

Comment: @e28Makaveli: `Select` is for projecting. That is not the same as mutating nor transforming.

Comment: @e28Makaveli, the Select extension method returns a new IEnumerable, it doesn't modify the original which is what you are trying to do. It's only for projecting.

Comment: I do not see the difference between projecting and transforming.  You can use Select to transform one collection of type T to another collection of type T1.  This is a projection but is this also not a transformation?

Comment: @e28Makaveli, the difference is that Select returns a new resultset => that's projecting. A transformation is when you modify the original collection.

Comment: @e28Makaveli: A projection (in the mathematical sense) does not modify the item, it merely creates an alternate representation of the value.  e.g., 3D point projected onto a 2D plane.  A transformation (also in the mathematical sense) changes the item in some way.  e.g., translating (moving) a point from one position to another.  The same properties hold here.  The `Select()` method simply projects the collection of items to another representation.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) for the Enumerable class lists all LINQ methods, and unfortunately no method there does what you want.  LINQ is a *query* language and is not intended to modify collections. It is functional in its nature, meaning that it doesn't modify the collection it operates on, rather it returns a new enumerable.

For your purposes it is better to simply use a foreach loop, or if you feel the need write your own extension method to do what you want, eg.

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, Action<T> action)
{
   foreach (T item in seq)
      action(item);
}
```

which could then be used as you wanted:

```
items.ForEach(i => i.IsActive = false)
```

Comment: Thanks. IList.ForEach does what I want.