# Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, compiler-errors

```
var query = rep.GetIp()  // in this line i have the error
           .Where(x => x.CITY == CITY)
           .GroupBy(y => o.Fam)
           .Select(z => new IpDTO
                        {
                            IId = z.Key.Id,
                            IP = z.Select(x => x.IP).Distinct()
                        })
           .ToList().ForEach(IpObj => IpObj.IP.ToList().ForEach(ip => PAINTIP(ip)));
```

When I run this code I have the error:

> Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable

I googled and found that it is a type issue because `foreach` is not a LINQ function? I cannot understand where the `void` is!

Comment: Is this the exact error message? Is it a compile time error? In which line exactly? Can you show some more code? There are many references not shown...

Comment: What are `PAINTIP` and `GetIp` and what are their return types?

Comment: Are you trying to assign the result of this query to some variable?

Comment: var query = rep.GetIp()  this is the line that gives the error. the file is SERVICES.ASMX.CS

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- `ForEach()` has type `void`.
- `Select()` returns `IEnumerable<T>`, `ToList()` returns `List<T>`, etc.

so:

```
List<X> x = ...Select(x => x).ToList(); // List<T>
```

or

```
x.ForEach(x => x); // void
```

because you can't assign `void` to `List<T>`.

---

```
var query = rep.GetIp()  // in this line i have the error
           .Where(x => x.CITY == CITY)
           .GroupBy(y => o.Fam)
           .Select(z => new IpDTO
                        {
                            IId = z.Key.Id,
                            IP = z.Select(x => x.IP).Distinct()
                        });

foreach (var dto in query)
{
    foreach (var ip in dto.IP)
    {
        PAINTIP(ip);
    }
}
```

or

```
var query = ....
           .SelectMany(z => z.Select(x => x.IP).Distinct());

foreach (var ip in query)
{
    PAINTIP(ip);
}
```

Comment: aba, thank you for the explaination , im not sure that i understand the syntax,do  i need to add  IpObj before the foreach as in your example?   .ToList()IpObj.ForEach(IpObj => IpObj.IP.ToList().ForEach(ip => PAINTIP(ip)));   ?

Comment: btw, you can use tilde to highlight code in comments, e.g. `ToList(); IpObj.ForEach(IpObj => IpObj.IP.ToList().ForEach(ip => PAINTIP(ip)));`

Comment: @Tania: Describe literally what are you going to achieve, e.g. call PaintIP() for each IP for each town in rep?

Comment: i need to return the results    "IId" and "IP" and for each ip(element from inside IP) call PAINTIP(ip)

Comment: you are my hero! where do you define the "ip" in both examples u use ip without defining it

Comment: @Tania1990: I've missed `var ip` in of the examples. Notice that in second example I don't use type `IpDTO` and use `SelectMany`() to select ip of each dto in united sequence

Answer (score 7):

`ForEach()` does not return anything. Its type is void.

Try replacing your [ForEach()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) calls with [Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I saw your other questions, wherein you have asked similar question for the same query. The code partially looks like this :

```
var Q = rep.GetIp()
        .Where(x => x.CITY == CITY)
        .GroupBy(y => o.Fam)
        .Select(z => new IpDTO
        {
          IId = z.Key.Id,
          IP = z.Select(x => x.IP).Distinct()
       });
```

Looks like you have used the answer as such and you are trying to assign the returned value from the query to the variable "Q". Check out your previous post : [syntax in LINQ IEnumerable<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240877/syntax-in-linq-ienumerablestring)

As others have said, ForEach return type is "void". You should call "ForEach", once the variable "Q" is initialized with the collection.

Comment: I understand it now but how to call ForEach only after the Q was initialized ?

Comment: @Tania1990, simple: `var q = …; q.ForEach(…);`. But I would recommend you to use normal `foreach` instead of `List.ForEach()`.

Comment: svick, please show me how would you use List.ForEach() with my syntax - i have used .ToList().ForEach(

Comment: @Tania : You  are increasing the scope of the original question. You can only write Linq queries, if you have proper understanding of lambda expression, system defined delegates like func<>, Action<> etc.Refer the following link for sample LINQ queries : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b