# Is there a more succinct way of adding items to a collection property using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a one line LINQ statement that would replace the foreach loop in the code below?

```
public static ReplaceItemsOnOrder(Order order, List<OrderItem> replacements)
{
    order.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var item in replacements)
    {
        order.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Here is a simplified definition for the `Order` class:

```
public class Order
{
    private Collection<OrderItem> _items = new Collection<OrderItem>();
    public Collection<OrderItem> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is order.Items anything more derived than a ICollection<OrderItem>?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet

Comment: I've updated the question to show the Order.Items type, which is Collection<OrderItem>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Linq is about selecting, not modifying.

You could write your own extension method to add this feature though.

Answer (score 3):

It's not LINQ but there's [`AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx)

```
order.Items.AddRange(replacements);
```

But you haven't said what `Items` is, so unless it's a `List` that method won't be available.

Comment: If it's not a List but implements IEnumerable, he just has to call .ToList() on it, and AddRange will be available.

Comment: @Baboon: `System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T>)` creates a _new_ list with all item references copied, so for this to work OP has to store the list anywhere.

Comment: @Tobias order.Items.ToList().AddRange(replacements) doesn't require him to store the list anywhere, AddRange is void.

Comment: @Baboon: That's true, but the `AddRange` method alters the newly created list, not the enumeration the list was created from.

Answer (score 3):

You could write the following:

```
order.Items.Clear();
replacements.ForEach(order.Items.Add);
```

Alternatively if there's an addRange method (available on `List<T>`):

```
order.Items.Clear();
order.Items.AddRange(replacements);
```

Comment: Which can also be written: `replacements.ForEach(order.Items.Add);`

Comment: @KlausByskovHoffmann very true, save the unnecessary anonymous method. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

Is `order.Items` a List? You could have:

```
public static ReplaceItemsOnOrder(Order order, List<OrderItem> replacements)
{
    order.Items = new List<OrderItem>(replacements);
}
```

This makes sense because, in your example code, it seems you're *replacing* the items in `order.Items`. `List<T>` has [a constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx) which accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` argument, whose contents will be copied to the  list being constructed.

It's also safer in the sense that if an error occurrs at construction time (including the copy operation), it won't result in a half-full new list.