# How I can improve the code using lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, refactoring

Can some one help me? I'm not very strong with lambda expressions.

```
protected void Process1(List<SomeClass> mylist)
{
    foreach (var item in mylist)
    {
        if (!SomeClass.Validate(item)) 
        { 
            continue; 
        } 
        DoStuff(item); 
        DoMore(item); 
        DoEven(item);
    }
}

protected void Process2(List<SomeClass> mylist)
{
    foreach (var item in mylist)
    { 
        if (!SomeClass.Validate(item) || item.Value == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        DoStuff(item);
        DoMore(item);
        DoEven(item); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You question might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What specifically are you trying to improve?

Comment: Can you be more specific on "do stuff"? Generally speaking, lambdas shouldn't alter the collection they operate on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ equivalent of foreach for IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet)

Comment: In general, this is a test and I'm trying to figure out how to do it right

Answer (score 3):

Second process is the same as calling first process with parameter

```
myList.Where(item => item.Value != 0)
```

Or, if you need both methods:

```
protected void Process1(IEnumerable<SomeClass> mylist)
{
    foreach (var item in mylist)
    { 
        if (!SomeClass.Validate(item))        
            continue;

        DoStuff(item);
        DoMore(item);
        DoEven(item); 
    }
}

protected void Process2(IEnumerable<SomeClass> mylist)
{
    Process1(myList.Where(item => item.Value != 0));
}
```

Also, I'd changed input parameter to `IEnumerable` (because you only iterating through sequence of items).

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void Process1(List<SomeClass> mylist)
{
    foreach (var item in mylist.Where(item => SomeClass.Validate(item))
    {
        DoStuff(item); 
        DoMore(item); 
        DoEven(item);
    }
}

protected void Process2(List<SomeClass> mylist)
{
    foreach (var item in mylist.Where(item => item.Value != 0 && SomeClass.Validate(item))
    { 
        DoStuff(item);
        DoMore(item);
        DoEven(item); 
    }
}
```

That's how I would get it done.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
protected void Process(List<SomeClass> mylist, List<Action<SomeClass>> actions)
{
    foreach (var item in mylist)
    {
        if (!SomeClass.Validate(item)) 
        { 
            continue; 
        }
        foreach(var action in actions) 
            action(item); 
    }
}
```

then call it with:

```
Process(list, new List<Action<SomeClass>> {DoStuff, DoMore, DoEven});
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to use Linq to apply the validation to the collection and just return valid items. Additionally, you can chain them together to apply multiple validations, if needed. For instance:

```
return myList.Where(item -> !SomeClass.Validate(item))
             .Where(item -> !OtherClass.Validate(item))
```

This would return a collection of just the items that pass validation, to which you could apply whatever "stuff" you need to "do".

Answer (score 0):

The `Process` method can be made very generic and reusable:

```
void Process<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Predicate<T> filter, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
        if (filter(item))
            action(item);
}
```

Then you will use it, for example, like this:

```
Process(
    list, 
    i => SomeClass.Validate(i) && i.Value != 0, 
    i => 
    {
        DoStuff(i);
        DoMore(i);
        DoEven(i);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a big fan of passing lists around to begin with, but...

```
protected void Process1(List<SomeClass> myList)
{
    myList.Where(item => SomeClass.Validate(item)).ToList()
        .ForEach(item =>
        {
            DoStuff(item);
            DoMore(item);
            DoEven(item);
        });
}

protected void Process2(List<SomeClass> myList)
{
    myList.Where(item => SomeClass.Validate(item) && item.Value != 0).ToList()
        .ForEach(item =>
        {
            DoStuff(item);
            DoMore(item);
            DoEven(item);
        });
}
```

Comment: -1 IEnumerable<T> has no extension method `ForEach`

Comment: You are correct, sir. Forgot the ToList().

Comment: @L.B - It is List not just an IEnumerable and it has ForEach extension method. Please remove your down votes.

Comment: Now do you think it is better then a simple `if`?

Comment: @Tariqulazam When you apply `where` to `List`, you don't have `ForEach` anymore.  Try to compile `new List<int>().Where(x=>x>0).ForEach(i => { int x = 1; });` before commenting

Comment: @L.B - Yes, that's true. I was only thinking about the parameters passed to the functions. You should have provide better clarification with each down vote. However, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: "I'm not a big fan of passing lists around to begin with, but..." Could you clarify why not?