# Passing Lambda selectors as an argument

Tags: c#, lambda

I am working on some reporting code and I have found myself repeating a certain piece of code which contains a where and select cause over and over again?  The only piece of information changing is the target field.

```
    private static void UpdateResultsListInstructions(List<ManagementInfo> managementInfo, KeyValuePair<int, int> item)
    {
        managementInfo
            .Where(m => m.YearMonthNo == item.Key)
            .Select(m => m.VolumeOfInstructionsReceivedInMonth = item.Value)
            .ToList();
    }

    private static void UpdateResultsListClaims(List<ManagementInfo> managementInfo, KeyValuePair<int, int> item)
    {
        managementInfo
            .Where(m => m.YearMonthNo == item.Key)
            .Select(m => m.VolumeOfClaimsCancelled = item.Value)
            .ToList();
    }
```

Is it possible to pass in the selector as an argument so I can reuse one method?

Along the lines of

```
UpdateCommonResultsList(managementInfo, item, (m => m.VolumeOfClaimsCancelled = item.Value))
```

I can probably rejig all the code so that this is not necessary but now that I've had the thought I'd like to see if its possible. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your current code is assigning values in the select clasuse. Is it your intention to cause this effect (it could be why you're doing a ToList and not returning anything).

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using Linq extension methods to do what it seems a foreach loop would be better at?

Comment: No particular reason other than i just read the chapter on Linq in the Jon Skeet book and thought I should give it a test drive :) When you say a foreach would be better in what respect? I thought that these linq extensions resolved to pretty much the same il code as a foreach.

Comment: Not quite.  The Linq stuff is a bunch of methods, whereas `foreach` is a language construct, so they'll never compile to the exact same thing.  If you use a method that forces iteration, like `ToList()`, then yes, it'll end up doing a foreach internally.  But frankly, why bother?  You could say `.Select(...)` to modify your objects, but as noted in one of the comments above, it's unconventional and people will assume it's an accident.  You could say `.ToList().ForEach(...)`, but you've gained nothing outside of a potentially massive List you won't even return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I don't like the use of `Select` to *update* a list - I misread the question because it's not usual to do that! - you *can* do it as follows:

```
private static void UpdateCommonResultsList(
    List<ManagementInfo> managementInfo,
    KeyValuePair<int, int> item,
    Action<ManagementInfo, int> action)
{
    managementInfo
        .Where(m => m.YearMonthNo == item.Key)
        .Select(m => { action(m, item.Value); return item.Value; })
        .ToList();
}
```

Call as

```
UpdateCommonResultsList(
    managementInfo,
    item,
    (m, i) => m.VolumeOfClaimsCancelled = i);
```

Your code will be a lot more conventional if you do this as

```
private static void UpdateCommonResultsList(
    List<ManagementInfo> managementInfo,
    KeyValuePair<int, int> item,
    Action<ManagementInfo, int> action)
{
    foreach (ManagementInfo m in managementInfo
        .Where(m => m.YearMonthNo == item.Key))
    {
        action(m, item.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `Action`, but `Func` as the Select requires a result. But ideally, in your last bit of code, do `action(m)` with the action being `Action<ManagementInfo>` and then it doesn't need anything else.

Comment: I've been sat on the Tube for 20 minutes going "I hope nobody notices that didn't compile before I can fix it"... Fat chance :p

Comment: Awesome, many thanks for answering my question and pointing me in a better direction than using select for an update.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The Select method takes an argument of type `Func<TSource, TResult>` so you can use that type in the method, and then pass it in as a lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass action like this to update methods:

```
UpdateResultsListClaims(managementInfo,
  (m) => m == someItem.Key,
  (m, newData) => m.VolumeOfClaimsCancelled = someItem.Value)

private static void UpdateResultsListClaims(List<ManagementInfo> managementInfo,
Func<bool> updateCondition, Action<ManagementInfo> updateAction)
    {
        managementInfo
            .Where(m => updateCondition(m))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(m => updateAction(m));
    }
```

**UPDATE 1**
For more readability you can call:

```
UpdateResultsListClaims(managementInfo,
  updateCondition: (m) => m == someItem.Key,
  updateAction: (m, newData) => m.VolumeOfClaimsCancelled = someItem.Value)
```

**UPDATE 2** For easy use in many places you can make extension method like this

```
public static void UpdateResults(this List<ManagementInfo> managementInfo,
Func<bool> updateCondition, Action<ManagementInfo> updateAction)
    {
        managementInfo
            .Where(m => updateCondition(m))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(m => updateAction(m));
    }
```

and call it like this

```
managementInfo.UpdateResults(
  updateCondition: (m) => m == someItem.Key,
  updateAction: (m, newData) => m.VolumeOfClaimsCancelled = someItem.Value)
```

Comment: Any particular reason not to say something like `foreach (var m in managementInfo.Where(updateCondition)) { updateAction(m); }` rather than creating a List?

Comment: cHao, the reason is just little less typing 8)
By the way did some one know why in linq ForEach did't exists for IEnumerable?

Comment: here's discusson about foreac for ienumerable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet

Comment: Because the biggest feature of IEnumerable, besides the extension methods, is right in the name -- it is designed to be *enumerable*; that is, it can be used in a foreach loop.  A ForEach method wouldn't provide any functionality not already provided by C# and VB.

Comment: In case above, it can improve the readability and reduce typing. Even with codecomplete and snippets. But I vote up your comment both hands - list creation not optimal

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void UpdateCommonResultsList<T>(List<ManagementInfo> managementInfo, KeyValuePair<int, int> item, Func<ManagementInfo,T> updateFunc)
    {
        managementInfo
            .Where(m => m.YearMonthNo == item.Key)
            .Select(m => updateFunc(m))
            .ToList();
    }
```

And then invoke as:

```
UpdateCommonResultsList(managementInfo, item, (m => m.VolumeOfClaimsCancelled = item.Value));
```