# replace for(int i = 0; i< Count; i++) with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

What will be the best way to replace:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
{
   if(!members[i].Equals(anotherMembers[i]))
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

with LINQ expression?

Comment: Not really sure, but may be you are looking for [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567(v=vs.100).aspx), like `members.SequenceEqual(anotherMembers)`

Comment: there has been a long debate about this in LINQ land. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet

Comment: @pm100 This is not the same debate since there is no mutation ocuring in this loop.

Comment: @Habib, that wasn't exact my case, I really simplified the example, so it won't work for me :(

Comment: @Stanislav Then you haven't adequately described your problem, preventing a meaningful quality answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think LINQ would be more readable option, but in general you need to [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) sequences first to be able to deal with pairs at the same index:

```
var allSame = members.Zip(anotherMemebers, (x,y)=> Tuple.Create(x,y))
       .All(t => t.Item1.Equals(t.Item2)); // or other operation on pairs
```

As Habib pointed out if you just need to compare sequences [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) may be better choice.

As @juharr commented `.Take(10)` may be needed to close match original loop, but LINQ versions are way more forgiving - you'd need to check item count to exactly match all "out of range" errors from original loop.

Comment: ah, that looks good! but good point, it won't make it more readable, I'll go with classic for loop and accept your answer:)

Comment: I think you need to add `Take(10)` before the `All` to make it exactly the same.  Even then it would be different if either collection has less than 10 items (no exception).

Comment: @juharr - good point on `Take(10)` - inlined comment. Exact match of `for` would look ridiculous in LINQ version - I'd keep `for` OR write LINQ version that matches real requirement rather that possibly incomplete `for`.

Comment: I think the right answer is: _What will be the best way to replace it to LINQ_ is **NONE**