# Using Where and ForEach to modify specific elements in a list

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a list of objects that have the properties `fruitName` and `numFruits` and I want to pluralize the `fruitName` where `numFruits` is greater than 1, is it possible to do that in a single statement by chaining together `Where` and `Foreach`?

Something like:

```
fruitList.Where(fl => fl.numFruits > 1).ForEach(fl => fl.fruitName = fl.fruitName + "s");
```

I tried the above and it doesn't work. It complains that System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable doesn't contain a definition for ForEach.

Comment: The `.ForEach` only exists for `List`.  Call `.ToList()`

Comment: Use `foreach` instead of `List.ForEach`. Don't try to use a single LINQ statement i you want to modify the source. The best you can get is  an inefficient approach.

Comment: If I use ToList before ForEach it will remove all entries where numFruits is < 2. I need the whole list.

Comment: I know I can use foreach, but I want to know if it's possible this way without creating an explicit loop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want a one-liner (it will be harder to maintain) and want to keep the original list intact but only modify some of the elements, you'll have to use a full anonymous function.  If you need multiple statements (a block of code), you'll need to include the braces and statement-terminating semicolons like below:

```
fruitList.ForEach(fl => { fl.fruitName = fl.numFruits > 1 ? fl.fruitName + "s" : fl.fruitName; });
```

This works on the original list (no subset) and does basically the exact same thing a structured `foreach` would do.

Answer (score 3):

Typically you want to use `foreach` the language construct when possible. Eric Lippert has a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) going into additional detail as to why.

Loops are good when you are doing modifications as it makes finding those modifications easier.

```
foreach (var fl in fruitList.Where(fl => fl.numFruits > 1))
{
    fl.fruitName = fl.fruitName + "s";
}
```

Is more straightforward and accomplishes the same task.

Comment: ["foreach" vs. "ForEach"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)

Comment: @JLRishe: Exact post that I recalled, added a link.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good [blog post by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) on why there is no “ForEach” sequence operator extension method, essentially the reason is:

> The first reason is that doing so violates the functional programming
>   principles that all the other sequence operators are based upon.
>   Clearly the sole purpose of a call to this method is to cause side
>   effects. The purpose of an expression is to compute a value, not to
>   cause a side effect. The purpose of a statement is to cause a side
>   effect. The call site of this thing would look an awful lot like an
>   expression (though, admittedly, since the method is void-returning,
>   the expression could only be used in a “statement expression”
>   context.) It does not sit well with me to make the one and only
>   sequence operator that is only useful for its side effects.

If you wanted to do this in a single statement you could use a `.Select()`

```
var newFruitList = fruitList.Where(fl => fl.numFruits > 1).Select(fl => fl.fruitName + "s");
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Tim Schmelter suggested, you can use ToList() to convert to a list and then use the ForEach method on the result returned. Although the ToList() might return a shorter list based on the filter, the original objects themselves would be changed and your fruitList will remain unchanged.

```
fruitList.Where(fl => fl.numFruits > 1).ToList().ForEach(fl => fl.fruitName = fl.fruitName + "s");
// fruitList still has all elements
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the static [Array.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to update the list.

```
Array.ForEach(fruitList.Where(fl => fl.numFruits > 1).ToArray(), x => { x.fruitName += "s"; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that "append an s" doesn't actually give you the correct answer for many fruits, any approach that does that will give you an incorrect answer, no matter how well it does  it.

Consider using a lookup table to map singlular to plurals (and vice versa) instead:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> fruitLookup = 
        new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"blueberry", "blueberries"},
        {"peach", "peaches"},
        {"apple", "apples"}
    };

    public static void Main()
    {
        var fruitList = new List<string> {"blueberry", "peach", "apple"};

        // Here is your one-line conversion:
        var plurals = fruitList.Select(f => fruitLookup[f]).ToList();

        foreach (var p in plurals)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The fruit pluralization was just meant as an example. I didn't want to clutter the question with irrelevant domain specifics.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Although, it often turns out that just like the fruit pattern some other transformations don't apply uniformly. Hopefully someone else will find this useful. :)