# Print even numbers with Range() in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to print even numbers from 1 to 10 using LINQ with the following code

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(n => n%2 == 0).ToString().ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Now instead of printing even numbers its printing True or False statements. Where am i doing mistake here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Where(n => n%2 == 0).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

otherwise you're selecting the bool value, and not applying the filter :)

Comment: No worries. seems like you got the same answer about the same time :). Have a look @ msdn 101 linq guide, and have a look at linqpad as well, they will get you on the right path in no time

Answer (score 2):

You are using Select instead of where

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Where(n => n%2 == 0).ForEach(Console.WriteLine)
```

Select is creating new object for each evaluation, which evaluates to a boolean in this case.

Comment: when i run your query i got the 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' does not contain a definition for 'ForEach' and no extension method 'ForEach' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) error. 

the correct answer would be adding ToList() after the where clause in the above query.

Comment: You are right, though I usually add the ForEach extension to IEnumerable like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet

Comment: This would be more efficient than storing the results in a List and then iterating through them

Comment: @n00b I find it worth mentioning that the first comment on the question you linked to links to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) blog post from Eric Lippert where he argues why a `ForEach` extension on `IEnumerable` should _not_ be used.

Comment: @ThomasSchremser, thanks for sharing that. Though this might be better than ToList().ForEach() pattern, still probably something to avoid