# How to loop through var object collection in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have collection generated from linq (group by query). this generated list and collection I want to iterate the loop for each key, I have following code which generate list of object by grouping and now I want loop through

```
var objList=from p in objConfigurationList
group p by p.UserID into g
select new { UserID=g.Key, ReportName=g.ToList() };

foreach (object oParam in objList)
{

}
```

so how can I access key and reportname list inside this foreach. how to write foreach for that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `var` instead of `object`. The `select new` creates an anonymous type:

```
foreach (var oParam in objList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(oParam.UserID);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a small extension method ([credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/200584/1997232)):

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> @this, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var item in @this)
        action(item);
}
```

Then you can do

```
objList.Foreach(oParam =>
{
    ... // your code here, e.g. Console.WriteLine(oParam.UserID)
}
```

It's really good in method-syntax linq.