# how to invoke a method for each item using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to get a method invoked for each item in a list while passing that method the list item itself. Basically I can do it the drawn out way but was trying to get it in a concise LINQ statement like so:

```
var urls = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
             .Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value)
             .Where(href => !href.StartsWith("mailto:")) // skip emails, find only url links
             .ToList();
            //.ToList().ForEach(href => getWEbData(href.ToString ()));

            foreach (string s in urls) {
                getWEbData(s);
            }
```

> I could not figure out how to get the .ForEach() in to the LINQ
>   shorthand or if its possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ equivalent of foreach for IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to use `foreach` with Linq.  Id adds no values and makes it harder to debug.  You *can* embed the query in the `foreach` call like so:

```
foreach (string s in html.DocumentNode
                         .SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
                         .Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value)
                         .Where(href => !href.StartsWith("mailto:"))) 
{
    getWEbData(s);
}
```

Note that `ToList()` is unnecessary (whether you do the query inside or outside of the `foreach`)

Comment: looks identical to the for each i have after the generation of the href <list>

Comment: @kacalapy I just inlined the query and took off the `ToList()`  using `List.Foreach()` adds no value - all it's doing is iterating internally the same way `foreach` does.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. LINQ functions are designed to not cause side effects. ForEach is designed to cause side effects. Hence, there is no ForEach LINQ function.

See ["foreach" vs "ForEach"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) by Eric Lippert

Answer (score 0):

There is no LINQ `.ForEach` method, but you can easily write your own:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions {
   public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> pEnumerable, Action<T> pAction) {
      foreach (var item in pEnumerable)
         pAction(item);
   }
}
```

and then

```
html
.DocumentNode
.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
.Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value)
.Where(href => !href.StartsWith("mailto:")) // skip emails, find only url links
.ForEach(href => getWEbData(href.ToString ()));
```

or slightly better (although I think `href` may already be a `string`):

```
...
.Select(href => href.ToString())
.ForEach(getWEbData);
```

Although, as others have indicated, just because you can doesn't necessarily mean you should, but that was not your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use foreach with Linq but its better to have a constructor i.e. in Select statement take a new class object and make a parameterized constructor of that class an in the constructor you can do whatever you want it is one of the easiest and efficient way.