# How to implement ForEach statement on Newtonsoft JArray

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I need to cast JArray which I received from browser to list of MyType object. The problem is that I don't want to use .ToObject<> extension because object sended from browser can have missing or extra values and I cannot change deserializer. I wrote my own parser to receive data from single JObject. Usage:

```
foreach (var _object in _jarray)
{
    using (var tp = new TokenParser(_object)) 
    {
        MyType test = new MyType() 
        {
            id = tp.ConvertToInt("token_key")
        };
    }
}
```

What I want to do is something like this

```
_jarray.ForEach(_object => {
    using (var tp = new TokenParser(_object)) 
    {
        MyType test = new MyType() 
        {
            id = tp.ConvertToInt("token_key")
        };
    }
});
```

I don't want to cast elements like:

```
_jarray.Select(x => 
    (int)["token_key"]
);
```

I tried to wrote this extension based on [LINQ equivalent of foreach for IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet) but it seems that `Action` requires `T` as parameter type. I don't need this because JArray is an array of JObject.

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: `_jarray.ToList().ForEach(...)`?

Comment: That extension method should just work, but [per the docs](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jarray.htm) `JArray` is `IEnumerable<JToken>`, not `IEnumerable<JObject>` as you claim.

Comment: Why can't you do something like : `var result = _jarray.Select(o => { var tp = ...; return new MyType() { id = tp.ConvertToInt("token_key") }; });`