# Call Virtual Method of Object for each item in a List

Tags: c#, linq, azure-blob-storage

Bit of a wordy title, but I am not sure how else to phrase it. I am doing some work on Azure Storage Account Blobs, and I want to get the Metadata for each blob, which is done by calling a method on that object. Currently, I am using a looping construct to call the method like so

```
IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> listOfBlobs =
    cloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs(blobName, true, BlobListingDetails.Snapshots);

foreach (IListBlobItem blobItem in listOfBlobs)
{                    
    CloudBlockBlob theBlob = blobItem as CloudBlockBlob;
    theBlob.FetchAttributes();                   
    Console.WriteLine("Snapshot Uri: {0}", theBlob.SnapshotQualifiedUri.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

I am wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this. I know that I can typically do

```
listOfBlobs.ForEach(item => SomeMethod(item))
```

But since `FetchAttributes` is a void method, it will fail at build time because it needs to return an `IEnumerable<T>` to use `foreach`. My question is: how do I call `FetchAttributes()` for all items in the list? Am I better off using the loop? Is there some Linqy way of doing it?

Comment: Use the loop. Much clearer.

Comment: You can use `var` when you declare `listOfBlogs`, saves some space. Also you can do `foreach (CloudBlockBlob blobItem in listOfBlobs) {` to eliminate the casting in the foreach-block, also saves some space.

Comment: At the risk of splitting hairs, why "Call Virtual Method" and not just "Call Method?" A method is a method. The caller doesn't know or care whether the target inherits or implements it.

Comment: `Is there some Linqy way of doing it?` - Linq is for **querying**, not for causing side-effects.

Comment: To expound on Maarten's point, here's an [argument](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/) **against** using a *"Linqy"* construct instead of a loop by Eric Lippert. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet

Comment: Second that. Resharper suggests converting ForEach to a LINQ expression and "everyone is doing it," but it gives the impression that something is wrong with `foreach`. I've seen code that converts `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>` just so that it can use `ForEach` instead of `foreach`. Awesome adjective, "Linqy."

Comment: Also, you could avoid the question entirely by passing in "BlobListingDetails.Snapshots | BlobListingDetails.Metadata" into the ListBlobs call (or BlobListingDetails.All).  This should fetch the metadata without having to call FetchAttributes(), and should be much more performant.