# How to replace normal foreach to linq ForEach?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

```
public static List<TDuplicate> ValidateColumnInList<TItem, TDuplicate>(List<TDuplicate> DuplicateExpression) where TDuplicate : DuplicateExpression
{
    List<TDuplicate> TempDuplicateExpression = new List<TDuplicate>();
    var itemProperties = typeof(TItem).GetProperties();
    foreach (var DplExpression in DuplicateExpression)
    {
        bool IsContainColumn = itemProperties.Any(column => column.Name == DplExpression.ExpressionName);
        if (!IsContainColumn)
        {
            TempDuplicateExpression.Add(DplExpression);
        }
    }
    return TempDuplicateExpression;
}
```

In the above section how to replace above `foreach` to linq `ForEach`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ equivalent of foreach for IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet)

Comment: your slightly misunderstanding, Linq is a query language for selecting data it has no ForEach, the List class does have a for each as well as the Parallel class but neither of them is Linq

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `foreach` or `ForEach` here. Below code should give you result:

```
var itemProperties = typeof(TItem).GetProperties();
List<TDuplicate> tempDuplicateExpression = DuplicateExpression
    .Where(m => !itemProperties.Any(column => column.Name == m.ExpressionName))
    .ToList();

return tempDuplicateExpression;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get result by this simple way:

```
var result = DuplicateExpression.Where(n=>!itemProperties.Any(column => column.Name == n.ExpressionName)).ToList();
```

Or you can user ForEach like this:

```
DuplicateExpression.ForEach(n=>
    {
        bool IsContainColumn = itemProperties.Any(column => column.Name == n.ExpressionName);
        if (!IsContainColumn)
        {
            TempDuplicateExpression.Add(n);
        }
    }
)
```