# Foreach Loop In LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to replace the *foreach* loop in the following code with LINQ *ForEach()* Expression:

```
    List<int> idList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };

    IEnumerable<string> nameList = new List<string>();

    foreach (int id in idList)
    {
       var Name = db.Books.Where(x => x.BookId == id).Select(x => x.BookName);
        nameList.Add(Name);
    }
```

***Any Help Please!!***

Comment: there's a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet)

Comment: looks like you need to add a type declaration to Name, something like "var Name = db..."

Comment: @lloyd - That question **isn't** a duplicate. There's a difference between the C# keyword `foreach` and the `.ForEach` extension method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't quite work (you're adding an `IEnumerable<string>` to a `List<string>`). You also won't need `ForEach`, since you're constructing the list:

You can do this:

```
var nameList = idList.SelectMany(id => db.Books.Where(x => x.BookId == id)
                     .Select(x => x.BookName)).ToList();
```

But then you're hitting the database for each ID. You can grab all the books at once with :

```
var nameList = db.Books.Where(b => idList.Contains(b.BookId))
                       .Select(b => b.BookName).ToList();
```

Which will only hit the database once.

Answer (score 1):

Why not a select?

```
List<int> idList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };

List<string> nameList = idList
    .Select(id => db.Books.Where(x => x.BookId == id).Select(x => x.BookName))
    .ToList();
```

Or better yet: refactorise and select...

```
int[] idList = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

List<string> nameList = db.Books
    .Where(x => idList.Contains(x.BookId))
    .Select(x => x.BookName))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    nameList.AddRange(
             db.Books.Where(x => idList.Contains(x.BookId))
                     .Select(x => x.BookName)
                     .ToList());
```

This will generate an IN statement in the SQL, thereby only doing a single select.

One thing to be aware of is the performance of IN degrades as the set (idList in this case) gets bigger. In the case of a large set, you can batch the set and do multiple queries:

```
int start = 0;
int batch = 1000;
while (start < idList.Count())
{
  var batchSet = idList.Skip(start).Take(batch);
  nameList.AddRange(
             db.Books.Where(x => batchSet.Contains(x.BookId))
                     .Select(x => x.BookName)
                     .ToList());
  start += batch;
}
```

Comment: could you please add an explanation to your answer, so future readers can also learn *how* it works?

Answer (score -1):

To answer your specific question, you can do this:

```
List<int> idList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };

List<string> nameList = new List<string>();

idList.ForEach(id => {
    var Name = db.Books.Where(x => x.BookId == id).Select(x => x.BookName);
    nameList.Add(Name);
});
```