# How to convert nested foreach loops with conditions to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to ask if it is possible to convert below nested foreach loops to LINQ expression.

```
public interface IFoo
{
  bool IsCorrect(IFoo foo);
  void DoSomething(IFoo foo);
}

List<IFoo> listA; //assume that contains items
List<IFoo> listB; //assume that contains items


foreach (var a in listA)
{
  foreach (var b in listB)
  {
    if (b.IsCorrect(a))
    {
      b.DoSomething(a);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ equivalent of foreach for IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet)

Comment: @EtherDragon not really

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
var result =
    from a in listA
    from b in listB
    where b.IsCorrect(a)
    select new {a, b};

foreach (var item in result)
    item.b.DoSomething(item.a);
```

Comment: Not only is this readable, but it avoids `List.ForEach`, which is an abomination :-)

Answer (score 2):

With method syntax you would use this query:

```
var correctPairs = listA
    .SelectMany(a => listB.Where(b => b.IsCorrect(a)).Select(b => new { a, b }));

foreach (var x in correctPairs)
    x.b.DoSomething(x.a);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how far you want to go with this, but this is a Linq statement doing the same thing:

```
listA.ForEach(a => listB.ForEach(b =>
{
    if (b.IsCorrect(a)) b.DoSomething(a);
}));
```

Comment: Actually, this answer has nothing to do with with LINQ.

Comment: @itsme86 Very true.  I always thought the ForEach method was a linq extension, but it appears that it is not!

Comment: If you want a linq Foreach, this will give it to you:  
 public static partial class FunctionalExtensions
 {
  public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
  {
   foreach (T item in items)
    action(item);
  }
  
  public static IEnumerable<TResult> ForEach<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, TResult> action)
  {
   
   foreach (T item in items)
   {
    yield return action(item);
   }
  }
 }

Comment: @Jim That would involve no more LINQ than this method.  Nor is it representative of a LINQ style of programming.  In fact, it's very specifically *contrary* to the LINQ style of programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this but this is not more efficient what you have so far:

```
var query= listA.SelectMany(a=>listB.Select(b=>new {a,b}))
                .Where(e=>e.b.IsCorrect(e.a))
                .ToList()// Foreach is a method of List<T>
                .Foreach(e=> e.b.DoSomething(e.a));
```

To avoid to call `ToList`, you can implement an extension method like this:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<T> list, System.Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (T item in list)
        action(item);
}
```

And then your query would be:

```
var query= listA.SelectMany(a=>listB.Select(b=>new {a,b}))
                .Where(e=>e.b.IsCorrect(e.a))
                .Foreach(e=> e.b.DoSomething(e.a));
```