# Setting value of object property in List<T> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<Email>()` and my `Email` object looks like this:

```
public class Email
{
   public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
   public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
}
```

When I add a new email address that is set as primary, I want to set all the others as non-primary. I currently handle this using a `foreach`. Can I handle this using `LINQ`?

My current code is:

```
foreach (var item in emails)
{
   if(item.EmailAddress.ToLower() != newEmailAddress.ToLower() && item.IsPrimary)
      item.IsPrimary = false;
}
```

Comment: Please see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Comment: LINQ is intended for querying and not modification. Having said that, there is a `List.ForEach` operator, but not much increase in clarity.

Comment: Just use a `foreach`.  LINQ is not for modification.  Its not LINM, its LINQ.  Dont use a square peg in a round hole.  All your current answers are _bad_ answers.

Comment: The major red flag is: update all other instances.... bad design in my opinion. You should have a single mention of DefaultEmailId in a class, and IsDefault should be a an on-request check against that. At least in the in-memory model... So many years down the line and people still think models and code should map 1:1 to a database (sadface)

Comment: As an aside, with a data structure like this, you're leaving yourself open to having some weird data, like multiple primary addresses. You're much better off storing the ID of the primary against another object (e.g. `user.PrimaryEmailId`), that way a single update will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq queries collections, it doesn't modify them. The only spot in this equation that linq would come into play is actually making it a part of the enumeration - filtering the collection you're iterating over rather than doing an `if` statement inside it.

```
foreach (var item in emails.Where(e => e.IsPrimary && !e.EmailAddress.Equals(newEmailAddress, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
{
      item.IsPrimary = false;
}
```

EDIT: I didn't originally include it as it's not LINQ and that's what the question is about, but as mentioned in the comments on your question `List<T>` does include a [ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

It would look like this:

```
emails.ForEach(item =>
{
    item.IsPrimary = item.IsPrimary && item.EmailAddress.Equals(newEmailAddress, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
});
```

Comment: while I like the boolean expression, doesn't it set `IsPrimary` incorrectly? (e.g. if `item.IsPrimary` is `false`, it sets it to `true` which is not what the original code did.) Also, it sets every `IsPrimary` whether needed or not.

Comment: @NetMage you're absolutely right, I got in a hurry. It's fixed. Yes it does set each time which _could_ have side-effects if there's extra logic in the setters but as long as that's not the case I wouldn't consider it a performance hit of any real significance.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is intended for querying and not modification. Having said that, there is a `List.ForEach` operator, but with no increase in readability most of the time.

Having said that, I personally prefer not having side effect causing code that *modifies the collection* but I am not opposed to modifying the objects in the collection.

Add an extension method on `IEnumerable` to encapsulate the `foreach` loop:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action) {
    foreach (var s in source)
        action(s);
}
```

Then you can re-write your code as follows:

```
emails.Where(item => item.IsPrimary && !item.EmailAddress.Equals(newEmailAddress, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
      .ForEach(item => item.IsPrimary = false);
```

(Thanks to @McAden for the better `string` comparison I always forget.)

However, since you are creating a race condition anyway, if practical I would suggest reversing your order of operations:

```
// before adding newEmailAddress
emails[emails.FindIndex(item => item.IsPrimary)].IsPrimary = false; // add error handling if it is possible no `IsPrimary` exists.
// now assign the newEmailAddress and set that item.IsPrimary to true
```

Comment: And what is the benefit of this extension method? How does it make the code more readable that the original?

Comment: @DavidG I don't think that it does, but that is not what the question is about.

Comment: @DavidG at what point did he askt o make it more readable? He just asked how to do this with foreach.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet No, but we still have a responsibility to help people *do the right thing*. Sometimes that means saying "don't do that" (and say why)

Comment: @DavidG I tried to say that, but I made it more explicit.

Comment: @NetMage Indeed, you started well but it went rapidly downhill when you wrote the extension method that does nothing but obfuscate ([and already exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx)!)

Comment: @DavidG thats a List extension, _not_ an `IEnumerable<T>` extension like NetMage created.  Although I still think the `ForEach` extension for List or IEnumerable are travesties and should not be used that way.

Comment: @DavidG 1) It doesn't exist - or did you miss that I wrote `IEnumerable.ForEach` and applied it to the result of `Where`?  2) Obfuscation is in the eye of the beholder

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do that, but you should not as no one would expect LINQ code to modify the items in the collection.

```
emails
    .Where(item =>
       (item.EmailAddress.ToLower() != newEmailAddress.ToLower() && item.IsPrimary)
   .Select(item => { item.IsPrimary = false; return true;})
   .All();
```

Note that since LINQ queries are actually executed when result is enumerated you need something that will actually enumerate result. I.e. `.All()` call.

What would happen after you write this code - someone (or you in a week) remove that stupid and pointless `.All()` call at the end and things will be somewhat 
ok, but modification no longer happen, person will spend a day sorting it out and then use some *words* to describe author of the code. Don't go there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `.Select.Where` won't compile.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote as I consider the `.Select.Where` to simply be a typo and this _does technically_ do the change in linq. However, if I saw this in my repos I'd totally submit it to thedailywtf and I'd have a good sit-down with the perpetrator.

Comment: @McAden (typo fixed, thanks)..I tried to put some minor warning about that it is bad idea in the post, but it somewhat hard to answer this question with sensible recommendation... (Especially with `.ForEach` generally not considered part of LINQ - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet)