# can I .foreach a string[]?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a parameter `userSearch.Expand` where the `Expand` property is a `string[]`. I want to convert all values in this `string[]` to upper case. I was hoping to do something like

```
userSearch.Expand.ForEach(x => x = x.ToUpper());
```

But it looks like `.ForEach()` is not available on a `string[]`.

Is there a workaround for this or a simplified way to do this or will I need to revert a more basic loop for this?

Comment: `x = x.ToUpper()` does nothing to the element of array, regardless of whether `ForEach` is available on `string[]` or not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ equivalent of foreach for IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the 'more basic loop' as such here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Select` instead (*assuming you want to convert an array to uppercase and use it*):

```
var lowercaseArray = new[] { "one", "two", "three" };
var uppercaseArray = lowercaseArray.Select(x => x.ToUpper()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should reassign your values or create a new variable:

```
var userSearchUpper = userSearch.Select(s => s.ToUpperInvariant()).ToArray();
```

Then you receive a new array of string in upper invariant culture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to create a new array to replace the existing one.

```
userSearch.Expand = userSearch.Expand.Select(x => x.ToUpper()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, `foreach` is using only for `List<T>`.
You can read more about [ForEach()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx).

But you can use:

1) custom ForEach:

```
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in collection)
            action(item);
    }
```

2) or, if you want replace values in this container:

```
    userSearch = userSearch.Select(s => s.ToUpper()).ToArray();
```

Comment: How would the custom ForEach help?  strings are immutable, so calling ToUpper() in a foreach wont give the OP what they want

Comment: it is only simple for use ForEach on arrays, if will help him in understanding

Comment: It wont help the OP in understanding because a ForEach is not what the OP needs.  You are only adding more confusion and perpetuating a method that does not help the OP in _any_ way