# C# - check if substring is present in arraylist of strings

Tags: c#, arraylist

Suppose I've an Arraylist(arr1) like the below

```
 "String1 is present"
 "String2 is present"
 "String3 is present"
```

i wanted to see if 'String2' is present in this arraylist. i've done something like the below:

```
        var containsstringmatch = arr1.OfType<string>().Any(arg=>arg.Contains("String2"));

        if (containsstringmatch==true)
        {
            IEnumerable v1 = arr1.OfType<string>().Where(arg=>arg.Contains("String2"));

            foreach (string s in v1)
            {
                st1 = s;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(st1);
        }
```

which gives me the below output which is good:

```
"String2 is present"
```

I wanted to see if this can be achieved without me using the foreach loop. Can someone please provide suggestions as to how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, not sure what the intent of the code is. Clearly you're doing more than just checking if the substring is present in any of the strings. Are you supposed to output every value that has the substring in the array or just the last one like your code does?

Comment: Related or duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet BTW, you should put the Console.Writeline of tour original code inside the foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only to print the first string that contains the search, you can use `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
var foundString =  arr1.OfType<string>().FirstOrDefault(arg => arg.Contains("String2"));
Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(foundString) ? "Not found" : foundString);
```

Also, as Aomine wrote in his answer - ArrayLists where good when we worked with .Net 1.1. Since .Net 2.0 introduced generics, ArrayLists should be avoided.

As Rufus L wrote in his comment, your current code gets the *last* string containing the search string, not the first. If you want the last and not the first, you can simply use `LastOrDefault` instead of `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: the arraylist which i have will always have only 1 instance of a string (the above which i posted is just an example. The actually arraylist will have strings each starting with specific values which i cannot share here. My goal is to actually extract a specific string from the arraylist based on matching criteria and then do some validations on that later).

Comment: Well, in that case, `FirstOrDefault` or `LastOrDefault` are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid using `ArrayList` in this day and age in .NET, instead, favor the `List<T>` (*if possible*).

As for:

> I wanted to see if this can be achieved without me using the foreach
>   loop.

if by this you mean that you want to avoid the `foreach` construct and perform everything inline:

```
arr1.OfType<string>()
    .Where(arg => arg.Contains("String2"))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

or if you just want to find the last element satisfying the said criteria:

```
var result = arr1.OfType<string>().LastOrDefault(arg => arg.Contains("String2"));
```

Comment: This would iterated twice right?  Plus, OP wanted to avoid the `foreach` loop, I am not sure using the `ForEach` extension method is much better

Comment: @maccettura when OP said "I wanted to see if this can be achieved without me using the foreach loop" I assumed they wanted to avoid the `foreach` construct and do everything inline... but maybe I am wrong?

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do this without a `foreach` or `for` loop. But you can create an extension method that will move the code out of your method.

```
public static class ConsoleExtensions
{
    public static void WriteToConsole(this IEnumerable<string> list)
    {
        foreach (string item in list)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
arr1.OfType<string>().Where(arg=>arg.Contains("String2")).WriteToConsole();
```