# Apply one action to multiple objects C#

Tags: c#, object, generics

I have different objects: 6 buttons, Listbox, and 5 labels, those names are like lblHum, lblCo2...

I need to show or hide them together with one button click.

Is it possible (without putting objects in a panel or group boxes) to apply, for example, `Hide` action, within 1 method for all objects without specifying hiding for each?
Like `private void(List<objects>,action)`

Comment: All of them are `Control`s, so yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
public void HideAll(params Control[] controls)
{
     foreach(var control in controls) control.Hide();
}
```

Call it like this:

```
HideAll(lblHum, lblCo2,  etc);
```

Or for something more flexible:

```
public void GroupAction(Action<Control> action, params Control[] controls)
{
    foreach(var control in controls) action(control);
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
GroupAction(c => c.Hide(), lblHum, lblCo2,  etc);
```

In both cases, though, the collection is *still there*. You just hid it with a method. And since the method is fairly simple, I'm not sure you get much value above putting the collection directly in your code. That is, you can make a list as a member of the form class and add the controls when the form is initialized. Then you can loop over the list whenever you want.

Answer (score 2):

Since all controls inherit from the same base class (i.e. [`Control`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control?view=net-5.0)), you can do this with a generic method and passing in an [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-5.0). For example:

```
public void ApplyToAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```

And call the method like this:

```
var items = new List<Control> { lblHum, lblCo2... etc };

ApplyToAll(items, x => x.Visible = false);
```

Comment: For a `List<T>` you can call `ForEach(action)`

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, but I think that's a method that shouldn't exist.

Comment: And `ApplyToAll` should? What's the difference, the code is 100% identical? A `List` is not quite the same semantic as `IEnumerable`, it is meant to be mutable, so a justified function IMO.

Comment: @Charlieface ForEach is in the Linq namespace but it kinda goes against everything Linq stands for, which is *querying*. It doesn't return anything so isn't a query.

Comment: @Charlieface Linq is meant to be side-effect free by nature, but `ForEach` goes against that philosophy.

Comment: I challenge you to find it [System.Linq namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=net-5.0), it's not there. You will find it here though, [List.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=net-5.0) it's specific to `List` for a reason

Comment: Yes, but it gets lumped in with Linq all the time. See Jon Skeet's opinion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/200614/1663001) and Eric Lippert [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/foreach-vs-foreach)

Comment: They are both discussing why not to have it *in LINQ specifically*, they don't mention it being lumped with LINQ nor do they demonize `List.ForEach` @JonSkeet can you confirm maybe?