# C# Add DateTime Offset to DateTime Property in Large Collection

Tags: c#

What's the best approach to this situation:

I have a large list that contains a DateTime property in each object and I need to add the offset and modify the date manually. I wish I can do it in LINQ like so:

```
select new VM { DateTime = history.DateTime == null ? null : history.DateTime.AddHours(offset) }
```

My only option is to loop through? I'm not the one that adds the data to the db so I can't add the offset on insert.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ equivalent of foreach for IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet)

Comment: I know how to do a foreach. I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're asking for a LINQ alternative of a foreach loop, right? If not, you might want to [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: How are you planning to go through all items without looping through them? One thing you could optimize is the null check within the statement... just store `var actualDt = history.Datetime?.AddHours(offset)` outside the linq and use it within the loop: you'll avoid a nullability check on each loop

Comment: I wanted to add the hours in my LINQ query when I populated the list

Comment: @GHDevOps you can do it as you are doing there, however you'll need to populate the whole `VM` object, not just the property you want to change

Comment: LINQ doesn't seem to like the .AddHours() extension method

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to avoid `foreach` and `List<T>.ForEach`?

You can do it with LINQ, but it still loops under the hood:

```
list.Select(obj => obj.DateTime = obj.DateTime?.AddHours(offset)).ToList(); // Discard the result
```